# Hide preview for editing

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, edits, markdown-preview

I notice that when reviewing posts, when the "Edit" link is clicked, the editing interface that comes up has a "Hide Preview" link.  The ordinary editing interface doesn't have it.  Why is this, and would it be possible to add a link like this to the ordinary interface?

EDIT: By "ordinary editing interface", I mean the *suggested edit* interface, or the interface that comes up when a user with less than 2K rep clicks on the "edit" link at the bottom of any question

Comment: Why do you even need to hide the preview in normal editing mode?

Comment: @nhahtdh Sometimes, when editing a ridiculously long post, my computer starts to lag when constantly refreshing the preview pane.  It would be great to be able to hide the preview.

Comment: You can simply turn off JavaScript. No preview for you and the edit will be submitted all the same. (If not enable JS again before submitting)

Comment: Actually the ordinary edit (for 2K+ users) does have the "hide preview" link, it's missing for some reason from the **suggested edit** interface. Might be a bug, overlooked by the devs.

Comment: could you tell where is the  ordinary editing interface? @ShaWizDowArd your solution is irony...haha lol

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We consider the preview to be somewhat mandatory. We have enough horribly formatted posts already where new users ignore the preview. Condoning or encouraging this is the last thing we want to do.

The only reason that button exists is that when inline editing a post, there may be interesting content *below* the editor. This is not the case otherwise. And in most cases, inline editing is done by experienced editors anyway.

Answer (score 4):

There's already a "hide preview" link when editing, at least for the regular edits:

[image]

According to some comments, this is missing when using suggested edits though, or when not using the inline editing for some other reason.

Comment: Actually, the OP has less than 2k rep so he is redirecting to `/Edit` where hide preview option is not available.

Comment: Interesting, one can review with less than 2k?

Comment: I think he is reviewing first posts/ late answers.

Comment: (As an aside: there's a nice new image upload!)

Comment: Yep confirmed that the "hide preview" exists only for *inline editing*. Looks like a simple overlook, can't see any reason to not have it in the edit page as well..

Comment: There is no "hide preview" link when reviewing with less than 2K rep, as @hims056 pointed out.

Comment: @APerson241, *"There is no "hide preview" link when reviewing with less than 2K rep"* -- I assume you mean *"when editing"*? Or is something missing in my post?

Comment: @Arjan Whoops, sorry.  I meant to say "editing with less than 2K rep".

Comment: But +1 anyway for the freehand circle.

Comment: (No need to accept this, assuming you're still feature requesting this, @APerson241.)