# Opt-in alpha test for a new Stacks editor

Tags: discussion, product-discovery, editor, feedback, stacks-editor

**TL;DR**: We are testing our new *[open source](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor)* Stacks editor that offers both Markdown and rich text input options. If you’re interested in testing it out and giving us feedback, you can opt in by visiting [your preferences page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current) and enabling the Stacks Editor. You can opt out at any time but it will take up to 10 minutes to revert to the old editor. **Note, the new editor will only be active when drafting or editing answers** on MSE or MSO during the alpha test.

---

About six months ago (i.e. circa July 2020), our product teams and Community team began exploring whether we could bring to our public sites the [Stacks](https://stackoverflow.design/) rich text post editor that launched on [Stack Overflow for Teams](https://stackoverflow.com/teams) (or Teams) over the summer. We’ve been spending that time discussing the needs internally and also talking with some of our most highly-engaged users about the new editor - our Moderators and members of the [Charcoal](https://charcoal-se.org/) group - to understand what might need to change or be included to make using the new editor an easy change-over from the old editor.

Through this process, we’ve received dozens of answers with ideas for improvements, bugs that needed to be squashed, and UX confusion that needed to be ironed out. We’ve addressed many of the concerns these two groups mentioned and are ready to bring it to the larger community through an opt-in alpha test on MSE and MSO. We are asking for your constructive feedback to see where there’s room for improvement to make it into a tool both people who are comfortable with Markdown and those who may be more comfortable with rich text can use successfully.

Here's what the two views look like - you can click to view a larger image:

[image: Screenshot of the new editor window in Markdown mode with the text of this post input the text is monospaced and the Markdown in the post is visible, though sections in bold appear bold] [image: Screenshot of the new editor window in rich text mode with the text of this post input. The post is in Arial with bold and headers and horizontal rules being visible rather than the Markdown.]

### The test

The goal of this alpha test is to get an initial understanding of how well this new editor would be received and to also discover any concerns that would break workflows for users who like the current editor or prefer to work in Markdown. We also want to consider users who may not be familiar with Markdown, too, as they make up many of the users on our non-technical sites. This is the first public phase in a process where we hope to fully test and refine the editor so that, when it launches network-wide, people will find it easy to use and to be a major improvement over the current editor.

We understand that rich text entry is a difficult thing to get right and realize that it may take several months to find the right solutions before we can make this live network-wide - and that comes with the understanding that there may be unsurmountable issues - but we feel that working through this process with y’all will, at minimum, help improve the new editor experience on Teams and may end up with a great new editor for everyone to use.

This is part of a multi-part test that will look something like this:

- **Initial release on Teams with feedback from highly-engaged users (e.g. Moderators)** (Completed Summer 2020). The goal of this was to get feedback and get a good idea of how much we need to change the editor so that it will work for our public platform community. This allowed us to test many (though not all) of the features with a small group of people without impacting the public site.
- **Testing on MSE and MSO through an opt-in alpha test.** The goal here is to further refine and identify solutions that will help the new editor be openly adopted by users, primarily active members of the community.
- **Usability testing sessions with users of several different experience levels.** The goal here is to make sure that the features and UX we create after responding to our highly-engaged users is still transparent to others. We’ll watch how users of varying experience levels interact with the editor to identify and make additional improvements with the goal of an intuitive user experience that has sufficient guidance where needed.

As to a timeline, this is expected to take a while to work through. One of the benefits of the alpha test is that people can enable and disable it as they wish. For the rest of 2021 Q1, our plan is to leave the test running so that y’all can try it out in a more long-term way if you wish. While we’ll be fixing major bugs, we won’t be prioritizing new features or adjustments until we start digging into your feedback from this test and the feedback from the usability sessions in the second quarter of 2021. See a bit more on this in the giving feedback section below.

Assuming these tests go well and we find solutions that make post creation and editing easier than the current system, we’ll move into a gradual rollout phase, starting again with MSE and MSO and then to the sites with standard editing tools, reserving the sites with specialized editor add-ons for the end so that we can make sure that their tools work correctly upon launch.

---

### Why are we working to bring a rich text editor to our sites?

While there have been some requests for a rich text entry option over the years ([this one going all the way back to 2009](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28351/why-dont-stack-exchange-sites-use-a-rich-text-editor)), there’s never been much support for them from users - in fact, many of the requests get strong disagreement from other users. Markdown is a great tool and many users are or have grown accustomed to it - I admit to regularly trying to use Markdown in rich text spaces. That said, many of these requests have been to *replace* Markdown with rich text and that’s not something we want to do.

As a platform that is largely used by programmers, Markdown is generally a familiar format for many and they’re very comfortable using it, particularly now that we follow the CommonMark standards. For those who don’t know Markdown, we’ve expected them to learn and we give them some assistance but, in many cases, posts end up poorly formatted and need participation from the community to improve. Many of my edits on English Language Learners are purely to improve post formatting.

Additionally, our editor has been around since the beginning with few improvements in that time, so a major upgrade is in order and, in looking forward, we feel that a redesigned editor using Stacks will be more easily maintained and improved as we go forward.

#### Teams needed a rich text option

We have a great team who works to enhance the Teams product to meet the needs of companies and organizations who are using it for internal knowledge sharing. One frequent pain point from these users was the lack of a rich text editor - here’s a statement from Ham, one of the Teams developers:

> We started building the new Stacks Editor as a response to feedback from our Stack Overflow for Teams customers. While Markdown has become a widespread and successful format for writing content - not only at Stack Exchange but across the web - some of our Teams customers told us that they’re not comfortable writing their content in Markdown. They didn’t know the syntax and faced a learning curve before they could start writing the way they wanted to. Writing questions and answers wasn’t as easy as they were used to from other places.  For us it’s important to make contributing as easy as possible. Writing questions and answers should feel natural and come without a lot of friction.

This makes sense. Copy and pasting from a rich text editor like Google Docs or Word is much more common within a company where you may be transferring information from existing documentation to a Team, whereas much of our public site content is created from scratch. That said, it’s not unheard of to copy content in the form of quotes into posts, where a rich text detection feature would be helpful so that adding the Markdown manually wasn’t necessary.

The main driving force for the development of the new editor was to improve the experience of Teams for our existing users and give it a feature set that would attract additional users. That said, since many of the people using Teams are developer-centric groups, they also are often comfortable with Markdown, so we wanted to ensure that both options were available. More from Ham:

> The new Stacks Editor tries to be the best of both worlds. If you’re happy with writing Markdown and liked the way the old editor helped you with that, the new editor will feel very familiar. You can write Markdown, use familiar keyboard shortcuts, upload images and more. If Markdown is not your strong suit, Stacks Editor allows you to switch over to the new rich text mode that allows you to write in a more WYSIWYG kind of fashion.
>
> We still think that Markdown is the way to go, but we also see the benefits of a rich text editor for less technical users and/or network sites who may be more accustomed to a WYSIWYG style editing. With the new Stacks Editor, Markdown continues to be the leading format for your content and everything you write will be transformed and stored as Markdown at the end of the day.

So, our focus in building the new editor was to add the option of rich text but still maintain a Markdown focus because we love Markdown and think it’s a great experience for those who already know how to use it and is relatively simple to learn but we also want to simplify or improve the experience for people who may be copy-pasting into posts or who don’t know Markdown.

#### More than just rich text, we’re simplifying future work for development

The current editor has been around since 2008 and, while we’ve made changes along the way, it’s largely unchanged and now makes building new features difficult. Additionally, by adopting and improving the Teams editor on our public network, we’re simplifying future work on ask, answer and edit pages and maintaining similar features between Teams and the network. My final quote from Ham:

> Our old editor has served us well for many years, but due to a number of issues (reverse-engineered code that is hard to work with, inadequate API for handling cross-browser issues, and bare-bones content-editable support) we are unable to use it as the base for any major upgrades. Additionally, there are many advantages from basing an editor on a modern foundation (like we have done here on top of [prosemirror](https://prosemirror.net/)), which can take care of many of the nasty "content-editable" concerns and keep things safer and more cross-browser compatible.
>
> Being around for so long, it has accumulated quite some cruft and has become hard to maintain and evolve the way we would love to. Over the past years we tried revamping the editor a couple of times only to find out that it would be too hard to do. When we started building the new editor for Teams, we knew this would be a good opportunity to [greenfield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenfield_project) a new editor overhaul that would ultimately benefit all our users across the network.

On top of this, we’re opening the editor up for everyone to use and contribute to. Like Stacks, the new editor is open sourced, so if you’re interested in how it’s built or want to contribute to improving it, you can find it on the [Stacks-Editor repo](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor).

### Building editors is hard - particularly when dealing with rich text

I’ve learned the quirks of a variety of different editors over the years, whether it was BBCode on the forums I participated in, Wikitext on MediaWikis, Markdown here on Stack Exchange, or any of the various rich text or hybrid editors on the various platforms I’ve used (e.g. Jira, FreshDesk)… so I’m comfortable adapting to new styles, but I also find that some editors make assumptions that frustrate and confuse me and make me not want to use them any more. We want to avoid this frustration!

Because our focus is on Markdown, with the addition of special formatting for tables and spoilers, we’re able to limit what our rich text editor has to do - we’re not increasing which formatting options are available (e.g. colorful text or underlines) which is one way we’re working to keep our rich text implementation and the conversion between rich text and Markdown simple, easy-to-understand, and as frustration-free as we can.

### The major changes

Other than the optional rich-text entry, there are a bunch of other changes, big and small, that you’ll see in this test. Below are some of the biggest ones including a brief overview of how rich text entry works. A lot of what’s written below was penned by Ben Kelly, who’s done a lot of work with Ham to get this editor going and is supremely knowledgeable of the features, so big thanks to him for that!

#### Rich text mode

This editing mode was designed to largely resemble traditional word processing software that many users are used to. However, we've added in some extra features:

- Markdown-style "input rules" for *block level* syntax

  - Typing # , ## , etc creates a header; typing >  creates a quote; *  creates a list, and so on
  - We’ve got inline input rules (bold, italics, inline code, etc.) on a list of things to investigate for a future release
- Link and image editing tools will allow editing link URLs for links and the addition of an image description and title for images.
- Intelligent copy/paste support - Pasting external content from e.g. Google Docs or code from your editor of choice will retain most of its existing formatting, provided that formatting is in Markdown.

Ultimately, the rich text editor is converted back to Markdown and should support everything you can do in Markdown, with some caveats:

- Pasting rich text from outside sources isn't perfect, especially with very complicated content
- What we can support in rich text mode is restricted by our backing Markdown implementation, so things like merged cells in tables or super/subscript aren’t supported, even when we do support the HTML (see next bullet).

  - This is really more of a feature than a drawback. We <3 Markdown and are committed to supporting it first-class for the foreseeable future
- HTML support is HARD. We make no promises that any HTML written in Markdown mode will be editable in rich text mode

  - We recommend using the equivalent commonmark syntax when available. We’re looking to extend our supported Markdown syntax so users won't need to type HTML anymore.
  - Don't ask why [HTML is hard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/51). It's a long story that could be a blog post of its own.

#### The Markdown - rich text switcher

[image: Two screenshots in one - on top, the Markdown switcher in Markdown mode with the switch background green and the selector on the right; on the bottom, the Markdown switcher in rich text mode with the background grey and the selector on the left.]

To allow for movement between rich text and Markdown modes, we’ve added a switch. When the dot is on the right (green background), you’re in Markdown mode; on the left (grey background), you’re in rich text mode. The current default for all users is Markdown but, after you use the editor, the system will remember your last-used option as your default. So, if you submit a post or edit while in Markdown view, you’ll see that the next time you open the editor; if you do so in rich text, that will be the view you have when you next use it. The default configuration for users can be changed per-site, so if a site feels that rich text makes more sense as their default, we can allow for that.

#### Preview is collapsed into the rich text view

Over the years we’ve gotten lots of questions about whether we could optimize the preview so that it didn’t take up so much space on the screen. If you’ve ever written long posts, you may be familiar with the feeling of doing a lot of scrolling to get from the end of a preview back to the edit window. With the new editor, you see the preview by using the Markdown toggle to switch between Markdown and rich text modes and, because the rich text preview is part of the editor, you can edit right in the preview rather than having to find the edit window again. This is a lot more convenient for mobile users, too, with their smaller screens where scrolling through even a short post can mean a lot of work.

Aaron, our Principal Product Designer for Design systems explains the value of an editable preview:

> We think this is more than a layout issue. We could put these previews side by side, or toggle between them like GitHub does, but I think having a preview at all is something we can move beyond. Tiny sidenote: I worked on GitHub’s editor in 2016! We could explore alternatives like having a button that launches a full screen preview, but I think that’s wasted effort when we could be writing directly in the preview experience.
>
> The web has matured past the point of requiring Markdown syntax and discrete previews. Why should any text editing offer a read-only preview state in 2021? Is writing, previewing, noticing a mistake, and moving back to the editor truly better than simply being able to edit the text? Would you accept this interaction model in your word processor? In Notion? In Google Docs? In Medium?

We feel this is a positive change for these and many other reasons but we do understand that it’s a big departure from the current format. Please take some time to see how this new workflow feels and let us know what you think and how we can improve this. I know that many of the prior requests have been for a side-by-side preview to cater to the wider screens that many people have, particularly as this matches many other Markdown editors. Unfortunately, this can be complicated on smaller screens, which would require different placement and it’s pretty common to have previews separate from the entry form, like with GitHub’s two-tab format.

We do have a few known issues here:

- While switching between modes does maintain your approximate scroll position, it doesn’t remember where your cursor was. Any time you switch, your cursor will move back to the top of the post rather than staying where you were.
- There’s no history when switching modes, so flipping between views will cause you to lose the ability to undo/redo the changes from the other view.
- Since the rich text preview will interpret your Markdown, any incorrect Markdown (MD) may be escaped out by the rich text editor. When you return to MD view, you will be able to fix these errors.

#### Syntax highlighting in Markdown mode

You’ll notice your Markdown experience is a bit less monotonous because it now responds to the Markdown you use by changing the text in the pane - headings will be larger, bold text will appear bold, as will italics, and links will be in blue and code will be in grey. I’ve found this really helpful in drafting posts as it identifies a lot of the Markdown errors I might have made, making it so I’m less likely to even need to look at the preview. This isn’t currently CommonMark compliant but we’re working on improving it.

#### Changes to formatting buttons

We’ve removed some buttons and added some new buttons to the ones available for formatting. Here’s what the formatting bar looks like now:

[image: A screenshot of the post formatting bar showing the various buttons. In order from left to right there's the header button, bold, italic, inline code, links, quotes, block code formatting, image uploading, tables, ordered lists, unordered lists, horizontal rule, and a question mark for help. On the far right is the "Markdown" switch]

Removed:

- **Undo/redo** - these features still work with your standard key combinations but we’ve removed the buttons themselves - we’ve also improved undo/redo history support to be much more reliable overall.
- **Stack Snippets** (temporary) - We couldn't get Snippets built into the initial alpha test, so if you need to add a snippet to a post, you'll need to disable the alpha to do so.

Updated / New:

- **Tables** - this button will create a default three-row, two-column table and have special menu options when in rich text mode that allows adding/removing rows and columns.
  [image: A screenshot of the formatting bar with the table tool open and the various options to remove and insert columns and rows visible]
- **Headers** - this button has been redesigned and moved to the first position.
- **Inline code / code blocks / Stack snippets buttons** - one piece of feedback from our early tests was that for rich text, we need to differentiate between inline code and code blocks but on Teams we reused the same icon for code blocks that we currently use for Stack Snippets - to allow all three options, we created new icons. Snippets are disabled for the alpha but you can see the new trio of buttons (left to right - inline code, code blocks, snippets)
  [image: The new icons for the code markup buttons - a pair of angled brackets "<>" with no background for inline code, a pair of angled brackets with a background for code blocks, and a pair of angled brackets in a stack of icons for snippets.]

We're planning to add keyboard shortcuts to the formatting buttons but they aren't part of this initial alpha test.

#### Markdown mode is your go-to for fine-tuning posts

Markdown mode will give you fuller control of your posts, as it already does. Here are a few places you’ll want to stick to MD when composing or editing posts:

- **Adding a language to a code block for syntax highlighting purposes** - while we’re looking to add this to rich text, for now it’ll require MD. The system will still auto-detect languages based on tags as it usually does but if you need to call out a specific language, you’ll need to use Markdown mode.
- **Markup that requires HTML** - we still support some HTML in posts but the rich text mode won’t create it, so if you need to include HTML in your posts for formatting such as subscript or superscript, you’ll need to enter Markdown mode for this.
- **Spoilers** - like HTML, they're supported but we don't have a button for it, so you'll need to use Markdown mode to add them.
- **Creating complex lists** - this is possible in rich text mode, but it’s not as intuitive as using Markdown, particularly in special cases such as lists with indented code blocks.
- **Fine-tuning images** - resizing or adding links to sources or full-sized images will need Markdown mode.

#### Inline text and image links are the norm

The image and link tools will now add images and links inline rather than in the bibliography format. While the latter will still work, you’ll have to create it manually. Right now, images don’t have their image plus link formatting but we’re working on getting that added in a future release.

### How to participate

[image: Screenshot of the user preferences page with the alpha test opt in option emboxed.]

If you’d like to opt-in to the alpha test, visit your [preferences page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current) and opt in by enabling the Stacks Editor opt in option. At the outset the new editor will only be available on answers - you won’t see it on questions, profile pages, tag editing pages or any other editing forms around the site. Opting in is global, so if you opt in on MSE, you’ll also see the new editor if you’re on MSO. If you decide you’d like to opt out, you can do so in the same way, switching the slider on your preferences, though it may take up to ten minutes for the editors to return to normal.

### Giving feedback

This feedback phase is an incredibly important part of this process so we really appreciate any of you who take the time to try the editor out. If you run into bugs, usability issues or if you think of features that would improve your experience with the new editor, please leave an answer here - one per answer - so that we can review and respond to each. Steps to reliably reproduce are always appreciated along with which browser/s you're experiencing the bug in, and especially so when it comes to obscure edge cases or subtle usability issues. Additionally, because this project is open sourced, for truly technical bugs, [you can file them as an issue on the GitHub repo](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues) - if you feel comfortable with that - if we get reports filed in both places, we’ll link them.

Our plan is to transfer issues from our internal system to the GitHub repository and add any new ones that come up here so that anyone who’s interested can see what we’re working on and how we’re prioritizing this work.

While it’s great to hear your overall thoughts about the editor, if there’s too much in one post it can make responding difficult so try to keep each answer relatively concise. You’ll have until the end of the alpha to add the answers here. Once it’s over, we’ll let you know how best to give feedback.

### Thanks

This project couldn’t have been possible without the work of so many people and they all deserve a ton of credit. In particular I’d like to recognize Ben Kelly, Ham Vocke, Aaron Shekey, Des Darilek and Adam Lear for all of the effort that they’ve put in. Additionally, to those who have taken the time to test and give feedback while the editor was in Teams only, thank you!

Comment: I like this editor, I've been using it in SO for Teams for a while now.  Tooltips are great.  And thank you for giving us an option.

Comment: Where did you make [that screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpYV6.png)? My Stack Overflow profile shows an option to change the Theme; my Meta Stack Overflow profile to change the Editor. Not both :) I guess it's SO, looking at the left menu.

Comment: @Glorfindel Internal testing :P Yes, it's not actually possible to get that configuration currently. :D

Comment: It seems like the new editor will fix [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349613/extra-line-breaks-appear-in-editor-when-editing-a-post-in-microsoft-edge). Can that please get a [tag:status-planned]?

Comment: This post is getting more answers than upvotes.  Popular, you think?

Comment: @Ollie sorry, my fault. I can only upvote it once...

Comment: Yeah I'm too part of that problem @Ollie

Comment: "*in many cases, posts end up poorly formatted*" - I doubt that's the fault of markdown. Many askers are just too lazy to apply formatting or grammar.

Comment: @Bergi I mean... that's a possibility... but I really don't think that everyone, network-wide, who fails to perfectly format posts are all just lazy. And, honestly, it's kinda uncharitable to assume that. I'd much rather give people more options to make their post look great and honor that's at least part of the problem.

Comment: Watch the terminology around this. Searching for "Stacks Editor" in Google comes up with [StackEdit](https://stackedit.io/), which isn't built by Stack Exchange. (Incidentally, it seems to be a much more feature-rich markdown editor which also solves many of the problems users have shared in answers below. [Play around here](https://stackedit.io/app))

Comment: On the sites which have [tag:mathjax] enabled, the MathJax source will be shown in both views, right? Or does the rich text view actually show rendered MathJax?

Comment: @Robotnik we've come full circle. If you check out StackEdit's [GitHub repo](https://github.com/benweet/stackedit) you can see how they built it on Stack Overflow's previous markdown engine. Personally, I'm not worried about the name. Ultimately, it's gonna become the editor component in our [Stacks](https://stackoverflow.design) design system so people can find it there if they're looking for it.

Comment: I am glad to be able to test this. Certainly there are issues and decisions waiting there, but it looks promising to me. My favourite feature so far is the "syntax highlighting in the Markdown mode" - it makes MD editing much more robust and intuitive for me.

Comment: Is there a sandbox where we can try features out?

Comment: How about you use the official [sandbox post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) for that @ouflak

Comment: A question:  Why don't spoilers, blockquotes, backticks etc., render as soon as you've finished typing the whole element in Rich mode?  They did in the old editor.  Is this a bug?

Comment: "Why should any text editing offer a read-only preview state in 2021?" - arguably, WYSIABNQEUWYG editors that a lot of old forums had and that universally failed at anything more complicated than bold, italic and underline are exactly what the Internet has been moving *away* from.

Comment: @Catija Typical modern UI.  An ambiguous "slide switch" in place of a clear and simple check box.

Comment: @Ollie Not sure - feel free to ask about it in an answer?

Comment: @JRE It's called a toggle. And don't worry, it's probably treated the same as a checkbox on the server side.

Comment: @Catija "*I think having a preview at all is something we can move beyond*" Please, please no. Especially if there's still bugs to work out that wreck your formatting, nixing preview should be a nonstarter.

Comment: @TylerH:  I know what it is.  It is a UI catastrophe.  Every place that uses them generally also includes some additional  means to try and make clear whether left or right means the feature is activated. Look how much text was spent in describing the feature that went into describing how to turn it on and off.  Notice that it also changes color to help make clear when it is on.  Compare that to an unambiguous check box that needs no explanation.  The sliders suck.

Comment: @JRE .... So post a passionate posted about why a checkbox would be better rather than having your point of view forgotten, mouldering in the comments. The whole point of this is to try to get these things sorted out

Comment: @JRE You can easily make a checkbox ambiguous by inverting or obfuscating what it is for with the accompanying label text. Websites do that *all* the time. A checkbox is not any better, inherently, than a toggle.

Comment: Chiming in with others. This must be site specific. Killing the preview will introduce difficulties in Math.SE and other MathJax -using sites. I might manage myself, but others needing more complicated formulas and such are seriously hampered. I am also very worried about our new users who have not written thousands of pages of LaTeX like I have. They need the help of a preview pane. Typically they start with simpler pieces when the need to scroll much is not so pressing.

Comment: The new editor is a lot slower for me - it sometimes does not react to CR and sometimes inserts them on its own ... very irritating. (Firefox)

Comment: @laktak what's "CR"?

Comment: @Catija CR (or CR+LF, depending on the operating system) is the character (or two) produced by hitting the Enter-key. All the people above 50 years of age (may be 45?) were raised to think that you should hit CR+LF after every 72-80 characters, when the cursor approaches the right margin. I still do. LaTeX does not care, but some e-mail systems produce weird stuff, those configured to think that Enter means a new paragraph :-). I need to do a LOT of editing to my posts on SE because I have not yet unlearned that.

Comment: (cont'd) I very much prefer the LaTeX way: hit Enter once = move the cursor to the beginning of the next lite, hit Enter twice = start a new paragraph. 15 years ago my last grad student complained why I didn't reply to all the questions in her e-mails. It turned out that 80 per cent of her messages were off the right margin of my e-mail reader.

Comment: @Bergi part of that is from people not completely understanding what and how they can format, and finding the information out isn't the easiest thing to do on the site. It took me over a year to find out how to do <HR> in markdown (the buttons in the editor for HR and heading don't look to me what they do) and just the other day a user for 5 years thanked me because they learned how to embed block quotes (>>) from one of my questions.

Comment: what about vim based keybindings ;)

Comment: If you really want to test the feasibility of your dynamic, editable preview on technical sites, offer the option to have both the preview and markdown shown *simultaneously side-by-side* on PC, with both being editable and updating dynamically (depending on how it's implemented, this may even be fairly easy to roll out). This might create new constraints but it might also help bring out problems with the implementation. If you can make *that* work smoothly, though, I don't think people will have a problem with it (and you would likely be able to customize the appearance for different sites).

Comment: @FilipMilovanović There's already a feature request for that, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360058/428538

Comment: Are there a limited number of users allowed to use the new editor, or limited sites? I opted in well over a week ago and I still don't get the new editor when writing answers on SO... Thx.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It's not active on SO, only on MSO and MSE. :) To answer your specific question, no, there's no limit.

Comment: Thanks @Catija! FWIW I'd be able to provide dramatically better feedback if it were enabled (opt-in) on SO itself, where I'll be using it in a real context...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Completely understand! I think we're trying to balance getting good testing from y'all with also not overreaching - particularly on SO, it could be more likely to make people disable it and not test at all if it's on there and they get frustrated. With simpler posts that end up here on MSE, it's not as impactful - particularly when we don't have things like Snippets built in yet. :) But we certainly appreciate the help we're getting!

Comment: @Catija will this option reach area51?

Comment: long live markdown.

Comment: Is this going to be available in StackOverflow in the future?

Comment: I thought "Stacks" was referring to the massive, thousands-of-pages open-source algebraic geometry reference. I am deeply saddened.

Comment: Will this end up like the new site navigation, once the testers conclude that is is working great, it gets scrapped? I’m still waiting for the “even better” new new site navigation that was the reason for scrapping the new navigation. I don’t know why, but I don’t feel motivated to test a new feature…

Comment: @FZs did you know [this site has a search function](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=site+navigation)? I was referring to [this event, “Retiring New Navigation (beta) in preparation for Navigation 3.0”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359643/2711488). But, of course, it’s a good thing for this site that there are always users who are motivated to contribute, still having the big disappointment ahead of them…

Comment: @FZs it’s about the same process, beta testing for the same site owners, to which the comment was targeted. You don’t need to respond to the comment if you don’t understand it.

Comment: @Holger I commented *because* I didn't understand it, but I don't want to argue, so let's leave this alone.

Comment: How's this coming along for the question editor?

Comment: Is there an estimated time as to when it will be released to the main sites?

Comment: @12944qwerty as all projects without actual deadline (and some even with): nope. Personally I believe this project will be cancelled, like great many others, but even if not, any estimation start with at least a full year.

Answer (score 329):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

### Automatic conversion of "straight quotes" to “smart quotes” is catastrophic for code-centric sites.

When in Rich Text mode, the editor `auto-converts double-quote characters into “smart quotes”, even for text entered in inline code format`, but, fortunately, not in code blocks.

This will cause **massive** problems on code-centric sites like Stack Overflow, and is likely to cause substantial issues on at least some other sites.

To be clear: at least for code-centric sites, there should be *no mode* in the editor which automatically converts straight, double-quote characters into “smart quotes”. To have a mode which automatically does that conversion **will** result in automatic “smart quote” conversion being done to code, which *will* break the code. Having such a mode *will* increase the average time and effort necessary for every post in all of original entry, editing, moderation, determining actual issues, etc. Users *often* enter code as regular text, which they may, or may not, later apply code formatting to, so having automatic “smart quotes” enabled in *any* mode *will* cause additional problems. Having such a mode will reduce overall user satisfaction for all code-centric sites, due to the additional issues introduced.

Basically, automatic conversion of straight, double-quote characters into “smart quotes” is a feature about which some people think "ohhh pretty quotes", but which causes fundamental problems for other people (and some people just really, *really* hate “smart quotes”). **Please, *please* don't inflict “smart quotes” upon us.**

Comment: This is a catastrophe waiting to happen even on non-code-centric sites. Copying something I wrote on the Mod Team feedback post: Arqade has a very dedicated community surrounding Minecraft, which has both single-line commands and JSON-like syntax for writing scripts or setting properties on objects. Most users writing Minecraft commands and scripts are not programmers, and lack the basic diagnostic awareness/skills to handle when the wrong quotes are used. **This will likely cause ongoing strife/headaches for our site**

Comment: Looks like this only happens with inline code, but not in code blocks (not to say that it's not a problem).

Comment: Heh, I noticed that yesterday when I was writing one of the other bug reports; when I finished it, I *knew* I noticed another bug but couldn't figure out what it was. Thanks for refreshing my memory!

Comment: @Makyen I hear your concerns and agree that this can indeed become a hairy problem. Code blocks and inline code should _not_ trigger smart quotes at all, but at least on my machine inline code seems to trigger them. Are you on a Mac by any chance? I see a couple of options - we could disable smart quotes for specific sites or drop the feature altogether and let users who want them use their OS settings to type them. I'll check in with the team and see if there are good reasons for smart quotes to stick around. Stay tuned!

Comment: @HamVocke I've tested this on both a Windows 10 based PC and an Android device using both Google Chrome and Firefox. I didn't have to do anything other than just open the editor and start typing to have the quotes be changed to “smart quotes”. I don't recall ever having this issue in anything other than this editor. I don't see any way to *not* have it happen. Thus, I'm a bit surprised that Ben is having problems reproducing the issue.

Comment: @Makyen thanks, that helps! It's definitely Stacks-Editor handling the smart quotes. It's an [optional ProseMirror feature](https://prosemirror.net/docs/ref/#inputrules.smartQuotes) that I hooked up to Stacks-Editor early on and never bothered to think too hard about. It's easy to disable but I want to check in with the Team first.

Comment: @HamVocke From my POV, it *needs* to be that smart quotes are *never* used, not just not in code format. We get a *lot* of code that is saved in a post revision as normal text (i.e. not in code format) and a *lot more* that is initially entered into the editor as basic text and only later placed in code format (sometimes several post revisions later). Once the editor changes the quotes, it's done and over; an additional problem has been introduced, which can have substantial negative repercussions for the post, and will commonly affect how it's received by others.

Comment: We just discussed this with the team. We're dropping the smart-quotes feature (and a few others that are in a similar vein). You can find [the pull request here](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/pull/10) together with some additional explanation. Thanks for getting this onto our radar. This was really something I didn't put much thought into when I introduced it early on but I totally see how this was a bad idea.

Comment: I'm not even sure why "smart quotes" are a thing or what they are supposed to represent. Better to just not have them at all on the site.

Comment: @Braiam No, the code formatting which you tried to change is not emphasis. It's a demonstration of what happens when typing in code format. It's demonstrating the issue which is the *entire point* of this post. If the reason for that formatting was that I was just trying to emphasize it, then it would be in bold and italics.

Comment: @Braiam Because it is a short, concise demonstration of the issue that directly communicates (to everyone, except, apparently, you). Sure, I could make the whole thing longer by using an example of actual code, but I'd *still* have to explain that example with basically exactly the existing text. I would be doing that *only* in order to not have non-code in code format, when what I'm explicitly talking about there is text in code format. I agree one should not use code formatting for emphasis, and do edit posts to remove it. Again, if emphasis was the intent, it wouldn't be in code format.

Comment: The middle ground here would be to do what MS Word does: It auto-converts quotes to smart quotes; but you can hit Ctrl+Z after you type a (single or double) quote to convert it back to a normal quote. If need be, there could be a preference setting with a site-dependent default that enables that behaviour vs disabling smart quotes altogether.

Comment: I would personally argue, from a design perspective, smart quotes should always stay smart. In other words, if you copy and paste a smart quote, **it should still grab the underlying straight quotes**, and require any software that you paste it in to display them as smart quotes if they so wish.. Granted, I'm not sure HTML would make this easy (without some font shenanigans). But I've always opposed actually converting straight quotes to opening and closing quotes. Smart quotes are always just a cosmetic detail and contain no semantic difference.

Answer (score 294):

> [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [Preview mode is now available](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382236/stacks-editor-markdown-preview-mode)
> [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) MathJax is not yet integrated in the new preview mode, but will be included before the Stacks Editor is opened for testing on sites that include preview mode.

Disclaimer:

Let me start off by apologizing for the blunt tone in this post. I very much appreciate the spirit of openness and hard work that underlies the development side, and I want to thank you for both the hard work in improving the UI and for the time and willingness dedicated to soliciting community feedback. I offer this feedback with some blunt edges because it is important -- you're doing great work, but if you don't do that work carefully then there is a clear potential to cause significant harm, and most of the signs I can see indicate that your current trajectory goes towards that harm.

What follows is intended exclusively as constructive criticism, and I hope it reads as such =).

That said:

#### This change is extremely alarming from a MathJax perspective.

The design philosophy makes a lot of sense for a lot of sites, but several of the proposed changes (specifically, the removal of the live preview) would be a **catastrophe** for sites where MathJax is a common or essential part of the site experience. As a reminder, [this is no less than **42** sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216606/which-stack-exchange-sites-use-mathjax) out of the network total of 176, i.e., **24%** of the network sites.

<sup>(Also, as pointed out in the comments, there are [several other essential site-specific post formatting plugins](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298844) which are in an identical situation to MathJax, the clearest examples of which are [chess](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179), [go](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/425), [furigana](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199) and [music notation](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2581).)</sup>

Here are the things that worry me the most:

> We could put these previews side by side, or toggle between them like GitHub does, but I think having a preview at all is something we can move beyond.

uh... no it isn't.

> Why should any text editing offer a read-only preview state in 2021? Is writing, previewing, noticing a mistake, and moving back to the editor truly better than simply being able to edit the text? Would you accept this interaction model in your word processor?

**Yes I would. I already do. This is my main mode of work.** In my discipline -- similarly to many of those represented in MathJax-holding SE sites -- the industry standard word processor is LaTeX. Having a separate editor and preview is not only standard, it is the *only* way to work efficiently.

At the very least, building a WYSIWYG editor for math is a major software undertaking. But, to be blunt, none of the existing solutions, with decades of trajectory, make the bar as a professional standard. (For clarity: it would be absolute nonsense to attempt it here.) Editing math **absolutely requires** a code-and-preview configuration. As such, if your design philosophy is that "having a preview at all is something we can move beyond", then your design philosophy is blind and deaf to the requirements of the technical sites.

I am of course sympathetic to this concern:

> If you’ve ever written long posts, you may be familiar with the feeling of doing a lot of scrolling to get from the end of a preview back to the edit window.

and indeed it can be annoying (though, as has been pointed out, [not universally](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360058/184688)). But that viewpoint is missing another vital aspect of how MathJax works on Stack Exchange, and that is the amazing and extreme convenience of having an *instant* preview rendered alongside the plain-text Markdown/MathJax source. In fact, the current editor is *more* convenient than the standard LaTeX editors, due to the speed and constancy of the preview refresh -- it refreshes as soon as anything changes, and it is only limited by the (very fast) speed of the rendering.

In the proposed changes (Markdown source and rich-text preview on the same pane, with a button to switch between them), writing and editing mathematics will become noticeably and significantly harder. To put it bluntly, getting rid of the simultaneous preview kinda shafts the mathy technical sites, bigtime.

---

Now, I appreciate the points made regarding the age of the code and the difficulty of maintaining it and of using it as a base for further upgrades. It makes complete sense that there is a need to have a better codebase for the editor, and that it should, at the end of deployment, be used across the board throughout the SE network.

... which is why it is essential that the concerns surrounding MathJax form part of the *initial* design stage. [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360033/opt-in-alpha-test-for-a-new-stacks-editor/360068?noredirect=1#comment1201740_360068):

> Sites with MathJax are among the last we'd ship this on

is not good enough. The concerns surrounding MathJax are part of the core design decisions that need to be made. If the plan is to wait until the end, once everything has been hammered out and all of those design decisions are set in stone, and hope fingers-crossed that those decisions will work for the 40+ sites that use MathJax, then the plan reads "we don't care if the mathy technical sites end up getting shafted" to me.

If the goal is to have a single codebase work for rich-text-oriented sites and Teams as well as for MathJax-oriented technical sites, then that jointness needs to be recognized from the get-go: the design decisions regarding the preview need to be made now, and a mathy site (math.se, physics.se, stats.se, etc. - your choice) needs to be among the first sites to test it out.

---

One more thing:

> Syntax highlighting in Markdown mode
>
> You’ll notice your Markdown experience is a bit less monotonous because it now responds to the Markdown you use by changing the text in the pane - headings will be larger, bold text will appear bold, as will italics, and links will be in blue and code will be in grey.

That's great! But you also need to turn it off inside MathJax delimiters. Some of those problems have [already been pointed out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360068/184688), but I'll say it explicitly here: messing with the formatting like in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWckr.png) is extremely distracting, utterly useless (in the sense that it is not achieving any of its goals, as it's responding to syntax that's going to produce other output than what the highlighter thinks will happen) and it has no place in a math editor in the 2010s, let alone the 2020s.

Comment: Admittedly your disclaimer had my finger hover over the downvote button in anticipation. But you’re obviously 100% correct, and this is kind of a deal-breaker.

Comment: It's not just MathJax, but ***all*** post formatting, see: "[What site-specific post formatting settings are available?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298844/282094)" - without a live preview composing on most of those sites will be very difficult; it's also a problem that enabling the alpha-test editor on Meta Stack Exchange breaks the other versions of the editors on other sites (already reported).

Comment: @Rob Goodness, yes, that is a lot of other plugins. For some, the lack of preview might be OK (say, youtube embedding, or CircuitLab schematics, which has its own editor), but for a lot of those (from a quick skim: chess, go, music, furigana) the lack of real-time preview would make composing much more difficult.

Comment: @E.P. I understand that line of thought and I do appreciate you posting a new answer - I think that, if this had been created for a platform where MathJax were available, considering it from the start does make sense. That's not the case for Teams - there's no ability to add MathJax to Teams at this point - so that's why there wasn't any consideration for it at the outset. The (unfortunate?) reality is that the breadth of content on our sites is something that we have to remind ourselves of every day, particularly when our focus is on SO.

Comment: But this answer is exactly why we have this discussion here - We need to be able to see what we're missing, where our focus needs to turn to ensure parity in experience around the network. This editor, as I say, is months away from ever being shipped even to a single site, let alone made the default - and that assumes that we're able to get it in a good enough shape to meet the needs of the users. Understanding how much effort will need to be put into making it a great experience is why we're asking for your help. :)

Comment: In order to add to your already well conveyed points, could you just give an example of a situation where the editing of a rendered MathJax expression would most likely be failed by a rich text environment?

Comment: @Travis I don't fully understand your question. Do you mean having the MathJax source on the rich text environment? Then you're editing blind and without any preview, and even experienced users would sink when writing complex expressions. (For new users it would be a nightmare, and onboarding would be orders of magnitude harder.) But presumably you mean having the MathJax source on the markdown pane, and editable output on the rich-text pane, with the edits getting written to the MathJax source?

Comment: If so, there's no software that will do that. The closest you can get is LyX, which you would have to re-write in javascript. As a general rule, LyX is like training wheels for children: it's useful to get the hang of things, but it's not suitable for professional use (so the software for grownups is LaTeX). Going down this route means that the LyX reimplementation is writing code (much like, say, Dreamweaver creates html) and then that code is rarely human-readable and much less editable. If the goal is to keep the markdown source front-and-center, this would fail.

Comment: But again: you'd have to write the math editor from scratch. That would be a major undertaking in a desktop environment, and here there are many more constraints, in terms of UI and software platforms.

Comment: Well, with richtext the goal would be to avoid using source I would assume, so you would only deal with the UI and the actual editor itself, and no markdown. There would need to be some sort of tool that showed in order to manually edit expressions. I am unsure, which is why I asked, just trying to get a little clarity on what the pitfall of a richtext-only environment would be with a specific feature or MathJax expression.

Comment: @Catija - Suggestion: change the "Markdown" toggle into a "View As" dropdown with three options: "Markdown" or "Source", "Rich Text", and "Side by Side".

Comment: While it's typical to start work on a "minimum viable product" and expand the feature set, this answer shows why any rewrite has to have an architecture that's designed from the beginning to handle the most difficult cases. One of the biggest problems with the bit-by-bit agile approach is that it too often eschews that kind of design.

Comment: @TravisJ To avoid source for math and have some sort of tool to enter and display the symbols would look something like Microsoft's equation editor I think... I guess the only thing I can say about that is A) there's a reason few in math and science uses Microsoft Word to write papers and B) Microsoft now let's you enter LaTeX-like commands and have it render but it's still a pain to use and edit. It's a really hard thing to do correctly because the complexity (and generality) of mathematical expressions is really vast and any tool to avoid using LaTeX source will be greatly limited.

Comment: @TravisJ I'll take it you never wrote any scientific paper that had more than a handful of formulas in LaTeX? Rich text absolutely is **not** the goal. For exactly the same reason you're presumably not using your mouse and onscreen keyboard to write text.

Comment: @Voo -  I'll take it you never implemented a word processor using contenteditable. Just trying to give a clearer picture to whomever is going to be developing this feature, with regards to the type of hurdle they face. If the definition of the problem is abstract it will be difficult to quantify. I think tpg2114 does well to give a more concrete description of the problem the developer faces in this situation.

Comment: @TravisJ Soo the counter argument to why not having a live preview is a catastrophe UI wise is "it's harder with our chosen implementation"? Not convincing. But the main problem is the claim that rich text is the *goal*. It simply is not. It's one - often inferior - way to input text and providing it as an option should not come at the cost of making the UX much worse for the people using the other already available tools.

Comment: Just going to note that "the industry standard word processor is LaTeX" is blatantly false in general. Yes, there are places like academia that still use it strongly, but at the same time even e.g. in industrial life science research (a field I am active in currently) the industry standard is Microsoft Word. And yes, even in a semi-structured rich text editor you can easily take a click-to-edit approach to formulas and render the result by default which does not require a full rendered preview of the entire document/post at all times. (cont.)

Comment: This post conflates your completely valid concern/problem with a specific solution you're used to. Also have to say: Respect to SE for keeping the option open of not releasing this at all. I think it's completely worth releasing, but the fact they keep the option open is something worth positively calling out.

Comment: @DavidMulder Those points are moot. The only viable math editor is MathJax. The only way to go outside that is if there is a JS reimplementation of the MS Word equation editor or equivalent (no such thing, really -- or can you point to one?), or SE is willing to write and maintain one (not a feasible investment). And any new tool would have to be compatible with >1M pre-existing posts. So, ultimately: do you have any viable alternatives to MathJax to propose?

Comment: @E.P. How does that make my point moot? As I was saying, you could have a rich text editor that renders the TeX by default and when you click on it it shows the raw TeX for editing. And maybe there are other alternatives as well beyond 'render the entire content twice side-by-side using two different approaches'. As for what you use to render the TeX: MathJax practically but it doesn't matter what you pick, that's an implementation detail.

Comment: @DavidMulder Sure. It boils down to two alternatives -- keep the MathJax editor and a live preview, or somehow find or develop a rich-text editor. Perhaps SE does want to go down the second path, but then they need to commit to develop something that doesn't break the existing sites. If and when such an alternative gets put on the table, we can go down the whole host of ways it's liable to break science SE, and heck, I'll admit it's not impossible it could work. But I'll believe it when I see it.

Comment: I couldn't agree more with this answer. Latex or MathJax is essentially unworkable in a WYSIWYG setting. Many have tried and failed. For example, Overleaf has a rich text option, but it's not usable. If MathOverflow were to switch over to rich text with _no option_ to revert to markdown, there would be riots. I, and I've no doubt many others, would strongly consider exercising our contractual option to leave the Stack Exchange network. I suspect users at Math Stack Exchange would be similarly upset, and in all likelihood the same could be said about various other technical sites.

Comment: It should be a no-brainer, if rich text editing is added, to allow the option to switch back to markdown. For instance, that's what wikipedia has. If you think you can design a workable rich text mathjax editor as an afterthought, when so many others have tried and failed with this as their main goal, then you are afflicted with profound hubris.

Comment: I would add, after reading the comments a bit more, than a solution like the MS Equation Editor -- which I'm sure was a huge undertaking to create and is an impressive piece of software -- would still be completely inadequate for use on MathOverflow at any rate. To ask a mathematician to use something like that is like asking them to type with their thumbs. I'm sorry if MO is an edge case, but all we'd need is the _option_ to revert to markdown -- whether it's at the site level, or at the individual question /answer level.

Comment: To clarify my last comment -- the MS Equation Editor would be strictly _worse_ than being forced into typing mathjax in rich text on two counts. First, it's less expressive: the range of what you can write the the equation editor is a small subset of what you can write in latex or mathjax. Second, even for the things you can write, it is in every case _more_ cumbersome to to write in the equation editor that it is in mathjax. The only benefit of the equation editor is its decreased learning curve for use, which is a non-factor when the community standard is already Latex / MathJax.

Comment: One last comment (hopefully): You would never ask a developer to write their code in Microsoft Word. If it's not clear that there are a dozen good reasons for that, just ask any developer in the world. Asking a mathematician (or, I believe, a person in any of several other technical fields) to write in rich text is laughable for exactly the same reasons.

Comment: Although my previous comments were written under the mistaken understanding that there would be no markdown mode at all, much of what I have said is still applicable to the terrible idea of trying to use the rich text editor in _lieu_ of an actual mathjax previewer. See my [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360304/289078) for more on this.

Comment: @DavidMulder In my (limited) experience those fields that can get away with using MS word to write mathematics, do not have really complex math formulas to begin with. For truly complex mathematical formulas (of the kind I routinely use every third lines in my papers for example), writing them in Word would be a nightmare hard to express. Note that I consider even Mathjax lacking (compared to a fully fledged LaTeX), especially in writing commutative diagrams, reverting to something like the equation editor would make writing answers essentially impossible for me.

Comment: A big part of the discussion here reads as FUD to me. Let me try to address some of the concerns. 1. Markdown editing is here to stay. If you liked editing content as markdown you can continue to do so. 2. When designing the new editor, we made sure that the new architecture allows us to support different site-specific plugins (MathJax, video embedding, chess, circuit diagrams, you name it) and to avoid painting ourselves into a corner. 3. We have to start somewhere and wanted to get something in front of our users early, that's why we decided to implement site-specific plugins later.

Comment: @HamVocke Apologies -- from your comment, you seem to have missed the point here, and you're certainly not addressing the concerns. Nobody thinks that you will suspend MathJax as a plugin, but that is not what this is about. For the MathJax (+chess,go,music,furigana) composing to actually work, it **needs** a live preview. If your initial designs don't allow for one, then you're painting yourselves into a corner. It's not about "implementing site-specific plugins later", it's about creating a design framework that won't collapse under the weight of those plugins when you do enable them.

Comment: We have a range of options to build MathJax support. Edit in markdown, preview in rich-text mode is one way of handling things. Adding an edit pane in rich-text mode that allows you to enter a MathJax equation and then rendering the equation could be another option. And then there are other [interesting approaches](https://github.com/benrbray/prosemirror-math) that might be worth trying. We're really flexible here. Let's figure out what works best for people and build it. I'm confident that we can build something that'll fit into our users workflow.

Comment: @HamVocke I too am confident you can build something that will fit into most users' workflow -- you have built one already. But it's hard to take the assertion that you're really flexible at face value, when the *one* thing that you don't seem to have allowed on the table is the one thing which is guaranteed not to break workflows (i.e. the thing we're asking for).

Comment: From the options in your last comment: 'Edit in markdown, preview in rich-text mode' will break most workflows; if you think it won't, you're not looking at the workflows closely enough. 'Adding an edit pane in rich-text mode that allows you to enter a MathJax equation and then rendering the equation' is unclear to me, but if you mean that math gets entered into little bubbles separate from the main text, then that will also break workflows, and it feels rather insulting. (As a rule of thumb: if you wouldn't do it for inputting code on SO, then it doesn't work here.)

Comment: Your final link, prosemirror-math, is the only option you've given which stands a chance. (If nothing else, though, note that KaTeX and MathJax are not fully compatible, and the conversion would entail migration of tens of thousands of posts.) How about pointing us to somewhere where it is enabled so we can see how it works?

Comment: In any case: I've raised prosemirror-math as a possibility on [the physics meta](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13355/8563) and [on meta.mathoverflow](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/4862/20729). I don't know what people will think of that style -- let's see what comes out.

Comment: Strong agree with @E.P. that prosemirror is the first alternative suggested that has any hope of working.  I’d certainly prefer the current solution but prosemirror is a serious possibility.

Comment: @HamVocke regarding "FUD": I think I have been the most careless in spreading misinformation. I'm sorry for that. This was not done intentionally. This thread introduces large, deep, and complex changes, and I think some form of misunderstanding was inevitable. I'm relieved to start discussing things like KaTeX (thank you), but the fact that such fundamental design choices are first coming up in the comments to an answer on a thread which is primarily meant to catch minor bugs speaks to the point that these issues are serious, and feelings of fear, uncertainty, and doubt are warranted.

Comment: In addition, any suggestion that E.P. has engaged in any form of fearmongering would be completely unfair. E.P. has been meticulous in attention to detail and has bent over backwards to avoid doing any such thing, while at the same time being clear and blunt about the severity of these issues.

Comment: @TimCampion thanks for your explanation. I'm sorry, I didn't mean to dismiss any concerns with my comments - I know that this is a topic that's dear to a lot of our users' hearts and we really want to improve the status quo, not just blindly push for something that we think is right. What's important to me is to assure you that we're trying to be diligent and build something that's good for years to come. This editor is far from finished and we can't solve all problems from day one. The lack of math support in this alpha was not an oversight but a compromise to get faster feedback.

Comment: Support for math (and other site-specific plugins) was on our roadmap early on and we will tackle these things as we progress. The examples I listed were only quick top-of-mind ideas but I hope they show that this new editor allows us to think in much bolder directions than we previously could.

Comment: @HamVocke:  I don’t mean to start a fight, but those aren’t “bold ideas.” They’re very old ideas that have been tried many times and always been eventually discarded in professional settings to return to the simple clean idea of having a separate preview.

Comment: +1 for being spot on! I have experienced the problem you describe on my blogger editor (I have added mathjax in my blogger template). Currently there is nothing better on web than the mathjax preview offered on Math.SE or MO.

Comment: @HamVocke That makes MathJax usable in rich-text mode, which is superior to it not being so. It still isn’t a rerendered-as-you-type preview, and it does nothing for the Markdown editor, which is by a **vast** margin the preferred way of working for almost everyone doing MathJax in the first place. If your proposal is “hey, this is another neat thing we could do,” sure, have at. If your proposal is “hey, if we did this, we wouldn’t need the separate preview, right?” then ***no***, absolutely not. There does not exist any acceptable alternative to the separate preview. You **must** accept this.

Comment: Quick mod note: Stuff's getting a bit passionate - and its worth stepping back and looking at "We absolutely need a preview option for mathjax to work" and "Chill, this is a minimal viable product! We're looking at it!- this isn't even our final form!" which is what this seems to be boiling down to.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Re "Currently there is nothing better on web than the mathjax preview offered on Math.SE or MO" -- you should give https://stackedit.io a try. (cf. [this comment](/q/360033#comment1201638_360033) and [its response](/q/360033#comment1201660_360033) under the question in this thread.)

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I agree passions are a bit on the too-high side, but I understand where it's coming from. Thus far there hasn't been *any* response from the team that even suggests a simultaneous live preview is still on the table, and it sure would be reassuring to hear that.

Comment: @E.P.: stackedit.io looks very similar to the way WriteLatex (now it's called overleaf) worked with preview side by side. But the current editor with preview below is more suitable for my needs. I use this site exclusively on mobile device and with responsive design it works so nicely. Side by side preview is great on desktop wide screen btw.

Comment: New users who aren't familiar with MathJax/LaTex need encouragement - and there are many of these, because MathSE is open to questions on mathematics at any level. This change will put an additional barrier for people learning/accessing the site for the first time. MathSE needs  the default option to be concurrent preview, perhaps with an option for the experienced to turn it off. The option to turn concurrent preview off could be trialled tomorrow on MathSE.  The number of takers would be small, and some would switch back again (others would essentially become dormant or leave the site).

Comment: @MarkBennet: there is a check box to hide or show preview in current editor. I sometimes turn the preview off for long posts because too much of mathjax rendering makes my mobile browser really slow. Another option which I use for long posts is to type the post in some other app and then copy paste it back.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Useful data would be how many people use it. I think my point with new users would suggest that the default should be to have it on so people don't have to find it.

Comment: @MarkBennet: yeah this should help the new users in a big way. I hope many would agree here on this given the focus on engaging new contributors.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: where is that checkbox, exactly? I have typed thousands of answers and I have never seen it.

Comment: @MartinArgerami: sorry, that's not in the form of a checkbox. It is just a link below the edit window (on the left side). Below the edit on right side there is a checkbox for community wiki.

Comment: @MartinArgerami: also this is shown when you edit an existing post and not when creating a new answer.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: If you find your browser slowing down when editing MathJax-heavy posts, I have a [user script](https://stackapps.com/questions/7765/incremental-markdown-preview-for-stack-exchange) that you might want to give a try. It basically Just Fixes It™ by re-rendering only those parts of the preview that actually change. FWIW, I've had it active all the time for years now, and haven't noticed any problems.

Comment: @MartinArgerami: I checked further (at least on mathoverflow and this meta.se). The show / hide preview toggle link is not available in general (on MO and meta.se), but somehow available on math.se. I mostly use only math.se site and hence my experience is limited.

Comment: Should we be concerned that we're not seeing a `status review` tag on this post or something? So many projects have been dedicated to the idea of an inline wysiwyg formula editor, including a couple backed with vast resources. So many have failed. I certainly hope the crazy idea of just shoehorning this in hasn't actually *stuck* and is no longer on the table for atleast discussion, if not a complete rethink.

Comment: @KRyan: Actually I can think of one alternative to the separate simultaneously-on-screen post preview that may be viable, which is to have a simultaneously-on-screen *per-block* preview, only for the blocks that can't be edited in WYSIWYG (math, chess, etc).  I guess you'd need another slider.  At one extreme, you have the pure full-post preview in which text is WYSIWYG editable and special blocks aren't.  At the other extreme, you have pure markdown with no preview.  And in between you have both "markdown plus per-block live preview" and "WYSIWYG plus per-block markdown entry"

Comment: That could be even better than the current situation, because you don't have to scroll back and forth between editor and preview on large posts, each block's markdown and preview are adjacent.

Comment: @BenVoigt I guess, but it doesn’t help with Markdown (which is beyond this feature request but also important to me, since I use the table formatting a lot). Fundamentally, I really truly think the only acceptable thing is for SE to realize they were wrong, accept that they cannot go forward with their plans as they were, and change them. There should be a commitment here that they are not going to ruin the experience for anyone, and I find it extremely telling—and galling—that they have studiously avoided any suggestion that they are committed to any such thing.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Actually, I do see hide preview on [mathoverflow.se]. I guess that the difference is that it is not shown if a user *suggests* an edit, it is only available to users with full edit privilege. Something like that is mentioned here: [Hide preview for editing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168391). I have posted some related comments (including a screenshot from MO) in the [Math Meta Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64952/conversation/show-hide-preview).

Answer (score 124):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

### Allow viewing the Markdown at the *same* time as the rich text

> Over the years we’ve gotten lots of questions about whether we could optimize the preview so that it didn’t take up so much space on the screen. If you’ve ever written long posts, you may be familiar with the feeling of doing a lot of scrolling to get from the end of a preview back to the edit window. With the new editor, you see the preview by using the Markdown toggle to switch between Markdown and rich text modes and, because the rich text preview is part of the editor, you can edit right in the preview rather than having to find the edit window again. This is a lot more convenient for mobile users, too, with their smaller screens where scrolling through even a short post can mean a lot of work.

As someone who's edited [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) posts here quite frequently, I definitely understand the sentiment here. A large portion of my time in editing those was in scrolling back and forth between the preview underneath the post editor and the editor itself.

However, the new editor removes the ability to view the rendered output of text at the *same* time as viewing its raw Markdown. As someone who frequently makes use of advanced Markdown techniques and subtle nuances (and the *occasional* HTML) while typing posts, having to constantly flip a switch back and forth every time I want to see how my post looks like is an *extreme* burden compared to simply scrolling.

This is also quite important because in the current preview, since the rendered output took as much space on the overall page as it would use when posted (slightly less due to the lack of a left margin for voting buttons), this would allow me to get a rough estimate of how long my post is, so I can tune it back (e.g. remove unnecessary details) if it was too long. The new preview makes it much more difficult to estimate how long a post will be on the actual page when posted, which is, again, something I make use of frequently enough to put up with having to scroll.

Again, I definitely completely understand the sentiment behind the way the new editor is designed currently. Having to scroll can be quite difficult for many people, especially for larger posts (e.g. FAQs here). However, I'm one who frequently makes use of more advanced things enabled by the current setup that the new setup would make it *more* difficult for me.

Can there please be an option to view a live rendered preview of a post at the *same* time as when typing raw Markdown into the editor? This need not be below the post as it currently is, but please consider this.

---

I should probably note that as a member of a Team, I've had access to this editor for quite a while. I've made repeated attempts to get used to this new workflow, but I'm still unsatisfied.

Also, those looking into this answer may also want to look at [two additional](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360146/377214) [answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360112/377214) written by Tinkeringbell, which expand upon the argument in this post.

Comment: +1 this was something I raised in the Mod Team's 'Rich Text Editor feedback' post too, and is probably going to be the one of the biggest issues for long-time power users of the sites.

Comment: @Robotnik Yeah, I raised this in the Charcoal team feedback thread as well (the team I'm a member of), and incidentally it was the highest-voted suggestion there.

Comment: Having an option to have it side by side could be useful on wider desktop screens.

Comment: Being unable to see the rendered output while typing Markdown would be utterly unacceptable. Absolutely must be fixed.

Comment: What about a hotkey to switch back and forth?

Comment: @LShaver The problem is not about having to use the mouse to click on the switch - it's about having to flip back and forth at all.

Comment: I mean... I created this post in the old editor and the frustration of scrolling up and down to see specific edits... takes its toll. With the editor, I could have flipped back and forth and the spot I was at would've been pretty close with no scrolling at all. I love the preview, too... but it's not the best solution by a long stretch. I think there's definitely a benefit to the toggle though I wish the cursor position was retained.

Comment: @Catija The complaint here isn't about the absence of a preview *below* the post - it's about its absence *overall*. I'd like to see a rendered preview *live*, without having to switch back and forth, *while typing Markdown*. As I say in the last paragraph above the line, said preview need not be below.

Comment: You don't have this now. You can't see what you type as you type it without scrolling. Can you please explain how the toggle doesn't address your needs?

Comment: @Catija In the case of posts that aren't longer than one screen, I actually *can* see what I type in both raw Markdown *and* a rendered preview: the page is scrolled so that the bottom 2-3 lines of the editor box are visible, so they're both visible at the same time. The same also applies when I'm editing the top sections of posts that are longer than one screen. When editing the bottom sections of longer posts, however, you're right, I can't see both at the same time, but that's only *some* of the time, not *all* of it. (continuing)

Comment: The majority of my edits are of the former varieties, editing posts or sections of posts whose live previews of what I type and raw Markdown are visible at the same time without scrolling. I don't want to be shut out of that case all the time, simply because of a minority of edits which require scrolling to see one or the other. Also, see my post's paragraph about using subtle Markdown and HTML nuances.

Comment: Like I said, I completely understand the trouble of scrolling. But please provide the ability to view both Markdown and rendered output at the same time in any way, even if it's not in the current form. The current editor provides for that in a majority of cases; I don't want it to go down to 0% of cases. Implementing it for 100% of cases is also a valid (and better) way to implement this feature request.

Comment: @Catija For a lot of posts - the default edit box size [gives plenty of preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txjJy.png). Also - what about placing the render alongside, rather than under, the edit box?

Comment: @Robotnik generally, that only helps people on huge screens. Even with the standard width page, a two-column option is really skinny. And on mobile, requires a completely different view.

Comment: What you mean huge screen ? I work on 24'' and this is for me standard.

Comment: @Catija - the image I provided was from a 1920x1080 screen (image resolution is 1920x1048 because I cropped the taskbar) - is 1080p considered a 'huge screen'? Plus, the content section being too skinny was something specifically [called out](/a/307863/179041) by the community when the responsive design changes were announced. I don't see why Left/Right sides can't be moved out to give the Q&A more space. [Another post](/q/316019/179041) by Monica (pre-incident) asks why the right-hand column is even needed - there's enough space in the left column to fit most of the RHS stuff.

Comment: @Robotnik That's a huge screen. We've fixed the max page width and it's utterly out of scope to change it just to make the editor have a side-by side format - we'd have to redo the entire site for that and that's nowhere in any plan for the future. Making the entire page that wide would be a hardship for readability for many people.

Comment: @Catija Is there a keyboard shortcut to switch between `Markdown` and `non-Markdown preview`? Without any shortcut, it's barely usable for now. I think this is asbolutely needed, even during an alpha test. Good luck to the team! And congrats SE for always innovating :)

Comment: @Basj As noted in the question, we weren't able to get all of the shortcuts hooked up for the alpha but it's definitely on our list of things to add, in particular, to toggle modes. We had a discussion last week, actually, about what the shortcut should be but didn't reach a consensus. I'd be curious to know if y'all have thoughts.

Comment: @Catija A useful feature but not a replacement for the fundamental ability to see the result as I am typing. I routinely type—with Markdown syntax—while watching the preview rather than the actual text field. I do not want WYSIWYG, I like controlling my Markdown and moreover it simply isn’t how I work, I write `*` not `Ctrl`+`I` and retraining my fingers is approximately 0% within my interests. I don’t write documents in word processors, I write code. What is shown here is akin to what is found in Github—which I find miserable near to the point of unusability. This is a **massive** regression.

Comment: @KRyan On my system at least I get scrolled up to the text box whenever I type something on the old editor, so your approach doesn't really work consistantly at the moment anyway. For long posts I actually think it's better with the toggle because the scroll position is maintained and you don't have to try and find your insertion point in the preview -- just need a keyboard shortcut for it. For small posts hopefully the WYSIWYG editor is good enough that you won't need to switch back to markdown for trivial edits, and with the planned markdown shortcuts for inline formatting it _should_ be.

Comment: @Toastrackenigma No, it’s not ideal for long posts. Often posts are not that long. Posts are usually quite short, and are usually *supposed to be* quite short, and furthermore—and I suspect that this is a key point that is being misunderstood, though I am not the first to mention it—MathJax-heavy posts often require a lot more checking of the rendered output and can take up far less rendered space than the code takes up writing space. But MathJax seems to be getting ignored entirely in this process, so far as I can tell.

Comment: @KRyan Oh, I hadn't considered MathJax at all actually, this would be horrible in that use case. Probably horrible for the syntax they use on the chess site too, and I'm sure there's a couple of others. The other issue is that it turns out you don't keep your caret position when you toggle, so at the very least that needs to be fixed too. I did always think the scrolling was a horrible design too though, and having a way to jump to the insertion point would be nice; but I definelty don't think this soultion is _the_ ideal one.

Comment: I'm with @Robotnik here: sizing concerns would be irrelevant *if* the content area was fully-responsive (both large and small), but because there *are* constraints the editor can provide a misleading view of what will be visible / what will be cut off. Stuff like max height for code blocks makes that even more of an issue. Not everyone cares about presentation, but the system should accommodate those who do!

Comment: @Toastrackenigma No, the ideal one is probably size-by-side maintaining both scroll and caret position, but that has already been nixed since SE is adamant about their poor design decisions revolving around widths despite fairly massive community opposition. Which just puts this feature request as another example of the core functionality of the site being sacrificed on the altar of pushing new products.

Comment: One thing that isn't mentioned in this post: I use the current, live preview a lot when writing posts. When writing regular sized posts on a regular sized screen, I keep my eyes on the [live preview instead of the editor >90% of the time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwRbY.png), probably only taking them off if I have to add an image (as just pasting those in doesn't work and requires a click to confirm). Toggling to get this preview  is nowhere near as fluent or useful, and the argument that you can 'edit right in the preview' makes no sense to me as you can't actually write MD in the RT editor.

Comment: @Catija I think you might consider, perhaps, if your usage of the site might not be strongly atypical—you wrote this Question with the old editor, and you have written a large number of unusually-large posts as part of your role, but *that isn’t how most users generally interact with the site at all*. You might consider how that is skewing your perspective here.

Comment: @KRyan I've written hundreds of short posts across the network. I'm 100% willing to accept that my usage is atypical but I think it's fairer to say that everyone uses the platform differently and have different experiences. For example, some may only look at the rendering while drafting and others never look at it except when actually previewing. The reality is that everyone is different and all experiences are valid. We need to understand them all so we can find a solution that works for people.

Comment: @Catija The tone of your every comment on this request has been very much “Who needs this? No one needs this. This is dumb and pointless and we shouldn’t waste our time.” So while I agree entirely with your position that we all use the platform differently, and have different needs, and there is an importance to finding a solution for everyone, *you are the one who has been dismissing the needs of people with different use cases and advocating against there being any solution for us.*

Comment: @KRyan that's absolutely not my intention. I'm 100% in agreement that not having the preview is a huge change that I'm struggling to adapt to myself. I literally do not preview my posts on Teams because I can not take the risk of the RT mucking with my MD. But I need to understand your arguments so that we can find a solution that actually works and I'm trying to explain exactly why things like side-by-side are out of scope and non-options.

Comment: @Catija All right, that is not the impression I had gotten—side-by-side is one thing, but your apparent dismissiveness and negativity began before that was ever suggested. My suggestion, then, is that a “show/hide preview” toggle under the Markdown editor, similar to what we currently have for editing posts, be provided (and remember its state). That would result in no loss of functionality for those who prefer what we have (and we would reap other significant benefits, such as the in-line formatting in our Markdown, which I love, just not enough to give up the preview willingly).

Comment: This is absolutely a deal-breaker for me. I rely **so much** on being able see the produced output that I regularly resize the current editor text box to maximise the preview area so I can have full control over what the final rendering of my hand-crafted Markdown looks like. I just can’t get that same immediate feedback *and* control from the new editor.

Comment: This should be one of those cake and eat it too situations. The implementation of the rich text editor actually condenses the content back into markdown behind the scenes anyway... soo, we should keep *both*. There should be the same markdown editor everyone adores... **and** there should be a rich text editable preview pane. This is accomplishable because, as noted, the rich text implementation is already doing the heavy lifting, so any changes made in the editable pane, can easily be pushed to the markdown pane; the inverse (markdown -> preview) is already a solved problem (ty atwood/balpha)

Comment: no preview would be a disaster, togglable preview versatile though the best would be a distraction-free side-by-side preview....something that I had asked for here https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340425/669146

Comment: I was one of those who opted in for the new editor when it became an option on MSO. Sadly, I had to turn it off after a while exactly for this reason. I am a web developer, and for any web dev nowadays having the ability to preview your work *live* is a thing of vital importance. Yet SE decided to take a step backwards. If it is decided, please, give us **an option** to have the preview to the bottom or to the side.

Answer (score 76):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[Feature request opened on GH](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/19)

I’m not sure all users will understand how the ‘Link selection’ button works. (Hint: you have to select the text first, then the button will become enabled.) Other rich text editors I use regularly have an 'Insert Link' button where you can specify both the link and the text to display.

[image]

So something like this (excuse the bad mockup, hopefully the idea is clear):

[image]

Or enable the button at all times, and if nothing is selected, ask the user for a link (like the current editor) and insert it, with the popover visible so that users know they can edit both the link text and the link itself:

[image]

Comment: ...as does the current editor

Comment: @SonictheCuriouserHedgehog now is the best time to ask for enhancements I'd assume ;)

Comment: Your second suggestion is what we're currently doing in the "markdown" mode, ~to match the behavior of the old editor~. I'm not opposed to adding this type of functionality to the rich-text mode as well. Thank you for the suggestion! _edit: I was mistaken, the old editor behaves like your first suggestion._

Comment: This was completed in [release beta 1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/380295/51)

Answer (score 73):

> [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [Preview mode is now available](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382236/stacks-editor-markdown-preview-mode)

**If we [can't have the side-by-side preview](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360058/369802) due to technical limitations, we're going to need a better alternative than the Rich Text mode for previewing our Markdown**.  Even just another setting or toggle to put a live preview pane below the MD editor (like the preview works now) would be much better than having to toggle between MD and RT *editors*.

I use the current, live preview a lot when writing posts. When writing regular-sized posts on a regular-sized screen, I keep my eyes on the [live preview instead of the editor >90% of the time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwRbY.png), probably only scrolling up and taking my eyes off the preview if I'm pasting in an image and the dialog asks me to confirm, or if I decide to add another sentence to a paragaph. My usual workflow includes scrolling down the site to see the live preview over actually looking at the editor a lot of the time.

The post states that one reason the RT editor could be better than the current arrangement is that

> With the new editor, you see the preview by using the Markdown toggle to switch between Markdown and rich text modes and, because the rich text preview is part of the editor, you can edit right in the preview rather than having to find the edit window again. This is a lot more convenient for mobile users, too, with their smaller screens where scrolling through even a short post can mean a lot of work.

**Toggling between two *editor* modes to get an approximate idea of what your post may look like isn't a *live* preview of what you're writing.** It slows writing down. And saying that "you can edit right in the preview" isn't actually true: If I'm working in the RT editor, using it as both an editor and a preview at the same time, I can't continue writing in Markdown. I have to switch back, losing my "preview". Honestly, this is less than ideal. While it is less scrolling, it's also *not live*. And the RT editor does a worse job at showing how a post will look like than the current live preview does.

I like the idea of RT for mobile writing. I rarely use MD anyways when on my phone, just because asterisks, hyphens and hashtags [aren't a one-click thing](https://previews.123rf.com/images/grebeshkovmaxim/grebeshkovmaxim1803/grebeshkovmaxim180300249/97228382-smartphone-keyboard-mobile-phone-keypad-vector-template.jpg) when looking at your phone keyboard. But right now, and most of the time, *I'm writing my posts on a computer*. This means I have my hands a the keyboard, and a screen big enough to actually *show me what I'm doing*.

This whole post right now easily fits on my screen. And the preview of it is live, and it's something that I treasure. It makes writing this easier, quicker, more interactive, more fluent. **Whatever you do, for those people that do write using the Markdown editor, do not take away our live preview.** The Rich Text editor *isn't* a live preview, switching between the two breaks flow, and you can't write Markdown if your editor is in Rich Text mode while seeing it the result as the live preview allows now.

Comment: Just as a comment, I **do** routinely use Markdown in mobile. I’d give rich text a shot in that context, but honestly I doubt that I would prefer it even in that situation.

Comment: +1 for "I use Markdown on mobile," because selecting text is a pain.  I'd much rather just type an extra character, which my Android keyboard allows me to do with a long press from the normal keyboard.

Comment: @RyanM I don't need to select text on mobile with the new editor :) I can just press the **B** or *I* icon and start typing, and whatever I type will show up in italics or bold. It's the *one* thing I actually like about the Rich Text editor on mobile: No more switching keyboards with long button presses, and no more selecting text.

Comment: It would be really helpful to me if the devs said something about why they’re so opposed to markdown mode having a preview.  I assume there’s some reason behind it, but I haven’t seen it explained anywhere (maybe I missed it?). OP just says it’s embarrassingly old-fashioned and lists a bunch of software I don’t use or hate and says they don’t do it.  My main experience with this paradigm is Canvas and it’s an awful mess that I hate and can never get to behave the way I want it to.

Comment: Believe it or not the existing editor with preview works so nicely in mobile (i use Firefox on android). Almost 80 percent of my contribution on math.se is from mobile (ie from last 5 years or so even before they launched responsive design).

Answer (score 64):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)

[Bug report opened on GH](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/20)

This markdown:

```
# one heading

## two heading

### three heading

#### four heading

##### five heading

###### six heading
```

renders this preview in the rich editor:

[image]

It gets posted like such:

[image]

Comment: Side-note, actual 4th-, 5th-, and 6th-level headings might be nice. Rare that I want them (and there’s an argument to be made that anytime one does, it implies something structurally wrong with the post), but sometimes I feel it would be the right option and it’s unavailable.

Comment: Nice catch. There's been some internal discussion recently on whether we want to allow h4-h6 in markdown. Historically, we don't allow these because... well, nobody I asked could remember exactly why. In the meanwhile, it was more work to disallow these in the Editor, so they were left in. I'll resume discussions on allowing h4-h6 everywhere (not just in the new Stacks-Editor) and fix one or the other.

Comment: For what it's worth, I see no need for h4-h6 on Stack Exchange. We're not writing posts long enough, or we shouldn't be.

Comment: @BenKelly - there's an argument to be made that we [shouldn't be using h1 in posts at all](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271965/179041), because it's semantically incorrect to place it underneath the other h1 and h2 tags used to render the actual page

Comment: @Robotnik It be a bit confusing to have single `#` not work, though? Or, out of the expected behavior, anyway. I don't generally *use* H1, to be fair - you can see in the question here that my headers are all H2 and H3 - but I wonder if it's still reasonable to argue that post headers aren't the same? I'm pretty sure they're not actually formatted the same as page headers. That said, I'm not a web dev so maybe what I'm saying doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Catija, couldnt agree more. I feel that it would be highly confusing to have a "wrong" order in the headers. Although I do understand Robotniks point, that using H1 is rather wrong. I don't feel whe should disable it in any shape or form.

Comment: @Catija One could cause `#` to create an `h2` “under the hood,” so to speak (and cause the `h2` within Qs and As to look like the `h1` does now), and then `##` would produce an `h3`, and so on and so forth. The reason for this is that having a single `h1` on a page is a rather major web-accessibility standard—just last week my development team got slapped pretty hard for missing that one. Legal was **very** concerned about it getting us sued (that site is legally obligated to maintain a certain level of accessibility).

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings On RPG, we’re pretty often quoting things that have headers in them, which means if we want our own headers above them, we can push into `h4` territory (especially if we’re avoiding `h1` for accessibility reasons, which we should). Somewhat niche case, and even there it doesn’t come up often, but if it’s literally a matter of *removing a special block on them*, it seems worthwhile to have them.

Comment: @Catija making `#` output a `<h2>` (and bumping down `##` and `###` to `<h3>` and `<h4>`) would solve the semantic problem, and you could change the font size/styling to match, so visually there'd be no difference.

Comment: @Robotnik Related discussion under [this answer on _New post formatting_](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/353709/289905). The problem of changing the Markdown header semantics is that all posts would need to be migrated again, but which semantics should be used? If all `## Header`s become `<h3>Header</h3>`, then this breaks all posts of mine, since I use Markdown headers correctly all the time. Maybe, the migration script can figure out if `# Header` is used, or not, and based on that, shift everything one level down, or leave it as is. And then I’d need to relearn the Markdown semantics…

Comment: I believe SE now supports h4-h6 headings, so this is [meta-tag:status-completed].

Answer (score 59):

> "Preview is collapsed into the rich text view"

The preview is a necessary part of editing, particularly on some sites, and it is a great convenience to be able to see the entire post and proofread for redundancy.

Enabling the new editor on Meta Stack Exchange **breaks the editor** on other sites.

Take this question on Physics.SE for example: "[How the unitary operator acts on this vector?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/610390/170832)". Copy pasting the text here shows that without a preview it can be more difficult to read what you have written:

> [image: Example of complicated text]

Copying that same text into an answer on the Physics.SE site reveals a rendering issue, without the preview this wouldn't be obvious at first; leading to a lot of additional edits.

See this screenshot (editor **enabled** on Meta Stack Exchange):

> [image: Rendering Issue - Enabled]

---

---

See this screenshot (editor **disabled** on Meta Stack Exchange):

> [image: Rendering Issue - Disabled]
> -

Notice how enabling the Rich Text Editor caused misrendering on a different site where it wasn't enabled.

Answer (score 56):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[Bug report opened on GH](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/21)

When using an asterisk for italics, but not terminating it, like *this, the preview shows the rest of the line in italics but the rendered post won't.

[image]

Comment: We're using highlight.js to power the syntax highlighting for our markdown editor. Currently, the parser is not 100% commonmark compliant. This is something we've been working toward, but have not yet finished. This is currently on our list of things to fix. Thanks for the bug report!

Comment: @BenKelly in cases like this one (where it's arguably a user mistake), having some highlighting of the error might make sense. Maybe make the starting star red?

Comment: @BenKelly just checking: will cases like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQ7Qm.png) also be covered? Wikipedia links are full of underscores, but of course I always try to format them, and then it works fine.

Answer (score 52):

> [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)
> [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [Preview mode is now available](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382236/stacks-editor-markdown-preview-mode)
> [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) for having an "always start in this mode regardless of my last usage" preference

---

Sonic [already wrote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360058/369802) about missing the preview function. I do too, but I have some more reasons I miss the preview. Two of them are already known issues:

> While switching between modes does maintain your approximate scroll position, it doesn’t remember where your cursor was. Any time you switch, your cursor will move back to the top of the post rather than staying where you were.
> [...]
> Since the rich text preview will interpret your Markdown, any incorrect Markdown (MD) may be escaped out by the rich text editor. When you return to MD view, you will be able to fix these errors.

I've used this editor a few times on Teams, and I'm not really looking forward to turning it on here, because *it saves the last used option as a default*.

My usual workflow goes something like this:

1. Start writing a post in Markdown.
2. Look at the preview to see what it looks like.
3. Repeat 1-2 several times.
4. One final, careful look at the preview before posting.

While I think I may be able to get used to toggling a switch to see a preview (and not having to scroll), **the fact that my last-used option is saved is what makes this new editor so frustrating to use.**

Usually, my 'step 1' includes a pretty big chunk of text before I even look at the preview. But my step 4 means that every time I post something, I should either a.) return to Markdown mode first or b.) return the editor to Markdown mode when I start writing the next post. And I don't want to pay attention to that toggle, I just want to start writing. Which means I often run into the part where I write Markdown in the rich text editor, then have to switch and delete all the slashes that are now escaping the Markdown:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Is there anything that could be done, perhaps a profile setting, that means I *always* will start writing in Markdown mode, that will override the 'last-used' setting and perhaps even override site-specific defaults?**

Comment: Yes please! This bothers me too. Perhaps we can choose out of 3 options in the profile settings: 1. Use last setting (default) 2. Always use rich editor 3. Always use markdown editor

Comment: @Luuklag Perhaps more precisely: _Open editor in 1. Rich editing mode, 2. Markdown mode, 3. Last used mode._. "Always" sounds like it can't be changed from the editor itself.

Comment: I constantly run into this on Reddit, and untangling the unholy mess of escaped Markdown formatting is _such_ a pain. I don’t use Teams nearly as much but it has already happened to me there too.

Comment: It seems to me that the source of the problem is that you don't have any preview of the markdown code without switching the editor. Sure this works as a bandaid but it's really nothing but that: A bandaid.

Answer (score 44):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

[Feature request opened on GH](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/22)

> Tables - this button will create a default three-row, two-column table and have special menu options when in rich text mode that allows adding/removing rows and columns.

It would be nice to have some way to specify the number of rows/columns at the creation of the table (and not after), e.g. from Google Document:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, like with the image specifications.

Comment: I agree, this would be a nice feature to have. I'll see if I can't work it into the roadmap at some point. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Yes please. This would be great.

Answer (score 41):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[Bug report opened on GH](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/23)

I wholeheartedly support the requests to, in some form, [allow simultaneous viewing of the Markdown and the preview](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360058/165261).  If at all possible, I'd rather that be done in some way instead of this.  However, if that can't be done...

#### Toggling between Markdown and rich text to preview the result *without editing anything* should not be a destructive action

As one of the CMs [noted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360033/opt-in-alpha-test-for-a-new-stacks-editor/360058#comment1201776_360058):

> I literally do not preview my posts on Teams because I can not take the risk of the RT mucking with my MD

If the user *only* toggles between Markdown and rich text (for example, to see the preview) without making any changes, then toggling back should remember and restore the exact previous state.  It’s understandable that there can’t be a 1:1 correspondence between the two, and that editing something in the rich text view may result in different Markdown upon returning.

However, it should be possible to special-case “not changing anything” and return the user back to the previous state upon return, allowing the rich text editor to serve as a preview of the Markdown.

Comment: It is definitely the final intent for toggling back/forth to be a relatively non-destructive action (for the vast majority of cases). However, this is a lot harder than it may seem. We have a lot of these cases laid out in our [automated testing suite](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/blob/main/test/rich-text/markdown-serializer.test.ts#L88), with a number of them currently _failing_. Every time we come across a new edge case, we add a unit test ;). We're working to close the gap, but there's still quite a bit of work left to do so. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @BenKelly: Then it seems that there's something wrong with the editor architecture. Source markdown text should be the [single source of truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_source_of_truth). And the rich text editor should be built on top of it, it should not have its own internal model that doesn't map to source text 1:1 (with all its spacing and formatting variations). Switching editor must be non-destructive *always*, since 1) it's going to be used as preview, 2) editing posts in editor that were written in md and vice versa will introduce source differences and ugly diffs otherwise

Comment: In practice, this is why I’ll likely end up just using post as my “preview”, since you can always make edits after posting.

Comment: @user: I doubt if that kind of architecture can be implemented. Markdown is plaintext so the editing part is simple and implementing preview is tough. For rich text the editing is tough and I guess some form of compilation goes on to convert from the internal rich text representation to markdown. But expecting the compiled markdown to match a natively written markdown will be difficult.

Comment: It seems to be implemented such that switching the editor mode immediately discards the contents in the other editor.   A lot of this pain could be avoided if the other editor was simply hidden instead.   It only needs to be discarded if an edit is made in the visible editor.   If no edits are made, you could re-show the hidden editor and it would be guaranteed to be non-destructive.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller There already is a hidden textarea that contains the raw Markdown. Even then, the Markdown could simply be stored in a string — no need to use HTML at all.

Comment: This was completed in [release Alpha 2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/380295/51)

Answer (score 39):

> [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [Preview mode is now available](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382236/stacks-editor-markdown-preview-mode)
> [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned) MathJax is not yet integrated with the new preview mode, but this will be done before the Stacks Editor is released on any site that has MathJax

(I apologize for the uneven formatting in this post — it was written in the alpha-testing editor. I’m finding that even when in Markdown mode, the “syntax highlighting” features are too aggressive -- to the point that I am frequently unsure whether I am in Markdown mode or rich text mode. Moreover, the syntax highlighting in Markdown mode appears to be inaccurate. For instance, in Markdown mode, most of the text of this post is currently displaying in bold and italics, contrary to the case in rich text mode or when I publish. For another instance, apparently when I initially wrote three dashes below, at least two of them were written in rich text mode and converted to an em-dash, so that the separating line below initially did not render properly.)

My [comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360033/opt-in-alpha-test-for-a-new-stacks-editor/360142#comment1202300_360142) on [E.P.'s answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360142/289078) are already overflowing, so let me continue here. I strongly agree with everything in E.P.'s answer. Like E.P., I understand that there is no malicious intent behind these proposed changes and I understand that everybody is here in good faith, but like him I feel that the situation requires me to be blunt. Most of all, I agree with E.P.'s central thesis that

***This is extremely alarming from a MathJax perspective.***

Moreover, as [Rob points out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360033/opt-in-alpha-test-for-a-new-stacks-editor/360142#comment1201777_360142), the issues raised here will likely extend well beyond MathJax, to many other [site-specific formatting plugins](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298843/what-site-specific-post-formatting-settings-are-available/298844#298844).

Basically, when thinking about rich text,

> The MathJax-centric user is an entirely different use case from a non-MathJax-centric user.

As discussed in E.P.’s answer and in my comments there, it would be a joke to suggest that the MathJax-centric user compose their post in rich text mode. However, as currently envisaged, the MathJax-centric user would still be dependent on rich text mode, using it as a poor man’s  *MathJax previewer*.  In other words, in order to incorporate the MathJax-centric use case, the rich text editor would also be moonlighting as a MathJax previewer. This is a terrible idea because

***Fundamentally, MathJax is not compatible with a rich text representation.***

MathJax is designed to be written in a Markdown-like environment and compiled into a separate final output. So a MathJax previewer is a completely different sort of thing from a rich text editor. **Trying to make a rich text editor which is *also* a MathJax previewer is just asking for trouble** -- especially when the MathJax business is an afterthought anyway. As discussed in my comments to E.P.'s answer, many have tried to do this and failed. If you try to do this, I anticipate that you will eventually throw up your hands and stop fully supporting MathJax, and then we're back to the sort of rioting that I talked about in my [comments above](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360033/opt-in-alpha-test-for-a-new-stacks-editor#comment1202300_360142) (which were initially written under the mistaken understanding that there would be no Markdown mode at all, but which would be equally applicable in a scenario like this). To be clear:

> If MathJax were not fully supported, it is quite likely that MathOverflow would exercise its contractual option to leave the Stack Exchange network, and sites like Math Stack Exchange would be similarly unhappy.

**Solution:** For these reasons, the only solution I see is the following:

> There needs to be a dedicated preview for Markdown mode which is not dependent on the rich text editor.

This dedicated preview needs to fully support MathJax. Similarly, it needs to support plugins used at other sites like [chess](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179), [go](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/425), [furigana](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199) and [music notation](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2581). What MathJax and these plugins have in common is that it would be infeasible to create a rich text representation which fully supports them, especially if this rich text representation is also supposed to be functioning as a preview of the published output.

Here's the kicker: the requirements of the sort of preview needed for this solution are already met and exceeded by the current live preview. So such a preview is 100% feasible, and the only remaining question is whether Stack Exchange is willing to commit to supporting these communities by (re-)implementing the preview.

---

Here are some further thoughts:

As discussed [here](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/4859/2362), I agree that the live preview which exists in the current, non-rich-text, editor is in some ways an upgrade over many LaTeX editors because of its constant and automatic refresh. I don't need the refresh to be so frequent, or to be automatic, but it's a nice thing.

If there's no live preview in Markdown mode, I would prefer to have some form of preview I can see by hitting a "compile" button like in a standard LaTeX editor, without switching to rich text mode, for several reasons:

1. In rich text editors I've seen which have MathJax or Latex, the MathJax does not render fully before publishing (for example it may fail to render user-defined macros). There are good reasons for this -- MathJax / LaTeX is not designed with the understanding that there will be a one-to-one correspondence between the characters you're writing and the characters that will be output, so it would be infeasible to create such a correspondence for the purposes of a rich text representation.
2. For this and other reasons, I don't trust that what I see in the rich text representation adequately reflects what I will see when I publish. This makes it hard to catch errors before publishing.
3. It's cumbersome to switch frequently between modes, which I would need to do for previewing purposes (I would be writing exclusively in Markdown mode, for reasons discussed in E.P.'s answer and my comments there, and previewing in rich text mode).
4. One reason it would be cumbersome is that I anticipate there would be a time lag when switching modes.
5. Another reason it would be cumbersome is that I also anticipate that it would feel like the whole interface was being redone when switching modes, which is a jarring effect when all I want is to preview what I wrote.
6. The rich text interface would likely be designed with the presumption that the user was composing their post entirely in rich text mode, (and learning how to use the interface from that perspective) but since I would be using rich text mode exclusively for previewing, mine would be a completely different use case from what was intended. I anticipate this would lead to a frustrating experience for MathJax-centric users using rich text mode exclusively for previewing, both in learning and using the interface this way.
7. In order to toggle between rich text and Markdown content when writing a post of any length, I have to scroll up to access the toggle button. This is cumbersome for my anticipated use case, where I need to frequently toggle between modes, writing in Markdown and previewing in rich text mode. For one thing, I lose my place in what I'm writing, and have to find it again after switching modes. It’s doubly annoying because when I scroll up to toggle, I need to be sure I’m engaging the browser scroll rather than the editor scroll.

Comment: Your point 7 is exacerbated by the cursor jumping to the start of the text when you toggle between rich text and markdown.

Comment: Still freaking out. personally, the ability of mathjax to render expressions which are neither recognizable as linearly structured text nor in any way anticipated by things like the ms equation editor is not an abstract thing but an essential component of communication with others in my subfield and dozens of neighboring ones, primarily in the form of what are called “commutative diagrams”. For us, mathjax is already a significant downgrade over full latex in this regard but we’ve been able to get by. This was also mentioned by denis nardin in the comments to E.P.’s answer above.

Answer (score 32):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[Bug report opened on GH](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/25)

1. Start in Markdown mode
2. Write any text
3. Hit the Enter button

I expect the editor to take my cursor to the next line, but it doesn't. I need to hit Enter another time for the cursor to move, but when I restart typing words, they appear on the *third* line. In other words, the <kbd>Enter</kbd> button works, it's just the cursor that's lagging.

Reproducible in Firefox 86, but not in Chrome 88.

Comment: Having trouble reproing this - can you indicate your browser?

Comment: @Catija latest Firefox, latest macOS

Comment: @Catija same for me, FF Android.

Comment: Reproduced, Markdown mode, Firefox 86.0a1, Desktop, Win10.

Comment: I looks like this is related to [another `ENTER` bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360075/915027)

Comment: Strange... I _was_ able to reproduce in FF, but not Chrome. I'll update the post with details. Thanks for the report!

Comment: Also still reproducible in Firefox Nightly 87.0a1, Linux.

Comment: Found the same/similar bug. Pressing enter after a one-letter line (e.g. "a\n") enters what seems like a carriage return without moving the cursor (need to hit backspace twice to get back to where I was) and I seem to get a normal return without moving the cursor only in code blocks (e.g. "```python\n"). Not really tested much else though.

Comment: This was completed in [release Alpha 2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/380295/51)

Answer (score 31):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[Bug report opened on GH](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/24)

Quoting a multi-paragraph text messes up the paragraph segmentation.

E.g.

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam commodo turpis sapien, sit amet auctor felis vehicula at. Integer commodo vitae diam eget tristique. Vivamus au

Aliquam lobortis diam a dictum suscipit. Aliquam in lacus eu mi suscipit posuere et ac dolor. Vestibulum aliquet, ex eget molestie placerat, dolor mauris cursus libero, eget luct.
```

becomes

```
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam commodo turpis sapien, sit amet auctor felis vehicula at. Integer commodo vitae diam eget tristique. Vivamus au> u> Aliquam lobortis diam a dictum suscipit. Aliquam in lacus eu mi suscipit posuere et ac dolor. Vestibulum aliquet, ex eget molestie placerat, dolor mauris cursus libero, eget luct.t.
```

[image]

Comment: I'm able to reproduce this issue, but _only_ when using ctrl+a to highlight, rather than highlighting via mouse. I'm noticing a trend of these sorts of bugs and I have a theory on why they're happening. Hopefully they can all be fixed in one fell swoop. Thanks for the report!

Comment: @BenKelly  thanks, interesting yes I was indeed using ctrl+a

Comment: Similarly: select two paragraphs with CTRL+A and add multiline code or a numbered/bulleted list. It will break.

Answer (score 24):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[Bug reported opened on GH](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/27)

#### A triple-click selects the entire text in Markdown mode

It's a standard practice in modern text fields to double-click in order to select a single word and triple-click to select a single **paragraph**. This has worked in the old editor, works in the Rich Text editor, but does not work in Markdown mode and the entire text gets selected instead.

[image: Selecting paragraph in Rich Text vs Markdown mode]

Comment: Thanks for the report. I believe the reason for this is due to the underlying browser behavior. Triple-click works in rich-text mode because items there are independent elements (`<p>`, etc). In markdown mode, the entire surface is a single `<pre><code>` element. I agree that the current behavior is not entirely ideal, especially since it is a regression. I'll look into it and see what we can do.

Comment: Actually triple click should select a single sentence, not a whole paragraph. cc @BenKelly

Comment: @TylerH I've never seen the behavior you described in any web browser, text editor, or just about anything that displays text. Using a triple-click to select a paragraph/line is [pretty much the standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple-click).

Comment: @41686d6564 I said it should do that, not that other people do that already.

Comment: @TylerH Well, that's subjective then :) I, personally, don't see how that could be useful. Also, not to mention that classifying a piece of text as a "single sentence" is not particularly easy for a computer.

Comment: @41686d6564 It's pretty easy actually: a period followed by a space will catch most cases. Add a few regexes for common/known edge cases. When I need to select more than a single word, I find at least 9 times out of 10 I am trying to select a sentence rather than an entire paragraph. If things were nice we could have both and select a paragraph with 4 clicks. But I know that's difficult because typically the way it's implemented is to select the whole element (e.g. in web browsers), so unless people start parsing each sentence as an individual span...

Comment: @TylerH To select your sentence easily and quickly you can also double-click and drag.

Comment: This was completed in [release Beta 1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/380295/51)

Answer (score 24):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Can we have a symbol that resembles more of a table, then a calculator?

[image: Toolbar of the new rich text editor with the table symbol highlighted]

To me the large field in the top reminds me of a calculators display, with the buttons below it. I don’t recall ever using tables in which I merged columns in the title row.

Comment: ... and merged cells (iirc) are not supported at all by the current specs to begin with.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll run this feedback by our designers and see what we can do

Comment: Great to see you're working on this @BenKelly

Comment: We have the [new icon ready](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Icons/blob/production/src/Icon/Table.svg), I just haven't put it into place yet. Soon™

Comment: looks great @BenKelly

Comment: The new icon is now being used in the new editor, so [status-completed].

Comment: I edited accordingly @Justin. Thanks for the headsup

Answer (score 23):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

[Feature request opened on GH](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/29)

> The image and link tools will now add images and links inline rather than in the bibliography format. While the latter will still work, you’ll have to create it manually.

First off: This doesn't quite work yet.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
If you're going to allow manually adding a bibiliography format, please don't have switching editor modes mess with it (unless we're getting a different way to see a preview than the Rich Text editor :D)

---

Secondly, defaulting to inline links and images in Markdown breaks my workflow. I used the 'link' button a lot on longer posts with lots of links to research articles, as it would start a bibliography. The bibliography format made it easier to provide attribution, especially if I was reusing/quoting the same posts or articles multiple times in the same post. I could just type `[text][number of link to reuse]` and be done with it. While the syntax for inline links is easy to remember, it doesn't allow for this kind of reuse.

Another great benefit from the bibliography format in the 'old' editor, is that it adds images like this: `[![enter image description here][1]][1]`. It makes it much easier to hyperlink your image to another site, like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2191/369802) faq explains. Just change the second number, and put another entry in the bibliography list at the bottom of the post. The current editor inserts images using the `![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRHYf.jpg)` format, which gets messy quickly if you want to insert an extra hyperlink... it takes a lot more to memorize how to do that.

And, in long posts with lots of links, having them at the bottom of the post makes the work of potential editors a bit nicer, especially if the links used are long.

I'm not sure why this decision was made, but in my opinion it makes posts messier, not neater. I don't see many support questions on meta from people that are struggling with the bibliography format, so I don't think it's about 'ease of use'. And while the Rich Text editor is there for people that do struggle a bit with writing Markdown, that editor doesn't care how the links are written in Markdown, so those people will never have to know.

**As such I'd like to ask you to reconsider defaulting to the inline links, for both links and images.**

Comment: Regardless of which format is used by the editor to create links using the "link" button, changing back and forth between the Markdown view and the Rich Text view should ***never*** override the valid Markdown format which the user has chosen.

Comment: As to which to use as a default, it's probably a personal preference issue. My personal preference depends on what I'm writing. Sometimes bibliography format is definitely what I want, often because it makes reuse of a link easier (e.g. images with link, or multiple references in long text). Other times, I prefer inline (no scrolling around to find which entry it is I want in the bibliography). Overall, this should be something the user should be able to set. It would probably be a good idea to have a button which allows switching the whole document back and forth from one format to the other.

Comment: @Makyen a setting would be fine with me! Overall, if I'm using inline links I know the syntax and just use them, so that's why I prefer the button to default to bibliography... But I see there is a point for making it a preference so people that don't just type out inline links can use the button too.

Answer (score 22):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[Bug report opened on GH](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/26)

If you start writing in Rich Text mode and click the ‘Horizontal rule’ button, it’s automatically selected and you can’t deselect it, not even by clicking outside the answer box. Therefore, as soon as you start typing, the horizontal rule disappears.

[image]

Comment: Oh, interesting. I am able to reproduce locally. The behavior is similar to the [prosemirror demo editor](https://prosemirror.net/), but it handles the clicks as you'd expect. Short term workaround - hitting [enter] gets you a new line. Thanks for the report!

Comment: I would expect the HR button to add the horizontal rule _and an empty paragraph_ that you can start typing in.

Comment: This was completed in [release Alpha 2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/380295/51)

Answer (score 22):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[Bug report opened on GH](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/23)

The rich text editor does not escape HTML, but displays it in the preview as though it was escaped.

For instance, if I create a post with these contents:

> To create a link, use <a href=”https://stackoverflow.com”>text here</a>
>
> It is <this and > that

It will display as:

> To create a link, use text here
>
> It is that

Worse yet, converting back and forth corrupts it.  Note that it starts with escaped HTML entities, then goes to unescaped HTML, then removes chunks of the (invalid due to smart quotes) HTML.  It also breaks the quote formatting.

### [image: screen recording of post being corrupted as described above by switching between Markdown and rich text]

(I was unable to create this post in the new editor due to these bugs)

Comment: A small note - I'm not sure if by "new editor" you mean you disabled the editor before posting this - but what I do (often, to be honest) is to just never look at the preview - the re-rendering of MD only happens when you flip modes, so you can get around that issue by using MD mode only and just posting and then [ab]using the grace period to fix any errors.

Comment: @Catija I did indeed disable the new editor to post this. In this case, given the amount of tricky Markdown and the number of times I had to copy/paste back and forth to get the screen recording right, I wanted the preview for assurance. But for simpler stuff, that's a useful tip that I've used since. Thanks!

Comment: I reported a similar bug with `<code>` elements (the same?) on the GitHub issue tracker: [<code> not rendered correctly; incorrectly escapes when switching](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/12)

Comment: This was completed in [release Alpha 2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/380295/51)

Answer (score 21):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [images](/questions/tagged/images) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Make inserted images clickable (like in the former editor).

The new editor uses `![](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvbcS.png)`, the former uses:

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvbcS.png
```

Making inserted images clickable is useful for large images.

Comment: This is mentioned in the question's body as a known issue. But I sure hope this gets fixed or else editing old posts with images using the new editor will end up creating unnecessary edits.

Comment: @Dan thank you sorry I missed it

Answer (score 19):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[Bug report opened on GH](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/21)

In Markdown mode, the syntax highlighting doesn't know about *escaped asterisks* - it'll still show the words in between (including the trailing backslash) in italics.

[image]

Comment: The markdown syntax highlighter is not 100% markdown compliant yet. See [my comment above](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360033/opt-in-alpha-test-for-a-new-stacks-editor/360064#comment1201530_360038) with further explanation. Thanks for the report!

Answer (score 19):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)

[Feature request opened on GH](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/28)

Add the ability to easily change the language of a code block.

This was mentioned in another answer I believe, but I would like to add some mock UX for an idea of how it can work and look.

*I just added an arrow next to the language to make it look like a selector.*
[image]

When clicking on the language, a dialogue would appear with possible selection. For example, a list similar to the following.

```
✓ auto
-------
c#
css
html
javascript
plaintext
python
```

---

Another idea would be to show a dialogue similar to the image's details dialogue. Although this can be annoying and would much prefer the option above.

> [image]

Comment: Code blocks in rich text mode have a number of very obvious shortcomings in their current state and we will be working to improve them. A solution very similar to your first mockup is how I personally envisioned supporting this, so it is a little affirming to see someone else suggest it as well. Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 17):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)

[Bug report opened on GH](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/30)

In Rich mode, spoilers don’t have the “Reveal Spoiler” text:

[image]

Comment: and in Markdown mode, they don't have syntax highlighting (blockquotes do). I guess this falls under 'fine-tuning'.

Comment: Ah, nice catch! Thanks for the report!

Answer (score 16):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

1. Type some text
2. Paste something
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>
4. Watch your typed text being undone, and not your pasted "plaintext"

Comment: Ctrl + Z in Firefox has always been strange/unpredictable (typically two undos instead of one).

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q I agree, but in this case it just blatently skips the pasted item, no matter how many Ctrl + Z actions you perform

Comment: I'm able to reproduce this issue in Firefox, but not Chrome. I suspect the "something" in "Paste something" will alter the behavior somewhat as well. I'll take a look into this and see if I can't find a root cause. Thanks for the report!

Answer (score 16):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

[Bug report opened on GH](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/31)

If I want to add some fancy keyboard buttons using `<kbd>X</kbd>`

<kbd>X</kbd>

They show up perfectly in the rich formatting, but when putting your cursor behind the X will make you type inside the kbd element. There is no way to type anything on that same line. Not even forcing your your cursor to appear there by double clicking (as would work in MS Word).

Reproduction steps:

- Start in markdown mode
- Add the following text:

  ```markdown
  <kbd>X</kbd>
  ```
- Switch to rich text mode
- Placing the cursor inside the kbd element allows you to edit it, but your cursor is trapped and cannot leave the element

Comment: Oh, fun... Thanks for the report! I am able to reproduce the issue. I'm going to edit the post to add a few notes for reproduction purposes.

Answer (score 16):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

#### Discarding a draft doesn’t clear the editor in both modes

1. Start typing an answer.
2. Wait until the draft is saved and the <kbd>Discard</kbd> button appears.
3. Click <kbd>Discard</kbd>.
4. It says “Draft discarded” as usual but the text stays in the editor.
5. When trying to leave the page, a warning message about “losing changes” is displayed.

[image: Draft discarded but the editor is not cleared]

Comment: I wonder if this is a new bug at all. I've seen many inconsistent behaviours with drafts. Sometimes I copy some part of a post in the answer box as a "staging ground" to format it before making an edit or just to experiment (e.g., a stack snippet). I don't intend to post that as an answer but I sometimes find I'm unable to discard. Other times I've *started* writing an answer I intend to finish later on a different computer but re-visiting the same answer doesn't bring up the draft. I wouldn't be surprised if this is an old bug.

Comment: @VLAZ I've had the second issue you describe many times before. Saving drafts is very inconsistent indeed. Regarding the first issue (which is what this bug report is about), I've never experienced it with the old editor. As long as the "Discard" button is visible, clicking it always cleared the text for me.

Comment: Just to be clear, the first issue I mentioned is that I never actually get a Discard button. So, the text just stays there. I've even occasionally deleted it manually (Ctrl+A -> Delete) only to have it show up again when I open the page again. That last one *might* have been fixed for a while, I don't think I've seen it within the last year, at least. What you describe is Discard being there and not working. I've not experienced this but I just wonder if it's not an old bug. In either case it probably should be fixed, of course.

Comment: Thanks for the report! Believe it or not, I got the code in to support this just the other day for another dev. They have a fix in their branch, along with other features, but I can get a dedicated fix out for this independently.

Comment: Bug fixed! The change went out earlier today

Answer (score 16):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[Bug report opened on GH](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/37)

### Table cells misalign if you add URLs to a cell

I attempted to create this table with URLs in the first column:
[image]

Adding the URLs to the text causes the table formatting to break. Cells become misaligned. This happens when you are creating/editing the table via rich text and when you are using markdown.
[image]

Steps to repro:
Create table, add URL to text either via markdown or using the "insert link" icon

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| [Cell 1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360033/opt-in-alpha-test-for-a-new-stacks-editor/361096#361096) | Cell 2 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 |

**Was able to do this successfully in MSE editor, had misalignment issue in Teams editor**

Comment: How did you do this? I tried to reproduce this because I was curios, I don't seem to able to do this, neither with rich text nor markdown. Not even when I deliberately try to screw the editor up by choosing multiple columns etc.

Comment: Just tried to repro here, and I was able to do it successfully. Failure happened in Teams editor. Added note. @Polygnome

Comment: This was completed in [release Alpha 2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/380295/51)

Answer (score 15):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

While adding an answer, if I copy text in markdown mode and paste it in rich text editor mode, the text gets pasted as code block. I would rather the text gets copied to the clipboard unformatted while in markdown mode.

I'm using Firefox, but unsure if this is reproducible elsewhere.

---

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> the following selection
[image: markdown mode]

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> in the rich text editor mode
[image: rich text editor mode]

Comment: The reason for this is that our markdown editor is one large `code` block. We've had this discussion internally and my personal opinion is that _markdown is code_ and should be treated as such. However, I do definitely see both sides of the argument. Marking as "review" for now. Anyone who disagrees with me can upvote this answer to show support ;). Thanks for the report!

Comment: @BenKelly Ah that makes sense, but it seems that using `code` is causing several issues. There are at least [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360115/) [other](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360111/) answers reporting a bug that seems to be related to the `code` tag.

Comment: I think we should not mix  makrdown mode with RichEdit mode. I mean if you copy yours content in one mode, then you can not expect that pasting them in the other one mode you will get the same results. I mean you could not use both modes at the same time. You have to choose which one you want to use. And you can not pass your content between editor modes. I know for testing you coudl switch from one to the other, but not mix/copy content between them.

Comment: @MichałLipok I don't expect the rich text editor to parse the markdown when pasting from the markdown editor, but at least having the same result I would get when pasting the same content from some outside plain text editor, or entering the same text directly via keyboard. In principle, the markdown box is unformatted plain text, not code.

Answer (score 14):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) / [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

<sub>I'm not sure if this classifies as a bug but it’s something that has always worked and doesn’t work with the new editor.</sub>

So, I’m using a spell/grammar checker [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/grammarly-for-chrome/kbfnbcaeplbcioakkpcpgfkobkghlhen) which works with most text fields. It works with the old editor, with the new Rich Text editor but for some reason, it does not work when switching to markdown:

[image: Rich Text editor vs Markdown mode]

Now, that’s a shame because this extension has been really helpful in writing (and especially, editing) posts, which a lot of it will be done in the Markdown mode.

Is it possible to fix this issue or should I wait until the new editor goes live and then take this “bug report” to Grammarly?

#### Update:

Checking the element in Chrome’s developer tools shows that the markdown text is wrapped in a `<code>` tag and that’s likely the cause:

> ```html
> <pre class="s-code-block markdown">
>     <code>test</code>
> </pre>
> ```

Comment: Not sure if SE would support this. But if they don't, we may have a shot by asking Grammarly to support the new editor instead.

Comment: Thanks for the report! My official stance on this is "we don't want to support external extensions/scripts that mess with our page", but realistically, I'll take a peek and see if it isn't something that would be an easy remedy. Your hypothesis about it not spell checking code blocks seems likely to me.

Answer (score 14):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)[mobile-chrome](/questions/tagged/mobile-chrome) [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro)

[Feature request opened on GH](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/34)

If I want to start a post off with a bolded statement (usually a **TL;DR**), on mobile I can't see what I'm doing if I use the Rich Text editor, as the 'Bold' label doesn't disappear until I tap the white pop-up:

[image]

[image]

It would be nice if these things a.) weren't put in a place where they block part of the editor or b.) automatically disappeared (perhaps a short time-out?), so that I can start typing without having to manually dismiss them.

Comment: Nice catch. I'll add to our bug list. Thanks for the report!

Comment: @BenKelly Our popover library's trolling us a bit on this. I have it spec'd out that those popovers would appear as `top`, but they're flipping based on the editor as a container instead of the full page layout. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @AaronShekey Even if the popups could correctly align themselves beyond the edges of the editor container, what happens if they’re too close to the edges of the viewport, especially when the sticky top bar is disabled?

Comment: @AaronShekey Native info bubbles aren't enough? That's what you use on the Markdown toggle. I find the current ones being on my way all the time.. they are also, pretty bulky imo.

Comment: We could not repro this on any mobile browser

Comment: @YaakovEllis I can no longer repro this myself either... after more than a year, I'm guessing something must've changed.

Answer (score 13):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[Feature request opened on GH](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/19)

In the old editor, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> brought up this:

[image]

Whereas pressing that in the new editor brings up `[text](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)`.  I would like to have this popup in the new editor when I press the keyboard shortcut, since I can simply paste my link in there and edit the link description, not the link *and* the description.

Comment: Ideally we’d get rid of that hotkey entirely since it masks the (to me) vastly more useful browser hotkey for focussing the address bar. 10 times out of 10 when I press Cmd+L I want *that*, not to insert a link (I can do that just fine with Markdown, thank you).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! We have a few reports asking about a hyperlink "widget" for markdown mode, similar to the old editor. Marking as "review" for now.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I don't often want to focus the address bar while writing a question, and secondly, F6 does the same job in fewer keypresses

Comment: @Pureferret Not in Chrome on macOS. Key combinations OS/browser specific, but web apps generally should *never* override them, unless they provide a fully-featured substitute for the same function. — Anyway. I *do* want to focus the address bad while writing answers; quite frequently, in fact. Just because you happen not do to do this doesn’t mean my use-case is any less valid.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I'll be honest, until this question I wasn't even aware of the Ctrl+L command. I completely agree that in general they shouldn't override these, but as this is existing behaviour I wouldn't argue we should take it away. How did you get around this command before?

Comment: @Pureferret I didn’t, I always swore at the stupid editor. Swearing is therapeutic. :-)

Comment: @KonradRudolph then I'll have to do the same if they take it away

Comment: @Pureferret At least in Chromium Edge, I have to press F6 twice to focus the address bar. So it's the same amount of keypresses as Ctrl+L, but IMO the latter is more convenient.

Comment: This was completed in [release Beta 1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/380295/51)

Answer (score 13):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

[Bug report opened on GH](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/32)

In the current editor using nested `<sub></sub>` html is supported, and can achieve an extra small fontsize. For example: `<sub><sub> Extra Small </sub></sub>`

When writing this in the Markdown version of the RT editor, and then switching over to RT the first `<sub>` gets trimmed, the last `</sub>` doesn't: `<sub>Extra Small</sub> </sub>`

Either nested `<sub>` statements should be supported, or the last closing argument should also be trimmed.

Comment: In the current editor, any HTML-valid combination of `<sub></sub>` and `<sup></sup>` is supported (or at least functional), including nesting one element within another. It might result in text which was too small to read, but it produces the correct HTML output.

Comment: Thanks for the report. HTML is... tough and there's still a number of edge cases we're running into. I'll see if I can't get to the bottom of this one, as I'm sure it affects other nested html structures, not just `<sub>`

Comment: Please tell me, this editor isn’t using regexes to parse HTML…

Comment: Apparently empty elements like `<sup></sup>` are removed when switching from rich-text to Markdown. Does this also explain why no `<code></code>` is present when performing the steps to reproduce from [It is impossible to place your cursor immediately after an inline code block in rich text mode](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360412/289905)?

Answer (score 12):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

Can we add support for inserting a table directly from MS Excel by copy pasting? Right now it gets added as a screenshot, which is less convenient than a table in almost all cases.

This has previously been reported as a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320162/cant-paste-data-to-question-get-prompted-for-image), with reference to [this MSO post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381951/copy-paste-from-microsoft-word-triggers-image-upload). The accepted answer there states that you could circumvent uploading as image by using "paste special" <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>. Doing so on a simple 2x4 Excel range yields the following (indented as code):

```
Feb Mrt
    
32  32
10  15
```

PS: Using MS Excel 16.44 on macOS

Comment: Dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/358890/282094

Comment: @Rob even older: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320162/cant-paste-data-to-question-get-prompted-for-image

Comment: Luuk, even older than [your example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360033/opt-in-alpha-test-for-a-new-stacks-editor/360046?noredirect=1#comment1201499_360046) is this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/381951/3648282 - **both** of those are **different** Q&A's (not about tables) ***but*** the reason is probably the same; any clipboard data is stored, and thus pasted, as an image.

Comment: @rob It is stored in a multitude of formats, the editor just isn't capable of picking anything other then the first (which is Image/PDF) IIRC.

Comment: We do support some amount of content pasting, but tables are "special". Due to how restricted the markdown support is, there's very little that we can do in most cases. A "normal" paste should at least paste text, rather than a screenshot, which is... odd. The only way it could possibly do that is if Excel added image data into the paste data. I'll see what we can do to support basic table pasting from Excel. It works from Google Docs (with limitations), so I'm not sure why we can't support some limited Excel as well.

Comment: Today I checked this with [osTicket](https://osticket.com/) which use [Redactor](https://imperavi.com/redactor/) editor , and it works. I mean I can copy Tablee in OpenOffice Calc and paste to `Redactor` editor. After saving content to DB this editor show it as a table ( I'm able to select text in rows and in columns ).

Comment: @BenKelly How is it implemented on https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables ?

Comment: @BenKelly I think Excel programming questions can be split into three subcategories: worksheet functions; Excel-file-as-data; and manipulating the Excel application object model, either using VBA or Office.js. The real value for pasting Excel data as a table is for the first two questions, where generally formatting and the like doesn't matter at all; it is absolutely appropriate to paste just the text without any formatting. For the third category, a screenshot makes more sense.

Answer (score 12):

[status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)

[Bug report opened on GH](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/33)

Pasting a network link doesn't automatically make it a link in the preview when in rich mode:

Toggling Markdown On and Off again does make the link look properly formatted:

Paste link in rich mode:
[image]

Link when switched to Markdown mode:
[image]

Link when switched back to rich editor from Markdown mode:
[image]

Comment: Yup! This is in progress.

Answer (score 12):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro)

[Bug report opened on GH](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/36)

Copying quoted text from Markdown mode into a text editor like Visual Studio Code and back invisibly breaks the Markdown to insert extra line breaks between the lines of the quote.  Toggling back and forth between rich text and Markdown reveals the extra line breaks.

[image: Copy-pasting between windows inserting linebreaks]

This isn't a contrived scenario: I often compose longer posts in a separate text editor so that I don't lose them if something happens to the browser tab.

Comment: Interesting... thanks for the report! Copy/pasting from other editors is something I explicitly would like to support, especially in rich-text mode. Not sure why extra / invisible line breaks are being added here, but we'll take a look into it.

Comment: +1 to making edits in a separate editor due to browser paranoia/the possibility that I may have to step away for it for a while.

Comment: We were not able to reproduce this

Answer (score 12):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)

## Add `<small>` formatting

As I’ve [argued elsewhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/354008/1968), `<small>` formatting is eminently useful (for footnotes, side-notes, just generally less important stuff — small print). Furthermore, whether or not it’s officially supported, in practice **it is used extensively**, using dirty hacks (via `<sub>`/`<sup>`), which negatively impact accessibility.

Comment: At this time, we're focusing on parity with our existing markdown support. I'd recommend opening this as its own, separate feature request. Side note: I'd _love_ to support something like this (and `sub/sup`) first class in Markdown (without html), but there's no official support in the Commonmark spec. That hasn't stopped us from adding our own extensions, along with other popular extensions with a generally agreed on syntax, but it'll take a bit of discovery to ensure we're not inventing our own wacky syntax when nearly everyone else has mostly settled on a single implementation.

Answer (score 11):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

[Bug report opened on GH](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/35)

> Tables - this button will create a default three-row, two-column table

For Markdown mode, this is correct. For Rich Text mode, a four-row, three-column table is created:

[image]

(tagging this as [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) because I don't think the difference is intentional, if it *is*, the introductory post needs to be updated)

Comment: Ooh, good catch. The code that inserts these are different based on which editor you're in, so this was very likely an oversight during implementation. Thanks for the report!

Comment: Off-by-one error.

Answer (score 11):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[Feature request opened on GH](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/50)

#### Indent code by pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> while in a code block

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> shortcut is what I always used to indent/unindent code blocks but...

- it only worked for one-level indentation,
- not many users knew about it, and...
- currently, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> does nothing while in a code block in the Rich Text mode anyway.

Enabling <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> in code blocks will be a great addition.

Comment: I assume this will break when they roll this new editor out, but in the meantime, there's a user script for tab indentation that I have found very useful over the years: [Better handling of indentation and the TAB key when editing posts](https://stackapps.com/q/3247)

Comment: Agreed! This is a personal pet feature that I'd love to add, but it unfortunately didn't make it in time for the alpha. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 11):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[Bug report opened on GH](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/21)

**TL;DR:**

In Markdown mode, inline formatting is still being applied even if the starting token is escaped with backslash

---

If you are in Markdown mode and use italic and bold inline formatting on text with newlines (which would create block element paragraphs), then switch to rich text, the formatting is removed. That is probably fine and intended since you can't have block level elements within inline elements. However, if you switch back to Markdown mode, the asterisks used to create are escaped with backslashes but **the italic formatting is still rendered**.

Here are some images to illustrate:

1. In Markdown mode with newlines between the text and wrapped in three asterisks for bold and italic formatting:

   [image]
2. Switched to rich text mode and formatting is removed (probably expected behavior since we can't have inline formatting on block level elements):
   [image]
3. After switching back to Markdown mode, asterisks are escaped with backslashes, but it's still rendered with italic formatting:
   [image]

Comment: Thanks for the report! I commented on a related bug [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360038/395497). The short answer is that our syntax highlighting is not 100% commonmark compliant, but this is something that's currently on our list of things to fix.

Answer (score 11):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[GH #49](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/49) and [GH #64](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/64)

**It is impossible to place your cursor immediately after an inline code block in rich text mode**

1. Type in some text, highlight and `Ctrl-K` to make into an inline code block
2. `<Right-Arrow>` to deselect the highlighted text and place your cursor immediately after
3. `Ctrl-K` to turn off the inline code block
4. Start typing (don’t hit the spacebar first no space)
5. Use your arrow keys to place the cursor immediately before your first plaintext character after the inline code block (or just use your mouse)
6. Hit the spacebar or type a character

**Expected**: you are typing in plain text, and not in the inline code block

**Currently**: you type inside the inline code block. There is no way to get to the plaintext section immediately after the inline code block. The workaround is to type a space at the end of the inline code block, highlight it, `Ctrl-K` to toggle the inline code block off for that space. But that is really annoying.

Ideally, if you are at the end of the inline code block, you could use your right arrow key to move out of the inline code block and to the spot right after it in the plaintext area, and then use your left arrow key to move back into the tail of the inline code block. (This is how Slack handles the transition between inline code block and plain text areas).

Comment: Thanks for the report! I'm able to reproduce this issue and I've opened a bug report on our public repo

Answer (score 11):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[Feature request opened on GH](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/51)

Tag badges can't be created from rich-text mode.

[image: tag badges can't be created from rich-text mode]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! This is something we'd like to add in the near term, but there needs to be some discovery on how the UI would look first (extra button vs dropdown vs ...)

Comment: @BenKelly It would be nice if it worked similarly to entering a tag in the search box as a first step. My initial expectation was that I would just wrap a known tag name in brackets, and not necessarily get a list of valid tags. A list to choose from would be detrimental if I was trying to suggest a new tag or synonym and I think it's overkill for a text editor.  If the brackets are too similar to text, something like `[tag:discussion]` would work.

Answer (score 11):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

[Bug report opened on GH](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/151)

Issue when switching the Markdown setting on and off when there is a new line in a table:

[image]

```
Something else<br />that's rather long
```

Tested with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate + Google Chrome Version 88.0.4324.146 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: I suspect this is because tables don't technically support newlines (by spec), but you're "cheating" with an explicit `<br>` html tag. I'd have to look into it, but I have a feeling this is a combination of bugs that is causing this behavior. Thanks for the report!

Answer (score 11):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

[Bug report opened on GH](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/40)

After double-clicking a word to highlight it, if you quickly right-click the highlighted word to bring up the context menu, the rest of the paragraph will be highlighted, which should not be the case.

Normal behavior: (Note no new text is highlighted when context menu opens)

> [image: Normal text highlighting behavior]

New behavior: (Entire paragraph is highlighted before menu opens)

> [image: New, broken text highlighting on context menu open]

Repro steps:

1. Double-click word in a paragraph
2. Immediately right-click highlighted word

Answer (score 11):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

As the editor currently exists, it allows image Markdown to be typed in rich text mode without any indication that the user is doing something which won't render correctly. This can be problematic.

Take [this recent case](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406335/stack-overflow-private-for-teams-does-not-offer-preview-of-question) from a Teams user posted to MSO ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5q1W.png) in case the post doesn't stick around). They typed the *Markdown* for a post image (`![image](...link...)`) in the *rich text* mode of the editor, which lead them to believe that the preview just wasn't enabled for the editor. They failed to see that this editor was different than the one across the rest of Stack Exchange, and then were confused by why their (syntactically correct) Markdown image didn't render.

I'm proposing that there be some mechanism in place to guard against this; maybe some sort of warning for when valid markdown is detected in rich text mode. Another possibility would be to automatically translate that image markdown to the WSIWYG equivalent, just like the editor does when you type `>` for blockquote or `#`'s for a heading.

Answer (score 10):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [images](/questions/tagged/images) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[Feature request opened on GH](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/43)

Clicking the "Insert image" button opens up the following:

[image: Image of the image insertion tool]

Which used to feature the ability to click the "paste" link to quickly paste an image or link. Here's how it looked in the older editor's tool:

[image: Image of the older image insertion tool]

And once you clicked "paste," you were greeted with a user-friendly textbox:

[image: Image of the older image insertion tool, expanded]

I take a lot of screenshots using third-party snipping tools (which auto-upload them to various image hosting sites, copying the link to my clipboard in the process), and I liked quickly uploading them using the "paste" link in the older tool, as it very quickly uploads them to Stack Exchange's imgur hosting service. Now, the only option available to me is to open a file dialog. I *can* paste the link directly into the "File name" portion of the open file dialog, but the ability to quickly paste a link without being taken to another window was far more streamlined.

Could you reinstate the ability to paste a link in the image insertion pane?

Comment: I personally use a screenshot program that offers me the option to copy to clipboard directly. I just paste that into my SE editor, saves uploading once. Just for your consideration.

Comment: Yeah, I could easily tweak it to just copy the image itself, but eh. I preferred the original functionality.

Comment: We do support pasting image data into the editor, even outside the image pane, but I can see where we are missing the ability to paste a link to an outside resource. Pasting image _data_ from basically any source (copy/paste an image from your file explorer, right click > copy image in your browser, etc) works. That being said, pasting a _text link_ to an image resource is currently not implemented. I'll see what we can support there. Thanks for the report!

Comment: This was completed in [release Beta 1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/380295/51)

Answer (score 10):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

[Bug report opened on GH](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/38)

In Rich Text mode, type some text, click the Blockquote button, then click Bulleted list:

[image]

Now when I click the Blockquote button again, I expect the blockquote to disappear (the gray outline indicates it's some kind of toggle, right)? Nope, it's the bulleted list that disappears:

[image]

(In Markdown mode, the bulleted list *replaces* the blockquote formatting, which is OK behaviour IMHO; especially, the buttons don't have a gray outline.)

Comment: Oooh, nice catch! I would definitely agree with your assessment that the blockquote should be toggled off, but the list should stay intact. I can imagine some edge cases, such as "blockquote > list item > blockquote", but ideally clicking "blockquote" in that case would only remove the inner blockquote and leave the outer alone. Thanks for the report!

Answer (score 10):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> inserts a newline instead of saving the post.  In the old editor, this provided a convenient way to save the post from the keyboard.  <del>Since one can enter a newline by simply pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, Ctrl+Enter has no other special functionality,</del> Since the special functionality it has (leaving code blocks) is also handled by <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> (and could also be addressed [in other ways](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360070/165261)), it would by ideal if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> continued to save the post as it did previously.

Comment: CTRL+Enter have now special feature, take a look here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360070/915027

Comment: Shift+enter also (perhaps counterintuitively?) exits a code block.  That said, I think your idea would eliminate the need for either unintuitive key combination to be required to exit a code block.

Comment: Normally/usually `Enter` and `SHIFT+Enter` is used to add two different kind of new line, and `CTRL+Enter` for post message (or to add/jump to next page in "document" editors). Currently there is a problem with `SHIFT+Enter` (wondering how to describe the issue I notice)

Comment: `SHIFT+Enter` pasted between two lines makes editor unable to normally use `KeyDown` and `KeyUp` key’s to go up/down between the entered text.

Comment: In Rich Text Mode, Enter starts a new paragraph, while Ctrl+Enter is only a newline. This is pretty standard for rich text editing and follows how most text editing software does it.

Comment: @Polygnome That's not my experience. A lot of text-editing software uses Shift+Enter to enter a newline.  Ctrl+Enter creates a page break in both Microsoft Word and Google Docs.

Answer (score 10):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[Bug report opened on GH](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/23)

Turning Markdown on or off removes any newline character at the beginning of the post.

E.g.:

[image]

becomes:

[image]

Comment: It probably shouldn't do that, but why would you *ever* need a newline character at the beginning of a post?

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q might happen during editing eg when placing the quote before writing some sentence before the quote. Which is what happened to me when I found the bug.

Comment: Oh, interesting. I agree that it definitely shouldn't be trimming leading whitespace, even though I would also agree that leading whitespace probably isn't ideal in the first place ;). Thanks for the report!

Comment: @BenKelly - Isn't leading/trailing whitespace trimmed on submit anyway? i.e. removing the trimming while switching to/from Rich mode won't negatively affect the final post.

Comment: @Robotnik no but that's annoying when editing the post

Comment: This was completed in [release Alpha 2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/380295/51)

Answer (score 10):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred)

Toggling between Rich text and Markdown moves the cursor to the start.
This makes it impossible to switch between modes and continue typing on-the-fly.

Comment: This is explicitly mentioned in the question. Building it so that it remembers cursor location, from what I understand, is not a simple thing, so it was intentionally omitted.

Comment: To echo Catija's statement, this is a fairly hard problem to solve, so we decided to focus our efforts elsewhere for the initial release. This is something that I hope to solve in the future, though.

Comment: This makes rich-text mode next to useless as a markdown preview.   I'd be OK with not having a live markdown preview if clicking the rich checkbox and then unchecking it was non-destructive, including keeping your cursor position.

Comment: I'm sure why this is "hard."   JavaScript has the ability to view and set caret position.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512528/set-keyboard-caret-position-in-html-textbox

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I don't think setting/viewing the caret position is the hard part. It's making the editor know that the previous position before switching to markdown at character index X is now at character index Y due to the changes done in the markdown editor, for example. Especially since the changes in characters aren't 1:1 between richtext mode and markdown mode.

Comment: @Dan Thats actually not that hard of a problem, many editors e.g. Overleaf can already do it. StackEdit.io has Scroll Sync, which also syncs positions between Markdown and Rich Text. Keeping caret position is actually easier than scroll sync...

Answer (score 10):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [tooltips](/questions/tagged/tooltips) [keyboard-shortcuts](/questions/tagged/keyboard-shortcuts) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[Feature request opened on GH](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/46)

Can we have the toolbar tooltips show the keyboard shortcut for inserting that element into a post, like the previous editor did, so it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Yes! This is currently planned, but the implementation needs a little more work. Thanks for the report!

Comment: @BenKelly More of a request than a report, but thanks anyway ;)

Comment: This was completed in [release Beta 1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/380295/51)

Answer (score 10):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[Bug report opened on GH](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/53)

The following Markdown will produce two images next to each other, but the preview will show them under each other:

```
![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQfjes.png)
![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7aHes.png)
```

[image]
[image]

This is what the editor shows:

[image]

Comment: I didn't even realise you could put images side by side at all. ._.

Comment: @BenKelly this is not exclusive to two images following each other, the same happens when your are in rich mode, insert an images, and type under it. The preview will show the text on a new line, while the rendered version will show the text on the same line as the image. Also see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/362260/361484 (deleted now, as it is mostly a dupe of this)

Comment: @BenKelly this is not exclusive to this alpha editor test, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362441/table-markdown-in-a-question-breaks-only-when-posted It probably is a problem with how the preview works.

Comment: This was completed in [release Alpha 2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/380295/51)

Answer (score 10):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[Bug report opened on GH](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/48)

**Pasting into an inline code block doesn’t work**

1. Start typing.
2. Copy some text (from anywhere) to your clipboard
3. Use the `Ctrl-K` shortcut to start a new inline code block or just click the button
4. (Optional) start typing in your inline code block (the bug happens either way)
5. Paste your text (`Ctrl-V`)

**Expected**: The text will be pasted into the inline code block, and the cursor will be at the end of the text

**Currently**: The text is pasted as plain text. If there had been text in the inline block, the block closes and the text appears after it. If there hadn’t been text in the inline block, the block vanishes, never to be seen again (if you toggle to markdown mode, there is no evidence of the block.

The same also happens if you select any text within the inline code block and then paste - if you have three words in the block, and select the middle one, then paste, it will split the inline code block into two (first and third words) and then add your pasted text as plain text between the two inline code blocks.

Comment: Thanks for the report! I am able to reproduce this issue. I've filed an issue on our public repo

Comment: This was completed in [release alpha 2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/380295/51)

Answer (score 10):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

[Bug report opened on GH](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/39)

### Description

When editing a code block in rich text mode, not all formatting buttons are disabled.

When they are clicked, *interesting things* happen:

- Heading

  When clicked, nothing seems to happen, but when the "Markdown" switch is toggled (or if the post is submitted), the code block's first line becomes a heading, and the remaining lines appear as regular text in a single line:

  [image: Heading bug]
- Blockquote

  When clicked, nothing seems to happen, except that the language indicator of the code block breaks. When the "Markdown" switch is toggled (or if the post is submitted), the code block gets contained by a blockquote:

  [image: Blockquote bug]
- Image

  Inserting an image breaks the code block into two parts (separated by the image), the part below the image appears as regular text. When the "Markdown" switch is toggled (or if the post is submitted), the part below the image appears in a single line.

  [image: Image bug]
- Table

  Inserting an image breaks the code block into two parts (separated by the table). If the table is selected and deleted, the code blocks rejoin (expected).

  [image: Table bug]
- Horizontal line

  Inserting a horizontal line breaks the code block into two parts (separated by the line). If the line is selected and deleted, the code blocks rejoin (expected).

  [image: Line bug]
- Link

  When some text is selected within the code block, the link button is enabled, clicking it animates the button but does nothing.

  [image: Link bug]

*<sub>I'm sorry for the low-quality GIFs, but I couldn't upload in higher quality because of the 2MB limit. I hope they are good enough to repro.</sub>*

### Suggestion

All formatting buttons should be disabled in code blocks.

Wrapping the code block in a blockquote might make sense (so it can stay enabled), but it should be fixed to do what it should in this case.

Comment: Oh wow, definitely agree that these block modifiers should _not_ be allowed inside code_blocks. This _used_ to be the case, so I suspect there was a regression somewhere along the line that got missed. Thanks for the report!

Comment: [Increase the file size limit for animated GIFs (currently 2 MiB)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360935/178179)

Answer (score 10):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[accessibility](/questions/tagged/accessibility)

The "Post Your Answer" button can't be reached using the <kbd>Tab</kbd> button.
If you are writing an answer and press tab, the focus jumps to the togglebox for "Community wiki" and on the next tab it jumps to the "Discard" button, skipping the "Post Your Answer" button.

Answer (score 9):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

[Feature request opened on GH](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/42)

When trying to select a row of a table in the rich editor, you select only the contents of a single cell. If you drag further you select the contents of the next cell, etc. There is no way to select the entire row.

Can we please make it such that we can do the intuitive thing here and select an entire row and remove it by pressing backspace / delete. Instead of having to go through the dropdown-menu to remove a row.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! We do have plans to give the table functionality some extra love, but it unfortunately didn't make it in time for the alpha launch. Row/column selection is something we'd like to look into supporting in the future.

Comment: Thanks for all your work and open communication @BenKelly. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

[Bug report opened on GH](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/52)

Images aren’t shown as selected, e.g. in the following I selected from “Google Document” to “blah” and the image wasn’t shown as selected (tested on Chrome with native dark mode+Windows):

[image: Screenshot showing text before and after an image being selected, but showing the image as not being selected]

Comment: Thanks for the report! I can reproduce this locally. Clicking an image shows it as "selected" (with a focus ring), but not when it is part of a cursor selection range

Answer (score 9):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

> Fine-tuning images:  resizing or adding links to sources or full-sized images will need Markdown mode.

That'd be convenient to have a way to resize images in the non-Markdown mode, as I've seen many people resizing images by lowering the resolution instead of using the HTML to change the image's dimension (which is a bit of a pain to type).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! We actually had a rough implementation of this _really_ early on in the development cycle, but we removed it since there's no [standards compliant](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.29/#images) way to set size attributes on an image in Commonmark (other than using html, which I prefer to avoid if possible). I'd love to get some sort of support for this use case in place though, so marking as "review" for now.

Comment: @BenKelly It may be helpful to mention that, on public, unlike on Teams, the fact we upload to imgur allows for us to use imgur's resizing links - if you add certain letters to the URL, it will display the image in different sizes or formats. Since this is just a change to the URL rather than any sort of HTML, perhaps it might be easier to implement? Here's the list of letters that will change the image size - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298818/detailed-info-on-imgurs-automatic-image-resizing-service

Comment: @Catija thanks the issue with these links is that they have images with lower resolution.

Comment: @BenKelly that'd be very cool, thanks!

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Personally, anyway, this is why I always default the linked image to the full-size image. This is simple in our current scheme - I copy the image URL and add it to the list at the bottom a second time. Then I change the number for the second one, add an m to the first link, and then change the reference link in the post body to refer to the second link as the image link... if that all makes sense. :D If we implemented this well, that would all be automatic when uploading, say - I upload, pick a size and the MD automatically links to the full size image.

Comment: @Catija thanks, got it, makes sense but I think it is preferable to display the image with the highest resolution but rescaled to a lower dimension

Comment: Good to know - I guess I've been lucky. I don't tend to have issues with the resized images being legible on my end but I think I have heard that some do have issues with it. I don't have a great solution - but, as the person who's written our internal guide on using HTML to resize images on our Team - I know it can be janky to try and do manually. :D

Answer (score 9):

[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

[Feature request opened on GH](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/47)

It's not obvious how to switch between modes on mobile/narrower screens

[image: Screenshot showing that the markdown/rich text switcher isn't being rendered due to the screen being narrow, and that it's not obvious that it exists as a result]

Would it be possible/desirable to have the mode switch on the left or bottom of the text input?

Comment: Maybe have the mode switch fixed on the right side and the other buttons scrollable.

Comment: Related:  [On the phone it'd be nice not to have to horizontally scroll to be able to access all the edit buttons.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360086/178179)

Comment: Thanks for the report. This issue is very similar to the one linked by @FranckDernoncourt. I'm follow up with our designers to see if we can't come up with a better long term solution to the horizontal scrolling

Answer (score 9):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

[Bug report opened on GH](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/41)

On mobile, with a touch screen, there's no obvious way to continue a post if the last element is a image. While I can tap on text to bring up a cursor, without arrow keys there's no intuitive way to move it.

On Desktops *if* the only element is an image, you can’t bring up the cursor, but if there’s any text on top, you can can navigate past the image with the down arrow.

As such there's no way to continue a post past and embedded image unless you you switch to markdown or insert it between text blocks on mobile, or if there’s already text on the desktop views

Comment: If I understand correctly, [the same happens on PC](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360056/348196) (i.e., you can't get to the end of the post using the mouse cursor, or even with arrows).

Comment: Thanks for the report. There's a bit of a trend I'm seeing regarding being unable to continuing editing when the final element is a selectable block. Hopefully we can address all these in one fell swoop

Answer (score 9):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

[Bug report opened on GH](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/55)

The video below shows what happens if one holds the  <kbd>↓</kbd> key. I think it'd be preferable if it doesn't loop around, especially since holding the  <kbd>↑</kbd> key doesn't loop.

[image]

Markdown used in the demo:

```
| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
|  | A margin call occurs when the value of an investor's |
| [Federal call](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/f/federal-call.asp) | A federal call is a legally mandated margin call pursuant to Regulation T. Investors will receive a federal call when their margin account lacks sufficient equity to meet the initial margin requirement for new, or initial, purchases. |
```

Tested with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate and Google Chrome 88.0.4324.190 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Comment: Nice find! I was able to reproduce locally. I logged on issue on our public repo to track this. Thanks for the report!

Answer (score 9):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)

I'm not sure if this is an artifact of the transition phase, but when I open an edit screen in a new tab (just like non-2k users would), e.g. with [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/361781/edit), I can't resize the question preview anymore, and only the first few lines are visible:

#### New situation

[image: screenshot from Meta.SE, without resize bar]

#### Old situation

[image: screenshot from Movies.SE, with resize bar]

Comment: Ooh, nice find! This resizer was initialized in the editor code and I missed it when testing out the non-inline edit screens. I have a quick fix ready to go that will go out sometime later today. We haven't decided yet if we're going to move away from the "grippie" (existing style) of resizable or move forward with the css native `resize` like you see in the new editor now. For a quick fix, I've simply added `resize` to the original question body to match the editor, but I have a bug filed internally to revisit this before full launch. Thanks for the report!

Answer (score 9):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) [GH #173](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/173)

Toggling between modes causes italics within links to be changed like this:

[image: Screen recording showing how a link with italics in, but that doesn't cover the whole link text, it is split up from one to two links when toggling between markdown and rich text.]

This seems to have caused the red part to *leak* into the green one ([See rev 20](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/255584/revisions)):

I had just deleted an extra space between 'to' and 'delete'.

[image: Image demonstrating an additional rendering bug when the previously demonstrated edit was submitted, resulting in the red associated with text removal being shifted and positioned in the wrong place]

Answer (score 9):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

**Extra sidebar in toolbar menu & incorrect SVG rendering in image upload modal**

There's an annoying scrollbar on the new editor which appears even when there is no content in the textarea.

[image]

When you put a lot of content in it two scrollbars appear.

[image]

This can be sort of annoying. It appears that it can be fixed by setting the toggle button's height to `23px` instead of the current `24px`.

Specifically, here:

[image]

Oddly enough, I also ran across a bug when I tried to upload an image in this answer. It displayed something really quirky:

[image](sorry for the long answer)

Comment: We noticed this a couple of hours ago and are digging into what happened. Thanks for the report. :)

Comment: @Catija Thanks for the update. I also ran across a quirky bug with the image upload.

Comment: According to our design systems lead, that's our SVG imgur logo rendered as text. We'll... dig into that, too. Thanks! :D

Comment: Thanks for the report! I've found the root of both issues and will have a fix deployed later today. The odd scrollbar is due to switching the toggle to use a new [Stacks component](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/toggle-switch/) (Stacks is our internal design system) and in this scenario, some dreaded _legacy code_ is adding some margins that's causing the overflow we're seeing here. As for the image uploader, I added some fixes to mitigate potential XSS bugs (found by an eslint rule) and the sanitization was a little too eager in this cases...

Answer (score 9):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

Add a horizontal rule to separate the text field from the controls:

[image]

Comment: This is currently "by design", but I'll bring the suggestion to the design lead. Currently, there's no divider when scrolled all the way to the top, but once a scrollbar is introduced, the bar "floats" and uses a shadow to denote separation.

Answer (score 8):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

If you start by clicking on the 'Insert code block' button and type the word 'test', it'll say it auto-detects the 'lisp' language. I guess an autodetection feature is nice to have, but when switching to Markdown it doesn't show the ```` ```lisp ```` and without that hint, it won't work.

[image]

Comment: I believe that indicator is telling you which language that Hightlight.js will automatically highlight the code as in its current form, not that it automatically applied that language to the code block. If the code block had a defined language override on it, the "(auto)" part would not be there.

Comment: I guess it's different, or broken for Glorfindel, because it's identified as plaintext for me. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8khdu.png).

Comment: Code highlighting in rich-text mode still leaves a bit to be desired. We don't want to try and autodetect what language you're attempting to use in real time as you type (for performance reasons), so we do it once when switching _from_ markdown mode and keep the assumption. Even then, the logic doesn't take your post tags into consideration (yet), so it isn't a perfect emulation of the old process. We're still thinking on how to best handle code autodetection in rich-text mode. Thanks for the report!

Comment: I also [asked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360070/915027) if it could be choosed manually ?

Answer (score 8):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

[Bug report opened on GH](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/41)

When in Rich editor mode having an image at the end of your post makes the behaviour unpredictable.

If you press the down arrow to get to the end of your input field your cursor disappears. The only way to regain it is pressing the enter key until it pops back up.

[image]

Comment: I'm able to reproduce this. I'm seeing a trend of errors regarding end of document content, so hopefully we can squash them in one fell swoop. Thanks for the report!

Comment: @BenKelly I see some status has been put on this at git. Any olans on updating the answers in this post accordingly?

Answer (score 8):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

[Bug report opened on GH](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/41)

I can’t type additional text after I insert a code block in Rich mode (underneath the code block).  Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to a question where you haven't drafted an answer, and put the editor in Rich mode.
2. Put in some stuff.  Put in a code block with the toolbar shortcut.
3. Then you can't click underneath the code block unless you put it in Markdown Mode.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360056/361484

Comment: Thanks for the report! I'm seeing a trend of "can't click after last element", so hopefully we can resolve all these in one swoop. Temporary workaround - You can use `shift+enter` to exit a code block (since `enter` assumes you are typing more code).

Comment: @BenKelly +1.  Saved my stack-editing bacon! ;)

Answer (score 8):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

[Bug report opened on GH](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/41)

In Rich Text mode, if you start the post with a code block, you can't get rid of it. The button looks to be a toggle but clicking it again doesn't help; you can't remove it by pressing the Delete key (on macOS; I guess it's the same for the Backspace key on Windows). The only way is to switch to Markdown mode. If you use the code block somewhere in the middle of the post, it *is* possible to delete it in Rich Text mode.

Comment: Very similar to [my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360057/798831).

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that. It's also similar to https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360043/295232

Comment: A workaround for this is to press Ctrl-backspace to get rid of it, I just found.

Comment: Thanks for the report! We're seeing a few instances where blocks like these mess with cursor position. This class of bugs is firmly on our radar.

Answer (score 8):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

[Bug report opened on GH](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/24)

In Markdown mode, type a header text (e.g. `# Test`), select all text with a keyboard shortcut (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) and click the Italic button. This will put the asterisks on the previous and next line:

[image]

When selecting the same text with your mouse, and clicking the Italic button, you get something different (which is consistent with the old editor):

[image]

Comment: Ah, fun bug. I have an idea why this is, but will have to review further to make sure. Thanks for the report!

Comment: Ah I didn't notice this was already reported. I also reported that [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360154/299995). But it seems that you don't need the text to be a header, as long as there is only one line of text in the editor and you select all of the text. cc: @BenKelly

Comment: I just went ahead and deleted my bug report.

Comment: @KodosJohnson Your timing was perfect. I was literally adding a comment to your post at the instant it was deleted. I got a nice shock when it locked my additions and gave me a warning lol

Answer (score 8):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

[Feature request opened on GH](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/44)

When typing `1. test` in Rich Text mode, the editor automatically recognizes it as a bulleted list. Great! When typing `1) test`, it doesn't:

[image]

but when toggling between Markdown and Rich Text mode, it *is* recognized:

[image]

Comment: Good catch! Looks like our input rules only operate on the `.` ordered list marker and not `)`. I'll see what we can do to extend it to allow for both. It looks like these are the only two markers allowed in the [commonmark spec](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.29/#ordered-list-marker), so we likely won't add any more past what you've suggested. Thanks for the report!

Answer (score 8):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

When having two tables in the rich text editor, selecting everything and pressing backspace only deletes one table, not everything selected.

To reproduce:

- Add two tables one after the other
- Select both tables *with your mouse* and hit <kbd>backspace</kbd>

  - Using <kbd>ctrl + a</kbd> to select works as expected

Comment: Oh, this is a strange one. Everything deletes as expected when selecting with CTRL+A, but _not_ when selecting with a mouse. Thanks for the report!

Answer (score 8):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

In rich text mode, toggling a code block on and off makes it visually appear to be a code block in the preview, but not after saving:

[image: Editor showing text as a code block after clicking the code button twice, then saving as plain text]

Comment: Oh interesting... I can reproduce, but I have no idea why it would be doing this. This'll be a "fun" bug to squash. Thanks for the report!

Answer (score 8):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)

[Bug report opened on GH](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/56)

When copy-pasting a post when Markdown is switched off, it’ll add plenty of new lines and some components such as tags are not copied properly. (tested on Chrome+Windows)

E.g., before copy (https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360077/178179):

[image]

after copy:

[image]

Comment: That might be hard to do as you are copying the rendered output which doesn't carry information about markdown code. It would be the same as trying to copy from the preview in the existing editor. A simple workaround would just be to turn on markdown mode before copying.

Comment: Thanks for the report! Some info about copy/paste that you didn't ask for, but I'll explain anyways: When copying into the clipboard we actually get the html representation of the content. On paste, we try to take that html representation, figure out what it maps to on our end and then add the correct nodes to the document structure. This is why copying from e.g. Google Docs tends to carry over the formatting on paste. As you can see with the pasted tag, we don't have this perfect quite yet, but we're working on it ;)

Comment: @BenKelly thanks for the information! Getting some info on points we didn't raise is typically a great way to learn.

Answer (score 8):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

In Markdown mode, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> inserts single backticks (inline code) instead of creating a code block like the old editor.

In the old editor, the only time inline code will be used is when only part of a line is selected. However, when an entire line is selected, multiple lines are selected, or nothing is selected at all, a code block is created. Right now, the only way to turn some lines into a code block (other than doing it manually) is by clicking the toolbar button.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is status-bydesign.  Ctrl+M used to insert an HTML/CSS/Javascript snippet; it inserts the code block in this new editor because those snippets don't exist anymore.

Comment: @Ollie Yeah, you're right about Ctrl+M. I rarely use code snippets, so I didn't know that before. The only thing is that they said the code snippets are _temporarily_ absent in the alpha test and I'm assuming it'll be re-added when the new editor goes live. I guess they're going to use a different keyboard shortcut for code snippets then.

Comment: You're right, yeah.  So maybe `status-planned` then.

Comment: Thanks for the report! We're likely going to revisit keyboard shortcuts for the different code types when adding in snippets. We tend to prefer not regressing behavior for these sorts of things, but that isn't a hard rule. Marking as "review" for now, until we decide on the final behavior.

Answer (score 8):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [mobile-chrome](/questions/tagged/mobile-chrome) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

[Feature request opened on GH](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/47)

On the phone it'd be nice not to have to horizontally scroll to be able to access all the edit buttons.

[image]

Comment: Other than collapsing them into one or more dropdowns, we don't have much choice. I'll pass this feedback on to the designer on this project and see if we can't come up with some alternate solutions. Thanks for the report!

Comment: @BenKelly if there is enough vertical space, maybe have two or more rows?

Answer (score 8):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[Bug report opened on GH](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/45)

#### Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> does not *toggle* Heading in Rich Text mode

- In the old editor, it would *cycle* between several Headings.
- In the Markdown mode of the new editor, it *toggles* between Heading1 and no heading.
- However, in the Rich Text editor, it only works one way. Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> for a second time opens the browser's history tab in Chrome.

Comment: Nice find! We have concrete plans to extend the headings implementation, so I'll see if we can't work this in to the roadmap since it's a regression from the behavior of the old editor. Thanks for the report!

Comment: FWIW, @Ben - H1 should really never be used in questions (the title becomes the H1) or answers here. There may be other contexts where that heading is appropriate, but it'd be nice if the editor guided folks toward H2 & H3 exclusively.

Comment: @ben as context: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214449/175002

Comment: Hello! I created [a PR](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/pull/110) that should fix this issue ([preview](https://deploy-preview-110--nifty-lalande-39c157.netlify.app/)). Does it look good?

Comment: The `ctrl-h` toggle is fixed. The "show the same header options" is being tracked in [GH #165](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/165) and [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/380299/51). Marking this as completed.

Answer (score 8):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

#### Selecting a word with a double-click does not work for links

As said in [my other answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360115/348196), it’s standard practice to double-click to select a single word. That works! Except when the word being selected is part of a link’s text. See demo below.

[image: Double-clicking a word doesn't select properly]

It looks like it only selects the clicked letter and the ones to its right. When the click occurs *between two letters*, nothing is selected.

Compare that to what happens in MS-Word, for example:

[image: Double-clicking works well in MS-Word]

It also works very well on other websites' RT fields, like Reddit, for instance.

Comment: hmm. I wonder if the triple click to select line is something to consider too

Comment: @JourneymanGeek A triple-click works in RT mode but not in MD mode regardless of links, and that's what my other answer (linked above) addresses. Is that what you're referring to?

Comment: The double click also appears to select part of the popup. For me (Firefox Nightly 87.0a1, Linux), if I double-click the left half of a letter, it selects the letter and the rest of the word to the _right_ and everything in the popup; otherwise, if I double-click the right half of a letter, it selects the letter and the rest of the word to the _left_ and everything in the popup; if I double-click the right half of the _last_ letter of the link, the non-link word next to it, to the right, is also selected.

Comment: If I didn’t enter a valid link, however (e.g. left it as `https://`), then selection is very broken, and the input in the popup constantly overrides focus and selection. **It’s definitely the popup’s fault**, as it gets inserted in the middle of the word.

Comment: @Sebastian If by "the popup" you mean the one where you enter the link, it works well for me (Chrome, Win10).

Comment: On Chrome for Linux I can reproduce this report more closely: double-clicking the left half of a letter (to be clear: a letter of a word within a link) behaves like on Firefox. Double-clicking the left half of a space between two words of the same link selects the space; double clicking the right half of it selects nothing. Double-clicking the right half of a letter selects _nothing_; but double-clicking the right half of the _last_ letter selects only the space to the right of it — the popup _doesn’t appear_.

Comment: @41686d6564 Yes, that’s the popup: the `<span class="w0 ProseMirror-widget">`. What do you mean by “it works well for me”? Does it select the whole word? Does it not select the popup?

Comment: Oh, you mean selecting text in the editor causes the popup to be selected too? Yes, I can repro this. I thought you meant selecting text _in the popup's textbox itself_. Selecting text _in the popup_ [works as expected](https://i.imgur.com/VIWCKMz.gif).

Answer (score 8):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)

[Feature request opened on GH](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/54)

Blockquotes are rendered automatically in rich-text mode, but spoilers aren't.

[image: spoiler not rendered automatically in rich-text mode]

Comment: Thanks for the report! This is simply because we haven't registered a input rule for them yet. It should be a pretty quick feature to add though

Answer (score 8):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

Image in the table causes some periodic movement (Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate + Google Chrome Version 88.0.4324.146 (Official Build) (64-bit)):

[image: Screen recording showing the size of the table fluctuating periodically]

Markdown code:

```
| header 1 | header 2 | header 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| cell 1 | cell 2sd   sdf |  |
| sdfcell 3 | klkl<Bjjj![](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIT9D.png) |  |
| cell 4sdf | cell 5 | cell 6 |
| cell 7 | cell 8 | cell 9 |

jk,
jk,

jk,jk,
```

Comment: Oh, who doesn't like perodically moving tables? ;) Good catch!

Comment: Oh, fun... Thanks for the report! We'll look into it.

Answer (score 8):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Pasting a text with a link in a table results in the text getting cut:

[image: Screen recording demonstrating how pasting text outside a table works fine, but pasting it in a table cell results in the link and the text after the link not being included]

Markdown used in the demo:

```
| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
|  | A margin call occurs when the value of an investor's  |
| [Federal call](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/f/federal-call.asp) | A federal call is a legally mandated margin call pursuant to Regulation T. Investors will receive a federal call when their margin account lacks sufficient equity to meet the initial margin requirement for new, or initial, purchases. |

A margin call occurs when the value of an investor's [margin account](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/m/marginaccount.asp) falls below the broker's required amount

fghj
```

Tested with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate and Google Chrome 88.0.4324.190 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Comment: For me, it pastes the whole text but without the link. Surprisingly, when copying text with a link from the table and pasting it outside, the hyperlink is also lost in this case. [Demo](https://i.imgur.com/p1riy4I.gif).

Answer (score 8):

[status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[lists](/questions/tagged/lists)

[Bug report opened on GH](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/69)

#### Inserting a bulleted list trims digits if they are at the start of the list entry

If you want to make a bulleted list from text like this:

```
3 users need to foo the bar
then the bar becomes foo
4 bars have been foo'd
```

and you select the text, and press on the bulleted list button it turns into this:

- users need to foo the bar
- then the bar becomes foo
- bars have been foo'd

Removing part of the text you wanted to turn into a list.

If you manually add the `-` in front of the text you end up with this:

- 3 users need to foo the bar
- then the bar becomes foo
- 4 bars have been foo'd

Comment: Nice find! This is due to the bullet list command being too "smart" (and it backfiring). The idea was that if you're already using an ordered list, the bullet list will replace it. In reality, it should really only do this if you have the ordered list markers on each line AND the marker is correct (e.g. `1.` or `1)`). There's some undefined behavior for what to do with nested lists, but I'm not so sure we're going to get _that_ smart in handling the edge cases in markdown mode. Thanks for the report!

Comment: Good you identified the cause @BenKelly. Good luck fixing it ;)

Comment: @BenKelly possibly related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/363589/361484

Answer (score 8):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

`\*` causes text to be italicized in the markdown editor, whereas it shouldn't.

Example:

[image]

Pasted markdown:

```
There exist 2 active lists:

1. https://\*.stackexchange.com/?tab=active
2. https://\*.stackexchange.com//questions?tab=Active

https://\*.stackexchange.com/?tab=active has a limit, as [Tim Stone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/150235/tim-stone) mentions in their [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/117120/178179).
```

Tested on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate with Chrome 91.0.4472.12.

Answer (score 8):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

[feature request opened on GH](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/101)

Use a more appropriate resize anchor. The current one suggests it has horizontal resizing support, but it only supports vertical resizing:

[image]

Comment: This isn't exclusive to the question dialogue, it's also present on the comment box.

Comment: @Luuklag Good spot, although that one bothers me less because it has no obvious place to be resized _to_. While the answer form has a whole lotta whitespace to the right of it.

Comment: That's actually the browser default resize handle, so we can't do much to style that icon specifically. This is a topic we've discussed internally in the past, but have yet to take action on. I've opened a feature request item on our GitHub repo.

Answer (score 7):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

When making the screen of my browser smaller, some other buttons (undo/redo) become visible and the Markdown label for the toggle switch becomes a logo:

[image]

The same happens on Safari on my iPhone (though I have to scroll the toolbar sidewards for the other buttons to become visible).

Comment: This seems like odd behavior to me too. I understand logic of why it was done this way. They are hidden by default (intentionally) and only appear at smaller screen widths because it assumes you are on mobile at the small of a width, and thus would not have access to Mod-Z and Mod-Y keyboard shortcuts. That assumes everyone likes using those and if there's space available, and removes the options for people who might be browsing the site in desktop mode on their phone. Curious if there was some other reason why it was designed this way.

Comment: This is the desired functionality. In the spirit of responsive design, we reduce the "Markdown" text to an image to provide more horizontal room for the rest of the toolbar and show the undo/redo buttons since the majority of the cases where the screen is this small are mobile/touchscreen devices. As you note, on very small screens there is a potential for the toolbar _still_ being too big and needing some scrolling.

Comment: I don't think adding *new* buttons is in keeping with "the spirit of responsive design".

Comment: @BenKelly What about people on tablets, which have big screens, but no keyboard?

Answer (score 7):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [mobile-chrome](/questions/tagged/mobile-chrome)

On Google Chrome on Android, one can't access the table menu to alter the table structure (add/del rows/cold).

Demo:

[image]

Tested on Android 10 with chrome 89.

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue on Chrome 89 on Android. Can you provide reproduction steps? My repro steps are: 1) Rich text mode 2) Create table by tapping button 3) Tap table cell 4) Tap table button (can see menu) 5) Tap remove column or similar

Comment: @BenKelly Demo: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENIEY.gif using the same steps as yours

Comment: Oh! You're in _markdown_ mode. We only support the column/row commands in rich text mode currently. The reason being that it is _so_ much simpler to manipulate nodes than it is plain text.

Comment: @BenKelly got it, good catch!

Answer (score 7):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [images](/questions/tagged/images)

When adding a picture, you can click it in rich text mode, and a popup will appear (you may need to scroll due to [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360033/opt-in-alpha-test-for-a-new-stacks-editor/360175#comment1202385_360175)) where you can enter the image source, the image description and a title text. Similar to [this related bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360460/289905), the popup is displayed *inside* a `<div draggable>`, together with the picture. Since a mouse down or mouse up will be interpreted as a drag start or drag end, respectively, and moving the mouse while holding it down is interpreted as a drag action, it is difficult to select text within the popup or to place the cursor at a specific point.

- On Firefox, the drag always starts, no matter what you do. You can only focus a specific text box with your mouse, but beyond that you have to use your keyboard.
- On Chrome, you can actually use text boxes normally, but click-and-drag to *select* text is only possible if you’re clicking in the boundary of the text itself; clicking the padding of the text box still triggers the drag action. Double-clicks and triple-clicks work fine.

---

Example below. You can click the edit link, enable rich text mode, click the image, and try to adjust (or even read) the text in the image description and the title text (and the image source) using your mouse.

[image: Some very long description. Try to select some text here with your mouse]

<sub>Example picture is *[1000 years Old Thanjavur Brihadeeshwara Temple View at Sunrise](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:1000_years_Old_Thanjavur_Brihadeeshwara_Temple_View_at_Sunrise.jpg)* from Wikimedia Commons; public domain.</sub>

---

This has now also been reported here: [Unable to position my cursor by mouse inside the image textboxes in the Answer section in the Firefox browser](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/371593/289905).

Comment: If I start drawing my mouse *on the text,* it works form me as expected, but it's still a bit annoying that even if it's one pixel off of the text (not the text*box*), it starts dragging.

Comment: @FZs Ah, there’s a difference between Firefox and Chrome! On Firefox, it doesn’t work at all.

Comment: Oh, yes, I used Chrome.

Answer (score 7):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

## My entire answer was deleted when I went to edit the question

I have not used this editor much (maybe 2-3 answers), but I discovered a fatal flaw: when in markdown mode, my answer is wiped out a few seconds after I click *edit* on the question (which happens inline due to me having 2k+ rep). When the answer is in WYSIWYG mode, it simply wipes out what I have in code fences.

So far, this has only happened to me when I was [answering a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366105/6083675). In this case, I was able to recover by refreshing the page to access the autosave. I posted my answer there, and the same thing happens to me when I am editing the answer then click to edit the question. It's not caused by an extension and there are no console errors.

Answer (score 7):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)/ [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

### TL;DR: The new editor *must* refrain from reformatting/ destroying unrecognized markup in Rich Text mode.

At the moment, when you switch the editor from Markdown to Rich Text mode, the editor does its best to parse and display the formatting "live," which works well most of the time. The problem is that it also largely destroys or reformats any markup it doesn't recognize, which is downright *disastrous* for at least two reasons.

#### Reason #1: "Previewing" content may break it

One of the top reasons that I refer to the preview, whether in the old or new editor, is because I'm unsure about the syntax of the markup I've written, or when I'm using several formatting elements at once and I want to make sure they're all playing nicely together.

With the old editor, that was as simple as scrolling down the page, and on the new, it's as simple as flipping a switch– except it's not, because by "checking the preview" in the new editor, my markup is likely to have been changed in unanticipated ways. I have zero guarantees that flipping that switch isn't going to destroy a delicately formatted post, and that's a ***royal pain***.

Using the Rich Text mode as a stand-in for the preview pane is fine for me, but if there truly isn't going to be a different substitute, then I *need* to be 100% certain that switching modes isn't going to wreck my markup. This is especially true given that undo/ redo history is currently lost as soon as the mode is switched!

#### Reason #2: Unintended post edits

The second major issue with the forced formatting is that if you go to edit a post and the editor opens in Rich Text mode, this will *automatically* reformat and/ or break post content (no need to toggle modes). There's also no built-in way to revert these changes (you have to refresh the page or cancel the edit altogether).

This makes it *really* easy to introduce broad, unneeded changes into posts, especially when editing large FAQ-style ones (I did it myself [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/2678/revisions), view the Markdown side-by-side in Rev. 104).

I know that I'm not the only one that's stumbled into this specific trap based on other reported bugs here, and the fact that the editor does this forced reformatting without warning or notification leads to pretty awful UX in this case. In the best scenario, I recognize something of value has disappeared, and in the worst, I don't notice at all, which can lead to posts with missing and/ or broken content.

Comment: You're definitely not the only one. There are several related answers that were posted about the many issues with switching between the two modes. It's still a good idea to have an answer that mainly focuses on losing formatting though. +1

Comment: Can you add one or more examples of the destruction and reformatting? E.g., will `List<map>` be converted to `List`?

Answer (score 7):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

## Formatting Toggle Bugs

*I know there's a lot to take in here, but I wanted to get the formatting bugs that I've run across documented. I searched for duplicates in this thread, but didn't find any; feel free to point them out and I'll remove them from the list/ add a reference to an already addressed duplicate.*

I noticed that some keyboard shortcuts don't "toggle" off properly in one editor mode or the other in certain circumstances.

The post states...

> We're planning to add keyboard shortcuts to the formatting buttons but they aren't part of this initial alpha test.

...so let me know if any of these aren't really bugs, and are more part of features that just aren't turned on yet or something.

For all of these, I'm experiencing them on Chrome 91.0.4472.77 on Windows 10. If a repro gif would be helpful for any of these which don't already have one, comment and I'll add it.

#### Lists

- In rich text mode, hitting <kbd>Ctrl+O</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl+U</kbd> with non-list text highlighted will format the highlighted text as an (un)ordered list, but doing the same with text that's *already* formatted as a list doesn't map to the shortcut. <kbd>Ctrl+U</kbd> does nothing at all, and <kbd>Ctrl+O</kbd> triggers the browser "Open" function.

#### Blockquotes

- In rich text mode, <kbd>Ctrl+Q</kbd> moves highlighted text into a quote block, but successive presses simply increase the quote level, rather than removing the quote block (like the button does).
- In Markdown mode, when highlighting *all* text in an answer box which happens to include one or more line breaks with <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> (specifically), all line breaks will be removed, and the last couple characters of each line will be duplicated and garbled... I can't figure out a pattern here, but it's odd (Not using <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> works as intended):

  [image: Animated gif of block quote shortcut garbling text in markdown mode]
- In Markdown mode, adding a list to a blockquote via the ribbon button or shortcut will remove the list syntax, and clicking/ pressing it again will not restore it:

  [image: Animated gif of block quote removing list syntax in markdown mode]

#### Code Formatting

- In Markdown mode, highlighting all text with <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> and then clicking the code block ribbon button doesn't keep all content highlighted, leading to strange behavior on subsequent button clicks. The code block syntax is not toggled away, and instead adds newlines and further borked code fences indefinitely (*Not* using <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> works as intended):

  [image: Animated gif showing the code fences fail to toggle away properly when all text is highlighted with Ctrl+A]

  - The same behavior as above also occurs under the same circumstances for inline code formatting, via ribbon button or <kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd> presses
- In rich text mode, toggling off a code block doesn't render properly. The code block visually sticks around, but the detected language switches to `plaintext`:
  [image: Animated gif showing code formatting not disappearing in rich text mode when you toggle it with the ribbon button]

Answer (score 6):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

DDon't double the first letter of the text.

FF Android.

---

**Reproduction steps**

- On Firefox on Android, start in either editor mode
- Type a single character, followed by any other character
- Note that the very first character appears twice

  - This happens to the first character on *any* line

Comment: Thanks for the report. I can reproduce on Firefox Focus on Android, but not FF 84 on Android. I've edited your post to include clearer reproduction instructions as well.

Comment: @BenKelly Thanks for reviewing this. --- The exact version of my browser is: 85.0.0-beta.9 (Build #2015787947) - AC: 70.0.14, 0de6d8b65 - GV: 85.0-20210115192513 - AS: 67.2.0 (From Google Play Store).

Comment: I can no longer reproduce this on FF Focus on Android. I think it must have gotten fixed upstream. Marking as complete for now.

Answer (score 6):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

[Bug report opened on GH](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/57)

When tapping <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> next to a list item, a new line under that bullet is created but the cursor does not jump to this new line. Even if I click on that line with my mouse, the cursor jumps back to the line above. Check the video below for a demo.

[image: Screen recording demonstrating how the line produced by shift-enter cannot be clicked or written to]

Comment: No idea what you mean or how it's related to the new feature. This is not the place to bring up old bugs with the existing editor.

Comment: FYI, this problem also happens for the last item in the list too. A way around it is to type the whole sentence, then add a line break with Shift+Enter in the middle of that sentence.

Comment: Ah, fun with soft breaks! Thanks for the report, I'm seeing a few different bugs around soft breaks that will (hopefully) be fixed in one swoop

Answer (score 6):

[support](/questions/tagged/support) [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

A lot of elements, such as spoilers, tags, blockquotes etc., rendered immediately in the preview as soon as you finished typing them in the old editor.  In this editor, I have to toggle between Markdown and Rich mode in order to get them to render.  I get it in Markdown mode, since it’s supposed to show only Markdown, but it would be nice if they rendered immediately in Rich mode.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand the issue being reported. We do support a few input rules where a limited amount of markdown typed in rich-text mode gets converted into a styled block (typing `> ` or `# ` for instance), but otherwise any text typed is just text. What behavior is it that you're seeing and what behavior is that that you are expecting to see?

Comment: @BenKelly In Rich mode (the old editor's equivalent of a preview, I guess) spoilers, tags and a few others don't render immediately, like they did in the old editor's preview.  Is Rich mode too different from that?

Answer (score 6):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [blockquote](/questions/tagged/blockquote) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) [GH #70](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/70)

#### Blockquoting a selection of text strips the markup of the selected text

I was working on a post, en wanted to quote a piece of a well formatted post by Shog9.

I copied and pasted this part:

```
### So what good is Triage?

Ok, now we can get to some numbers. From my perspective, it's *still* a better First Posts review than First Posts Review, and a better way of handling VLQ flags on questions than Low Quality review. But that doesn't *directly* help folks just trying to browse the site without bumping into lousy questions.

<!-- #24065 -->

So let's focus on views. In May of 2018, 256,414 questions were posted on Stack Overflow. Of those, 31586 entered Triage, and 25508 were reviewed completely (that is a consensus was reached). The average view count across all questions posted in May was 89; the average view count for questions that entered Triage was 64; the average view count for questions that completed Triage was 67. 

Broken down by Triage consensus:

    Triage result      Questions Avg Views 
    ------------------ --------- --------- 
    Looks Good         11379     76        
    Should Be Improved 9825      66        
    Unsalvageable      4299      48
```

I then selected it, and pressed the blockquote button as I wanted to quote it.

It's markdown now looks like this:

```
> So what good is Triage?
> 
> Ok, now we can get to some numbers. From my perspective, it's *still* a better First Posts review than First Posts Review, and a better way of handling VLQ flags on questions than Low Quality review. But that doesn't *directly* help folks just trying to browse the site without bumping into lousy questions.
> 
> <!-- #24065 -->
> 
> So let's focus on views. In May of 2018, 256,414 questions were posted on Stack Overflow. Of those, 31586 entered Triage, and 25508 were reviewed completely (that is a consensus was reached). The average view count across all questions posted in May was 89; the average view count for questions that entered Triage was 64; the average view count for questions that completed Triage was 67. 
> 
> Broken down by Triage consensus:
> 
> Triage result      Questions Avg Views 
> 
> Looks Good         11379     76        
> Should Be Improved 9825      66        
> Unsalvageable      4299      48
```

See that the heading got stripped from the first sentence, and the code indentation and dashes from the makeshift table got stripped too.

Answer (score 5):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [images](/questions/tagged/images)

When inserting a new image via  <kbd>CTRL</kbd> +  <kbd>V</kbd>, directly  upload + insert the image, as GitHub, Gmail, Outlook, etc. do (= no need to click on "add image").

Example in GitHub:

[image]

Comment: This can be rather problematic for accidental image uploads. GitHub likely provides more support for deleting images. We do not. We will only ever delete images that contain sensitive information that shouldn't be in them, meaning users who accidentally upload things because e.g. they forgot it was in their clipboard are out of luck if we just auto-upload it without verification.

Comment: Also you no longer need to wait for the upkoad to finish, you can just continue working on your draft.

Comment: @Luuklag thanks, I'll edit the feature request accordingly

Comment: @animuson but as long as the post isn't submitted, the only way to see it is by guessing the URL, which is very very hard to do. And even if one see the uploaded image somehow, it can't be linked back to the one who uploaded it. Risk here is very mininal.

Comment: @Shadow That doesn't mean people will not still write to us demanding it be removed, which we do not do.

Comment: @animuson I can only assume the amount of people who write to you asking to add the ability to paste images is greater... and amount of people who want it and don't ask for it is much bigger. :) (the current paste works only for Chrome, and requires extra step - while not bad, people these days are spoiled)

Comment: @Shadow This isn't requesting a feature for pasting or drag-and-drop to work in more places. It is asking for the image, once pasted, to automatically upload without any verification of the image to be uploaded (not requiring the user to click on the "Add picture" button after the paste).

Comment: @Shadow I would say even if the amount of people asking for the feature is far greater, it's easier to ignore them. oops, I mean redirect them to MSE. But people asking to delete an image can be more problematic for SE staff especially if the image might contain sensitive information by mistake (GDPR and friends come to mind). I would still be against this feature request as long we can't delete uploaded images.

Comment: Fair point, @Dan

Comment: @Dan GDPR and friends are exactly why SE should have some automated process to remove images, which would then make this feature more privacy friendly.

Comment: I agree with @animuson on this. Instant upload with drag-and-drop is fine, IMO but not with Ctrl+V. One might accidentally paste something that they don't wish to have uploaded to "the web". Sure, one should be more careful when dealing with sensitive data because you can't trust what a form will do with texts/images once inserted, so it's arguably the user's fault, but still.

Comment: @animuson There's a middle to be split here. There's strong reasons why you wouldn't want to start uploading without a confirmation step. But you can still launch that confirmation dialogue directly on copy-paste/drag-drop from the text window (without needing the extra step of clicking an "add image" button).

Comment: @E.P. That's how the editor behaves now, you can paste an image directly into the editor without the need to first click the add image button in the toolbar. And you get a confirmation showing you the image you pasted before uploading it to imgur

Comment: @Dan Yeah, I realized that after posting. I guess I'll leave my big d'ough there as a warning to others ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯.

Comment: I think it’s possible with the `File` API to create some fake Markdown like `![enter image description here](#image1)` (or even a “reserved”, proper Imgur URL) which renders as the uploaded image, and only when hitting the Post button, the images are uploaded to Imgur. This, however, would break the workflow of copying an Imgur URL into a comment and discarding the post. Being able to delete Stack Exchange Imgur images would solve this problem _and_ any GDPR problem in one fell swoop.

Comment: @SebastianSimon That approach has its own implications and risks. If a post has images, submitting the post requires the images to be uploaded before saving it. That can take a while. And what if one of the uploads fails? The UX for that would be a nightmare. And that's why all sort of editors usually upload file and image almost immediately instead of waiting for the final submit. Another problem is the draft, that would also need to be reworked to handle yet-to-be-uploaded pictures.

Answer (score 5):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

[Bug report created on GH](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/59)

Overlapping bold/italic formatting leads to incorrect formatting when toggling to Markdown mode.

1. In rich text mode, write some text.

   - this is bold, now italic, and now?!
2. Select part of the text.
3. Make the selection italic.

   - this is bold, *now italic, and now?!*
4. Select some *overlapping* text.
5. Make the selection bold.

   - **this is bold, *now italic****, and now?!*

(Now bold and italic formatting is correctly applied to overlapping portions of the text.)

When switching to Markdown, the formatting is screwed up because Markdown doesn’t support overlapping formatting in this way: adjacent `*`/`**` is ambiguous at the best of times, but Markdown wouldn’t support this even when using `_` to format italics.

Here’s what the editor generates:

```markdown
**this is bold, *now italic****, and now?!*
```

… but as mentioned, even the following isn’t really supported by Markdown as far as I’m aware (it certainly isn’t on this site):

```markdown
**this is bold, _now italic**, and now?!_
```

Comment: The editor seems to have functioned correctly here. It split the italics. So you have a `**this is bold, *now italic***` using three asterisks to close the bold and italics and then a `*, and now?!*` to re-enter the remainder of the italics for the part that was outside of the bold. The problem is that the parsers we have do not handle the scenario of four consecutive asterisks because of the ambiguity. I'm not sure how that's supposed to be handled.

Comment: @animuson It could *potentially* be handled by using `_` for italics but personally I’d be more comfortable with forbidding overlapping formatting, but that’s admittedly fairly opinionated since it (arguably) prevents “valid” markup.

Comment: Ah, this is clever. In a way, you've created _illegal content_ in the rich-text editor that isn't actually supportable in the backing markdown. The editor is "smart" enough to generate what would be sane markdown, but [isn't actually valid](https://spec.commonmark.org/dingus/?text=**this%20is%20bold%2C%20*now%20italic****%2C%20and%20now%3F!*) due to the introduced ambiguity. I guess the solution here is to default weak emphasis back to `_` in the case of an overlap [since that is valid](https://spec.commonmark.org/dingus/?text=**this%20is%20bold%2C%20_now%20italic_**_%2C%20and%20now%3F!_)

Comment: There's still some edge cases here I can think of, even using `_`. This is going to require a bit of thought and a few unit tests. Thanks for the report!

Answer (score 5):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)
Looks like there is a bug if you post in both modes. That is, you start off posting in Markdown mode, then finish the post out of Markdown mode. Most notably, the text gets pushed into a code block by default. If you toggle the Markdown a bit back and forth, it seems to sort itself out....

**EDIT**: Ok I think I’ve figured out what’s going on and how to reproduce it. If you copy some text from a post that is in Markdown, and then paste that text into a post without Markdown, the pasted text will be in a code block of some kind with the word ‘plaintext’ off to the right.

[image]

All subsequent text is also captured in the ‘code block’. If you delete the code block, or toggle in and out of Markdown mode enough times, the block eventually gets rendered out of existance and the text looks correct.

```
[tag:feature-request][tag:mobile-chrome] This was copy/pasted from another post on this thread that had Markdown enabled to demonstrate what's happening.
```

Comment: Yep, had a similar problem as well. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360137/172297

Comment: I was about to report this. I'm guessing its auto-detecting 'code' and markdown looks code-like enough to trigger it. Switching to markdown to paste the text seemed to work though

Comment: @JourneymanGeek, Yes the work-around is 'easy' I suppose. But, as was explained in the comments to the other answer pointing out this issue, I think the vast majority of the human population expect to copy some text, and have that and **only** that pasted into whatever else they paste into. If they want to implement a *paste special*, even if they have that on by default (but allow for a paste-as-plain-text-option), fine. Otherwise it's a clear bug.

Comment: Oh, I agree its a bug. Its also something likely to bite more experienced users in the ankle :D

Answer (score 5):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

<sub>Seeing that the editor does exactly what you tell it to do, I've tagged this as FR, and not as a bug.</sub>

---

If you select part of your text to format it in bold the new editor wraps it in double asterixes (as is expected):

`Here is some text to test with a **bold part** in it.`

If I now select an overlapping part of text, say "test with a bold" and make that bold as well the editor wraps it in double asterixes again (as expected):

`Here is some text to **test with a **bold** part** in it.`

This now renders as:

Here is some text to **test with a bold** part in it.

Which is technically correct, but I think it would be more convenient if the result would simply be:

`Here is some text to **test with a bold part** in it.`

Which is similar to what text editors like MS Word do.

ps. This holds for the other buttons, like Italics and inline code as well.

Answer (score 5):

### Tables don't copy and paste from Google Docs

I attempted to copy and paste a table from Google Docs in the editor.

[image]

The editor brought it an as plain text.
[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure they won't paste from Office 365 either. Or a desktop word processor for that matter. I don't expect this to work from a Google Sheet either (checked it, and indeed it doesn't paste a table) but restricting to the Sheets format might be easier to implement.

Comment: Duplicate of: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360033/opt-in-alpha-test-for-a-new-stacks-editor/360046#360046 ?

Answer (score 5):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

## Incorrect rendering of tables (HTML, extra row)

The following animated GIF shows the issue.[image]

The table with no header is correctly rendered. However, on editing, when I disable markdown, it automatically adds an empty row.

Reproduce it [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407335/text-aligned-right-and-left-in-the-same-line/407342#407342)

More obvious comparison.

**Regular preview:**

[image]

**Markdown preview:**

[image]

Not only does it add an extra row, but also incorrectly renders the HTML, which causes even more problematic troubles during editing, illustrated below:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

## Peculiar behavior when trying to upload GIF

While editing [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/363974/863015) answer I ran across a strange little quirk.

When pasting GIFs into the image upload section, it is rendered as a PNG, which makes it no longer animated. When dragging files from the file explorer into the section however, it preserves file type.

Here's a GIF that illustrates the issue:

[image: Screen recording demonstrating that pasting a gif removes animation, but dragging the original file into the editor preserves the animation]

Comment: It's not pasted as PNG; it's _copied_ as a still-frame image. When you right-click a GIF and select "Copy", only one frame is copied (at least in my experience). This has nothing to do with SE. Use "Copy image address" instead.

Comment: @41686d6564 Thanks for clearing things up :)

Answer (score 5):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

[Bug report opened on GH](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/70)

Lists are removed when quoted when markdown=on:

E.g.

```
- It's calc'd OTF each time there's a need to know; the status isn't stored in a variable on the Profile. Sources: [meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309220/…](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309220/warn-new-users-who-ran-into-a-question-ban-on-other-sites-before-they-post-here?rq=1#comment1007747_309220 "warn new users who ran into a question ban on other sites before they post here") [meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309220/…](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309220/warn-new-users-who-ran-into-a-question-ban-on-other-sites-before-they-post-here?rq=1#comment1007752_309220 "warn new users who ran into a question ban on other sites before they post here") [meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309220/…](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309220/warn-new-users-who-ran-into-a-question-ban-on-other-sites-before-they-post-here?rq=1#comment1008668_309220 "warn new users who ran into a question ban on other sites before they post here") - Can chng b4 posting – [Rob](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/282094/rob "13,587 reputation") [15 hours ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/363950/if-a-user-is-banned-from-posting-answers-state-so-before-they-start-writing-the#comment1214462_363950)
- To expand off Rob's comment: because they are calculated on the fly, it is also an expensive thing to check. Running that check every single time a user loads a question page is not viable at all. Only running it when someone attempts to post an answer reduces resource load. – [animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/141525/animuson "172,484 reputation")**[♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/141525/animuson "172,484 reputation")** [15 hours ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/363950/if-a-user-is-banned-from-posting-answers-state-so-before-they-start-writing-the#comment1214464_363950)
- Similar cross-site duplicates, which offer insights into the mechanism: [meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318202/3648282](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318202/3648282) [meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323194/3648282](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323194/3648282) - you can have a warning or message, but until you actually push the button you don't know the *true* answer. The permission to post can change a moment later, any message prior to actually pushing the button would be an estimate of what you should expect the result to be; and not the actual result. – [Rob](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/282094/rob "13,587 reputation") [4 hours ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/363950/if-a-user-is-banned-from-posting-answers-state-so-before-they-start-writing-the#comment1214520_363950)
```

becomes:

```
> It's calc'd OTF each time there's a need to know; the status isn't stored in a variable on the Profile. Sources: [meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309220/…](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309220/warn-new-users-who-ran-into-a-question-ban-on-other-sites-before-they-post-here?rq=1#comment1007747_309220 "warn new users who ran into a question ban on other sites before they post here") [meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309220/…](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309220/warn-new-users-who-ran-into-a-question-ban-on-other-sites-before-they-post-here?rq=1#comment1007752_309220 "warn new users who ran into a question ban on other sites before they post here") [meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309220/…](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309220/warn-new-users-who-ran-into-a-question-ban-on-other-sites-before-they-post-here?rq=1#comment1008668_309220 "warn new users who ran into a question ban on other sites before they post here") - Can chng b4 posting – [Rob](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/282094/rob "13,587 reputation") [15 hours ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/363950/if-a-user-is-banned-from-posting-answers-state-so-before-they-start-writing-the#comment1214462_363950)
> To expand off Rob's comment: because they are calculated on the fly, it is also an expensive thing to check. Running that check every single time a user loads a question page is not viable at all. Only running it when someone attempts to post an answer reduces resource load. – [animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/141525/animuson "172,484 reputation")**[♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/141525/animuson "172,484 reputation")** [15 hours ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/363950/if-a-user-is-banned-from-posting-answers-state-so-before-they-start-writing-the#comment1214464_363950)
> Similar cross-site duplicates, which offer insights into the mechanism: [meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318202/3648282](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318202/3648282) [meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323194/3648282](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323194/3648282) - you can have a warning or message, but until you actually push the button you don't know the *true* answer. The permission to post can change a moment later, any message prior to actually pushing the button would be an estimate of what you should expect the result to be; and not the actual result. – [Rob](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/282094/rob "13,587 reputation") [4 hours ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/363950/if-a-user-is-banned-from-posting-answers-state-so-before-they-start-writing-the#comment1214520_363950)
```

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360033/opt-in-alpha-test-for-a-new-stacks-editor/363589#363589 I think.

Comment: @Luuklag thanks I'm not sure either.

Comment: I think at least the root-cause is the same. Blockquoting something strips its markup. In my case headers and code indentation, in your case list formatting.

Comment: @Luuklag another related issue: https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/70#issuecomment-832179385

Comment: Thanks for the tip Franck, funny thing is that that links back to my other answer here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360033/opt-in-alpha-test-for-a-new-stacks-editor/363507#363507 We both spent too much time here I guess. We have to wait for a new iteration of the editor to come up with something new to report ;)

Answer (score 5):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

#### Right-clicking a word immediately after selecting it with a double-click causes the entire paragraph to be selected

It appears that the logic for selecting a paragraph with a triple-click does *not* (properly) check for which mouse button was clicked (which should be the left button only). Check the following table:

| Action | Expected behavior | Current behavior |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Double-click (left) + right-click | Select the word, then show the right-click menu on the selected word | Selects the *entire paragraph* and shows right-click menu. |
| Double-click (left) + middle-click | Select the word (middle-click does nothing) | Selects the entire paragraph. |
| Triple-click (right) | Nothing, just show the menu with every click | Selects the entire paragraph. |

Obviously, the first action is what's important as no one is likely to notice (or be bothered with) the other two but adding the right check should probably fix all three anyway.

Here's a demo:

[image: Demonstrating the behavior of the first and third actions]

Comment: [Duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360033/opt-in-alpha-test-for-a-new-stacks-editor/360785#360785), it's [status-review] with a [GitHub issue opened](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/40), but you've got more comprehensive details than I did! Probably worth adding these new cases to that issue.

Answer (score 4):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>PAGE UP</kbd> does not select the entire text when Markdown is switched off. E.g.:

```
The money goes directly to your PayPal Cash or PayPal Cash Plus balance where you can use it as you normally would.

How long does it take to receive money from selling crypto?

Usually, the money you receive from selling crypto will be available instantly in your PayPal Cash or PayPal Cash Plus balance. As with all transactions, crypto sales are subject to review and could be delayed or stopped if there's an issue.
```

if the mouse cursor is placed at the end, <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>PAGE UP</kbd> fails to select the entire text (only the last paragraph becomes selected). Tested on Chrome + Windows.

Answer (score 4):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [mobile-chrome](/questions/tagged/mobile-chrome)

Adding an image results in removing the post.

Demo:

[image: Screen recording demonstrating markdown of an image being copied and pasted into a post, resulting in other text/markdown being delted]

Pasted markdown:

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENIEY.gif
```

Tested on Android 10 with chrome 89.

Comment: It’s [this revision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/360090/2) ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/960ba53c-fbea-4846-a66c-289d3303fa8e/view-source)), right? Apparently the Markdown content is replaced by the pasted content (except for the first line).

Comment: @SebastianSimon correct

Answer (score 3):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

```
Dim oCSV
Local $oConnection = ObjCreate()
```

I check how to post *inline* code and I have two comments:

1. I can’t select a language .. is there always “auto” enabled and can’t be chosen manually?
2. I had such an issue, that when I started my inline code, that the editor area was empty, so there was no new line. And when I was in “code segment“ then I was unable to go down below the area, with the “cursor down key”. I had to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to go outside the box and then the cursor keys started working properly. My suggestion is to always automatically add a new line below the code area.

Comment: `1.` Asked/notified before [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360035/915027). `2.` Continued [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360075/915027)

Comment: For 1, you can indicate the code language in Markdown mode, which is the same as it always has been. We haven't figured out how to allow this in rich text - you can see this noted in the question's section about how MD is best for fine-tuning posts.

Comment: `in the question's section about how MD is best for fine-tuning posts` where ?

Comment: Search the question for "Markdown mode is your go-to for fine-tuning posts" - it's a section towards the lower middle of the post.

Comment: Now I see. Thanks. In the future: I would prefer to have an option in profile preferences to choose between `1` Auto mode `2` specific language/formating (my favorit) .  But in the moment when I post code I should be able to change them by selecting from some kind of combo. btw. Auto option is/will be the best option for new users, but advanced should have a way to spcified the formationg in code segment.

Comment: Thanks for the report! As you note, `1` is answered [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360033/opt-in-alpha-test-for-a-new-stacks-editor/360035#360035) (tl;dr, we're working on it). As for `2`, I'm seeing a few different bugs that appear to have the same root cause. Hopefully, fixing one will fix them all

Answer (score 3):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [images](/questions/tagged/images) [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)

When inserting a new image via  <kbd>CTRL</kbd> +  <kbd>V</kbd>, please don't place the "Add Image" button at the top of the editor, but instead place it somewhere closer to the cursor where the image is being inserted.

Example:

[image]

Comment: +1, especially as you can't hit Enter to get it.

Comment: The button should be focused anyway. Then, having it close to the cursor would be a "nice-to-have".

Comment: @41686d6564 imho [we shouldn't have to click or press any key](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360135/178179)

Comment: @Franck I thought of that too but then I quickly realized that this one might accidentally paste something that they don't wish to be uploaded (the same concern that animuson addressed in the comments below your answer). I'm fine with instant upload with drag-and-drop but not with Ctrl+V.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I understand the pain point, but I have to reflect a bit to figure out how I'd solve this. I'll pass this along to our designers and see if we can't come up with a good solution.

Answer (score 3):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) (tags don’t work yet in this mode either it would seem, although it may render properly given that this is ported to markdown)

Using a line break, breaks the user interface.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Type some normal text
2. Press shift+enter
3. Press enter

As shown below:

---

normal text

Comment: Using an `hr` as shown above, when clicking edit and entering the rich text editor, creates a wrapper for the hr which is `<div contenteditable=true>` which is probably not ideal.

Comment: The example shown below is missing markup, presumably because the process of converting the rich text back to markdown is not 1 to 1. As such, my attempt to actually show the issue there doesn't do much in itself, aside from pointing out the lack of 1-1 mapping (which should be a requirement for any richtext environment).

Comment: Thanks for the report, but I'm having a little trouble understanding the bug, as "breaks the user interface" is a bit vague. Can you explain what behavior you're seeing and the behavior you're expecting to see? Additionally, is this in markdown or rich-text mode?

Comment: @BenKelly - It is in rich-text mode. Once you have taken the steps, you can no longer select the element created by insertLineBreak, nor move past it. Instead, moving the cursor (or range tracker from a behind the scenes point of view) to the inserted line break causes the cursor to go to the prior element; perhaps a result of the tracker not recognizing the action and thinking it is somewhere it is not.

Comment: @BenKelly - You may want to whitelist the execCommand options that are available.

Comment: @TravisJ You may want to edit these details into your answer.

Comment: @SebastianSimon - This issue will be handled, it is similar in nature to several other bugs now that I have inspected most of what has been reported. It would seem that there is an issue with the tracker getting stuck. To be honest, there is a whole host of issues with creating a rich text environment, and this answer would turn into a melting pot if I started including all the sort of related nuances to this issue here.

Answer (score 3):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)[mobile-chrome](/questions/tagged/mobile-chrome)

On Google Chrome for Android, after clicking on the image button, one always have to scroll up to be able to click on *"Browse"*.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)[images](/questions/tagged/images)

If the image is above the max size (current 2 MiB), automatically resize (or change compression) to the largest image possible, or close to it.

Comment: While this is a reasonable request - the current editor doesn't have this functionality, so I'm not sure this is in scope.

Comment: Is this actually feasible? The size restrictions are presumably there to reduce the load on the server, so the file resizing would need to happen client-side. Are there reliable solutions to do this in-browser?

Answer (score 3):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [tables](/questions/tagged/tables) [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox)

When trying to navigate from one cell to another cell by pressing <kbd>tab</kbd> and then trying to select all the text of the cell by <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>end</kbd> keys, the selection doesn't happen the first time. I need to press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>end</kbd> *twice* to be able to select the cell's text.

This issue occurs on Mozilla Firefox only. On Google Chrome, it is working as expected.

Mozilla Firefox: 85.0.2 (64-bit)
Operating System: Windows 10 Pro

[image: GIF]

Answer (score 3):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Add progress bar when uploading an image.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

Adding `-` in the following example causes some color change when markdown=on, which goes away after switching markdown off and on:

[image]

Text used for the example:

```
- It's calc'd OTF each time there's a need to know; the status isn't stored in a variable on the Profile. Sources: [meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309220/…](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309220/warn-new-users-who-ran-into-a-question-ban-on-other-sites-before-they-post-here?rq=1#comment1007747_309220 "warn new users who ran into a question ban on other sites before they post here") [meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309220/…](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309220/warn-new-users-who-ran-into-a-question-ban-on-other-sites-before-they-post-here?rq=1#comment1007752_309220 "warn new users who ran into a question ban on other sites before they post here") [meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309220/…](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309220/warn-new-users-who-ran-into-a-question-ban-on-other-sites-before-they-post-here?rq=1#comment1008668_309220 "warn new users who ran into a question ban on other sites before they post here") - Can chng b4 posting – [Rob](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/282094/rob "13,587 reputation") [15 hours ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/363950/if-a-user-is-banned-from-posting-answers-state-so-before-they-start-writing-the#comment1214462_363950)
- To expand off Rob's comment: because they are calculated on the fly, it is also an expensive thing to check. Running that check every single time a user loads a question page is not viable at all. Only running it when someone attempts to post an answer reduces resource load. – [animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/141525/animuson "172,484 reputation")**[♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/141525/animuson "172,484 reputation")** [15 hours ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/363950/if-a-user-is-banned-from-posting-answers-state-so-before-they-start-writing-the#comment1214464_363950)
- Similar cross-site duplicates, which offer insights into the mechanism: [meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318202/3648282](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318202/3648282) [meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323194/3648282](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323194/3648282) - you can have a warning or message, but until you actually push the button you don't know the *true* answer. The permission to post can change a moment later, any message prior to actually pushing the button would be an estimate of what you should expect the result to be; and not the actual result. – [Rob](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/282094/rob "13,587 reputation") [4 hours ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/363950/if-a-user-is-banned-from-posting-answers-state-so-before-they-start-writing-the#comment1214520_363950)
```

Answer (score 3):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [tables](/questions/tagged/tables)

It would be nice if pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> inside a table cell adds a linebreak instead of navigating to the next cell (which can be done with <kbd>Tab</kbd> anyway).

This is important because as you said:

> We make no promises that any HTML written in Markdown mode will be editable in rich text mode

And indeed just having a `<br/>` inside a cell [to add a linebreak](/a/364765/348196) works in Markdown mode but breaks when switching to and from RT mode.

The linebreak in RT mode can then be translated either to some (extended) markdown or to HTML (if supported later).

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [keyboard-shortcuts](/questions/tagged/keyboard-shortcuts)

**I can't use the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key to exit this new editor.**

I like keyboard shortcuts, and this worked just fine for the old editor, for both questions and answers.  Can we implement the shortcut for this editor?