# Switching the answers sorting or page does not include a URI fragment in the URL on mobile

Tags: bug, mobile-web

*I'm using the question about the new [Stacks Editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360033/opt-in-alpha-test-for-a-new-stacks-editor) as an example as it's a good use case due to the long post.*

On desktop, when we change the page of answers, the URL includes a [UI fragment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_fragment): `#tab-top`. That fragment tells the browser to automatically scroll to the list of answers.

For [example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360033/opt-in-alpha-test-for-a-new-stacks-editor?page=3&tab=votes#tab-top): `https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360033/opt-in-alpha-test-for-a-new-stacks-editor?page=3&tab=votes#tab-top`

On mobile, however, the fragment is not there. And it forces us to scroll every time we need to change a page.

For [example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360033/opt-in-alpha-test-for-a-new-stacks-editor?page=3&tab=Active): `https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360033/opt-in-alpha-test-for-a-new-stacks-editor?page=3&tab=Active`

If this is by design, I would argue that, at least, the behaviour should be switched. It's more convenient to have the page automatically scroll to the list of answers on mobile compared to desktop.

Comment: I highly recommend clicking the "full site" link at the bottom to get a much better responsive site that *does* handle this (and many other things) properly.  Although on that *particular* page, scrolling all the way to the bottom might be an adventure.

Comment: Hard adventure mode is when you want to scroll back up to the pager when you want to switch pages. But going into full site mode is a neat idea, never thought of that, thanks! Although there are pages that not responsive but a have a mobile mode (mostly the profile pages).

Comment: @Dan Profile pages are in the process of getting redesigned.