# No spacing between tag-formatted text in the inbox' post preview aka. SE creates buglists

Tags: bug, tags, notifications

Yesterday, I have received a notification about a post (namely the [Opt-in alpha test for a new Stacks editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360033/opt-in-alpha-test-for-a-new-stacks-editor/363507#363507)), that I followed, so I can see (and vote for) the new bugs/features reported/requested.

[image: Screenshot]

I thought [buglists](/questions/tagged/buglists) is for some summary of bugs, or an issue tracker used by this project, or something like that.

However, I found this:

[image: Answer to Opt-in alpha test for a new Stacks editor]

Ah, OK, [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) and [lists](/questions/tagged/lists). However, the tag-formatted texts slipped together.

---

The issue is probably on the backend, as the buggy HTML element contains only plaintext, and it has no space in it.

Comment: Hey, thats my post :). Have an upvote for the excellent example.

Comment: @Luuklag You already have my vote on your bug report ;)

Comment: Most likely duplicate of [Search doesn't space out tags in a post](/q/357800/289905). The representation of tags as plaintext (used in search and in notifications, most likely using the same method) is just the text content of the tags. If there’s no space between them in the post, then there won’t be a space in the plaintext representation. Not sure what you mean by _“as the buggy HTML element contains only plaintext”_ — there is no buggy HTML element and whether or not it contains only plaintext doesn’t seem relevant.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Yes, it seems likely that the two issues were caused by the same problem, but I wouldn't say anything until a staff member looks at it. By "*as the buggy HTML element contains only plaintext*", I meant that the issue isn't a CSS styling bug, but a plaintext representation problem coming from the server. Yes, there's no *buggy* HTML element, I meant *the HTML element that contains the bug*.