# Emails are autolinked in the new Stacks editor

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, editor, stacks-editor

I just recently submitted an answer written in the [new editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360033/opt-in-alpha-test-for-a-new-stacks-editor) that contained an email:

> `xxx@yyy.com`

After I posted it, I clicked 'edit', switched to rich text mode, made some changes and submitted my edits. However, the email became a link:

> `mailto:xxx@yyy.com`

When I use the old editor this doesn't happen, so I suppose this is a bug.

Note that I can't even remove `mailto` in the new editor... I can only remove it by switching back to CommonMark mode.

Only HTTP and HTTPS links [are allowed in posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites) (along with relative and protocol-relative URLs), and using other types of links (other protocols such as `mailto` along with relative fragments) will result in the link being stripped out.

Comment: Even if it is not a bug but somehow "by design" that feature should be disabled. Do not linkify emails, ever.

Comment: The Stacks editor uses the [markdown-it](//github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it) library to parse CommonMark, apparently with the [`linkify` option set to `true`](//github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/blob/main/src/shared/markdown-parser.ts#L246) (default is [`false`](//github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it#init-with-presets-and-options)). This option uses the [linkify-it](//github.com/markdown-it/linkify-it) library ([ref](//github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it#linkify)) that converts emails to links by default ([ref](//github.com/markdown-it/linkify-it#new-linkifyitschemas-options)).

Comment: [Lines 274-278 in `markdown-parser.test.ts`](//github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/blob/main/test/shared/markdown-parser.test.ts#L274-L278) indicate that developers are indeed aware of this particular auto-linking behaviour.

Comment: @double-beep there are a few issues with the implementation though. Even though it renders as a link in wysiwyg mode, when you save, it is not linked anymore. Also, more strangely, if you surround the email address with double quotes, the email address isn't linked AND mailto: is included as literal text.

Comment: @double-beep here is the revision that I made on one of U12-Forward's post that led to this bug report: https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/370234/2. Notice that "team@stackoverflow.com" got changed to "mailto:team@stackoverflow.com"

Comment: As far as I know, bug reports for the "new" editor are still being collected as answers on the question: "[Opt-in alpha test for a new Stacks editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360033/271271)", rather than as separate bug report questions. This question should be deleted and the bug report reposted as an answer on the announcement question.

Comment: @rene Yeah! I agree!

Comment: @double-beep Ah

Comment: I guess give this 6-8 weeks to solve :)

Comment: [I opened a PR](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/pull/85) that addresses this question. We now only have to wait 6-8 weeks for the devs to merge it.

Comment: The solution here may be a bit more complicated than the proposed PR to just disable it. `mailto` links _are_ allowed within Teams and the feature is intended to be available for users there.

Comment: @animuson `mailto:abc@example.com` *will* be linked, `abc@example.com` will not.