# Unable to position my cursor by mouse inside the image textboxes in the Answer section in the Firefox browser

Tags: bug, design, markdown, uploader, firefox

In the Mozilla Firefox browser, I'm unable to position my cursor by mouse inside the image textboxes in the *Answer* section. If I want to modify any text, I can only use the keyboard.

**GIF image for the issue:**

[image: GIF]

| Configuration | Version or value |
| --- | --- |
| Operating system | Windows 10 Pro |
| Mozilla Firefox | 93.0 (64-bit) |
| Zoom | 100% |

Comment: Are you able to position of your cursor on Image source?

Comment: I can't even get this screen to show in the newest editor...

Comment: @JitendraSingh Not on the three textboxes. But used to edit the description and title only.

Comment: Already reported: [Opt-in alpha test for a new Stacks editor](/a/360810/289905).