# New stacks editor discards all contents

Tags: bug, status-completed, stacks-editor

The new stacks editor destroys content in the most drastic way possible. It seems that if HTML tags are used the whole content is discarded.

It happens when stacks editor is enabled and you have selected the non-markdown view. When you press "edit" (both inline and in new page) the contents disappear. When you have the markdown view selected, switch it off to see everything gone. It also happens when creating a new post, but you have to switch to markdown view and back. [Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/379036#379036)

Tested in Chrome 101 on Windows 10.

A sample input that causes the issue:

```markdown
Any text here, doesn't matter what.

<sub>
Any text is fine here, but note the inline html tags on their own lines
</sub>
```

Comment: Semi-related: [Toggling between Markdown and rich text to preview the result without editing anything should not be a destructive action](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360159/165261)...but even if that were fixed, this would still be extremely broken.

Comment: Yep, these sorts of complete loss of content have been reported for going on 2 years now, since the new "Stacks" editor was first previewed in Teams and SE asked for testing/feedback. It's ridiculous that they *moved something into production* with such glaring, known, obvious, critical issues. It's even worse that they've *kept* using it and both *forced* their paying Teams customers to use it, and *forced* new users on SO to use it (during one of the weeks long trials of revamping the question asking pages).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Stacks editor is broken. This is the proof. Try to edit this answer if you can. If the content is shown to you in the editor, try switching "markdown" back and forth.

<sub>It will be accepted to reproduce and demonstrate the bug.</sub>

Comment: No repro, but that's because I can't switch between editors on your post. I'm assuming you've already disabled all adblockers and userscripts when testing this?

Comment: @Mast Why can you not switch between editors? What do you see when you open the editor in a new tab? https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/379038/edit

Comment: Repro'd, and if I hit "Cancel" and reopen the >2k editor, it doesn't regain its content.

Comment: @DavisBroda You need to enable the New Stacks Editor in your [preferences](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current).

Comment: Enabled the new editor in preferences, and the issue now reproduces for me. Content is completely gone upon hitting the edit button

Comment: If that switch is what's required, considering that feature is in Alpha, I wouldn't expect it to work 100% of the time.

Comment: @Mast That would maybe be fine if it weren't also the only available editor in Teams.  Also, it's still a bug worth reporting, since they eventually want this for the rest of the network.

Comment: @Mast Yeah, it's ok here on Meta where you can switch it off and ignore it, but many people don't have that choice, especially on paid Teams.

Comment: Looks like it breaks when the HTML tags cover multiple lines. If I edited it to inline `<sub>It will...</sub>`, it doesn't.

Comment: @Mast While the editor may be pre-alpha quality, it's been in production on Teams for well over a year. It was first pre-alpha'd about 2 years ago, which was when bugs like this one, where the entire contents of the post are lost, were first reported.

Answer (score 10):

Thank you for the report. I've [filed this issue](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/133) in the Stacks-Editor GitHub repo so we can triage and keep better track of it. I was able to reproduce this issue and I have a pretty good idea of where to start looking, so I marked this post as [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned).

Short version - HTML in CommonMark is a beast to get right and only assumes one way translation (CommonMark → HTML). In our best effort attempts to make HTML content editable in rich text mode, the tokenized output is getting mangled a little bit and is failing to import into the rich text editor's node schema.

Comment: Yeah, there's some oddity when you try to wrap a markdown list with `<sup>`. it's not the only thing here, but it does seem to play into this issue

Answer (score 7):

This is fixed. It was included in the [beta 1 release](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/380295/51).

> HTML tags
> on same lines or different ones
> discard text no more