# When a question is closed, the new Stacks editor is disabled instead of the Post Answer button

Tags: bug, closed-questions, stacks-editor

When a question is closed while you're writing an answer, you'll see an orange banner

> This question has been closed - no more answers will be accepted.

which disables the 'Post Your Answer' button. However, with the [new Stacks editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360033/295232) the *editor* is disabled instead of the Post Your Answer button. In the screenshot below, I did get an error but that was only because the question was *deleted* in the meantime.

[image]