# How should "rich text" (format? RTF?) be stylized?

Tags: discussion, edits, spelling

The new [Stacks editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360033/opt-in-alpha-test-for-a-new-stacks-editor) introduces support for [*Rich Text Format (RTF)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format) and although there are just [115 posts on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=rich+text) containing "rich text" (at the time of this writing) that number is likely to increase.

I tried researching how to properly stylize the name since the above sample of MSE posts already contains *Rich Text*, *rich text*, *RichText*, *rich-text*, etc... It also doesn't help consistency that Microsoft itself has documentation with varying stylings like [rich-text](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/enable-or-disable-full-rich-text-formatting-in-a-rich-text-box-d3c71c1d-8c88-41e9-9ee5-2ca6a3d0ea67), [Rich Text and rich text](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/ways-to-customize-a-rich-text-box-f9d7d48b-cdaa-4124-ae3b-352920c71ebd), but also [Richtext](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/model-driven-apps/rich-text-editor-control#simple-configuration) and [RichText](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-or-delete-a-rich-text-field-9f86237d-dbbc-4a85-b12c-9d8dca824630)...

Can the community give some guidance on how to copy-edit the tech name?

Comment: Prepare for some Rich Text Format Madness...

Comment: @Glorfindel LOL now I get it *["**R**ich **T**ext **F**ormat **M**adness"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM)*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rich text, on its own, is just another way of saying *formatted* text, whereas Rich Text Format (RTF) is specifically a type of [file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_file_format). They are two different things, AFAIK. All the examples from MSE refer to "rich text" as formatted text and *not* the file format.

Rich text:

> In computing, *formatted text*, *styled text*, or **rich text**, as opposed to plain text, is digital text which has styling information beyond the minimum of semantic elements: colours, styles (boldface, italic), sizes, and special features in HTML (such as hyperlinks).
>
> ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formatted_text))

> You can store **rich, formatted text** in an Access database [...]
>
> ([Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-or-delete-a-rich-text-field-9f86237d-dbbc-4a85-b12c-9d8dca824630#bkmk_whatis))

Rich Text Format (RTF):

> The Rich Text Format (often abbreviated RTF) is a **proprietary document file format** with published specification developed by Microsoft Corporation from 1987 until 2008 **for cross-platform document interchange with Microsoft products**.
>
> ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format))

So "rich text" needn't be capitalized and should not be written as a single word (i.e., "richtext").