# New Stacks Editor doesn't let me upload images at first try

Tags: bug, status-completed, images, uploader, stacks-editor

It used to be possible to drag & drop image files from Finder (and perhaps Windows Explorer as well) to the [new Stacks Editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360033/opt-in-alpha-test-for-a-new-stacks-editor). However, that isn't working anymore for me on the latest Firefox and Safari on macOS. All I see is this:

[image]

When I click 'Cancel' and then the image button in the toolbar, I do see my previously uploaded image. The same process also repeats every time I switch from Markdown to rendered text and vice versa (as shown in the GIF above).

FWIW, I don't see any errors in the browser console, and clicking the Browse link in the dialog also works (but is less convenient).

Comment: I've added a GIF to your post for more clarity, if you don't mind. I've also added another scenario where this keeps happening.

Comment: Possibly related to the reports of the inboc not loafing for those who are in a team?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has [been fixed](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/167) in the [beta 2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/380295/announcing-the-stacks-editor-beta-release) [release](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/releases/tag/v0.7.0) of the Stacks Editor, which is now live on the sites.

> Drag in that image…
> Drop it in the editor…
> Works on the first try!